# Maximum average ord

Tags: code-golf, string, math

#### Your task

Take a list of strings as the input, and output the maximum average `ord`.

#### Example

Given the list `['hello', 'world', 'bye']`:

- The average `ord` of `'hello'` is:

  - (`ord(h)` + `ord(e)` + `ord(l)` + `ord(l)` + `ord(o)`) / `len('hello')`
  - = 106.4
- The average `ord` of `'world'` = 110.4
- The average `ord` of `'bye'` = 106.7

The maximum average `ord` is 110.4. This is your output.

#### Test cases

Note: For the last two test cases, I have given the roundings for 1, 2, and 3 decimal places. As mentioned in the rules below, you can round to any number of decimal places.

```python
Input                                        Output
['hello', 'world', 'bye']                    110.4
['code', 'golf', 'stack', 'exchange']        106.8
['!@#', '$%^', '&*(']                        55.7 / 55.67 / 55.667 / etc.
['qwertyuiop[', 'asdfghjkl;', 'zxcvbnm,']    110.9 / 110.91 / 110.909 / etc.
```

#### Rules/clarifications

- The output must be only the average `ord`. You may not output anything else.
- It may be rounded (up or down) to any number (\$\ge\$ 1) of decimal places. If your language does not support floating points, you may output the average multiplied by 10.
- [Floating point innacuracies](https://0.30000000000000004.com/) are ok.
- You may assume that the input list will always have a length of 2 or more
- You may assume that the strings will never be empty
- You may assume that the strings will not contain whitespace or non-ASCII characters
- **This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!**

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25304/114446)

Comment: @Arnauld - oops, I forgot that wasn't an ASCII character. I've changed the test case.

Comment: If you allow ≥0 decimal places, then languages that work only with integers would be able to compete, too.  Or, as an alternative, could one output the average *times ten*?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen - for languages that don't have floating points, I'll allow outputting the average times 10. I'll edit that in now.

Comment: Can we take input as an array of character arrays?

Comment: @Shaggy yes, that's fine.

Comment: 'Round' seems ambiguous: I assumed that any rounding (including rounding-down) would be Ok, but apparently that wasn't your intention in the sandbox.  Can you clarify (and specify in the challenge) whether any rounding is Ok, or if it should be rounding-to-nearest-value?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I'll allow rounding up or down. I've edited that into the challenge.

Comment: What is `ord` or why does `ord(h) + ord(e) + ord(l) + ord(l) + ord(o)) / len('hello')` give `106.4`?

Comment: @QBrute - sorry, I didn't explain that: it might be called different things in different languages, but in Python `ord` means the ASCII/Unicode value of the character. `h` is 104 in ASCII, so `ord(h)` is 104.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `G`, 3 bytes

```
Cvṁ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuItHQSIsIiIsIkN24bmBIiwiIiwiWydoZWxsbycsICd3b3JsZCcsICdieWUnXVxuWydjb2RlJywgJ2dvbGYnLCAnc3RhY2snLCAnZXhjaGFuZ2UnXVxuWychQCMnLCAnJCVeJywgJyYqKCddXG5bJ3F3ZXJ0eXVpb3BbJywgJ2FzZGZnaGprbDsnLCAnenhjdmJubSwnXSJd)

Answer (score 9):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
eSm.OCM
```

[Test suite](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=eSm.OCM&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%27hello%27%2C+%27world%27%2C+%27bye%27%5D%0A%5B%27code%27%2C+%27golf%27%2C+%27stack%27%2C+%27exchange%27%5D%0A%5B%27%21%40%23%27%2C+%27%24%25%5E%27%2C+%27%26%2a%28%27%5D%0A%5B%27qwertyuiop%5B%27%2C+%27asdfghjkl%3B%27%2C+%27zxcvbnm%2C%27%5D&debug=0)

###### Explanation:

```
eSm.OCM   | Full program
eSm.OCMdQ | with implicit variables
----------+-------------------------------
  m     Q | For each word in the input,
     CMd  |  Get the ord of each character
   .O     |  Get the average
eS        | Get the max
```

Comment: For the record, [`eS.OCMM`](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=eS.OCMM&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%27hello%27%2C+%27world%27%2C+%27bye%27%5D%0A%5B%27code%27%2C+%27golf%27%2C+%27stack%27%2C+%27exchange%27%5D%0A%5B%27%21%40%23%27%2C+%27%24%25%5E%27%2C+%27%26%2a%28%27%5D%0A%5B%27qwertyuiop%5B%27%2C+%27asdfghjkl%3B%27%2C+%27zxcvbnm%2C%27%5D&debug=0) also works for 7 bytes, though I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: `eS.OCMM` works because `.O` is implicitly vectorized: If it is called on a list of lists, it is mapped over the inner lists. Most functions in Pyth that would otherwise throw errors are implicitly vectorized. This is implemented in the `unknown_types` function in `macros.py`: https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/blob/b70e591254a79b2b6efaa9b05d1d56d1bd9c2512/macros.py#L71

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 46 bytes

```python
lambda l:max(sum(map(ord,s))/len(s)for s in l)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY5bCsIwEEX_XUXERxOp-iuK4D58QNokbXWS1CTV1q34UxB1Te5GBgXBr3OHcy_M9VE2Ibemvanl5l4FNZ69JsB1IjiBueY19ZWmmpfUOhF7xqYgDfVMWUc8KQwB9l09S1eYQBVdR7kEsFFMorN1IDAkjYy2jHV-ndQKiSazoJA-8PSAQdZpzk323--uemj7gx1iOKJ__niWLjRVYcs1FrgXKsv3B1jgdanTU2J0jJvPu2374Rs)

Unfortunately, the only built-in `mean` function Python has is in the `statistics` module, and that's too expensive to import.

Answer (score 7):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>18</s> 11 bytes

```
|/{+/x%#x}'
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rRr9bWr1BVrqhV5+LSV0iLVspIzcnJV4rl4kqL1oByrJXK84tyUoB0UmWqkmYsALq+EBc=)

*Massive -7 bytes golf thanks to Steffan!*

Damn everyone is answering quick. Anyways here's my solution. Takes input as a list of strings.

Explanation:

```
|/{+/x%#x}'  Main function. Takes implicit input
          '  For each string in the input...
  {      }   Execute a function that...
   +/x       Takes sum of every character in the string
      %      And divide it by
       #x    The length of the string
|/           Get the maximum value
```

Comment: Max is just `|/`, and from there you can go pointfree: `|/{+/x%#x}'`

Comment: In k4, avg is a built in so we can get it down to 6 bytes: `|/avg'`

Answer (score 6):

## [Wren](https://wren.io/), 68 bytes

```wren
Fn.new{|x|x.reduce(0){|y,z|y.max(z.bytes.reduce{|a,b|a+b}/z.count)}}
```

[Try it](https://wren.io/try/?code=PTAWFMEMBNwJwFADdJwAQDMC8CEgMYD2sCAYgHYB054A7gN4A+AHi5XONAK77gAUABgCUTAJ4AaAF6NRlALaRmfSZQBGogC7gAzu049wTSONWNIAalUBfYCqJdyGoVau4QGQoS2IA2j4BEEAA2QYT+4v60hHBB0OH+6uD+ALriCGgBRLDxAOaEQRjx2hqQ+ADW8eDM+KCQ5DlJqekBAIQAAgDE8QAkADoApAB64Wj+AGQAVHwpaRn+AI608BqiXACWhAAOARGQ2tAYOaAAVmVBANzxktVIquRyKcmUUDVMrADKosXgcpSbcGtHHwMJR8JAQnxmEJnAggA)

Answer (score 6):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), <s>14</s> 13 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

*-1 bytes thanks to [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m)*

```
⌈/+⌿∘⎕UCS¨÷≢¨
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=ARoA5f/ijIgvK@KMv@KImOKOlVVDU8Kow7fiiaLCqA&f=S1PPSM3JyVdXUC/PL8pJAdJJlanqXGnqyfkpqUBeen5OGpAqLklMzgbSqRXJGYl56WAVig7KQBGVOFUgqaalARIqLE8tKqkszcwviAYKJhanpKVnZGXnWAM5VRXJZUl5uTrqXAA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

A tacit function which finds the maximum ord. Originally wrote a dfn, but I tried random stuff to convert it to tacit and it somehow worked out.

```
⌈/+⌿∘⎕UCS¨÷≢¨
          ¨              ⍝  for each element in the input...
     ⎕UCS               ⍝  convert the characters to their ascii values...
  +⌿∘                   ⍝  and sum the resulting ascii values...
           ÷             ⍝  divided by...
            ≢¨           ⍝  the length of each element...
⌈/                       ⍝  and take the maximum of that
```

Answer (score 5):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <del>80</del> <del>51</del> 48 bytes

```
0>0001.
$i:"!"(?v+$1+
(@:{:,$&/
v?(0&~$?/.02
\n;
```

[Animated Version](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiMDAwMDEuXG4kaTpcIiFcIig/diskMStcbjokQDokLCQmLyhAXG52PygwJn4kPy98LiEwMFxuXFxuOyIsImlucHV0IjoiaGVsbG8gd29ybGQgYnllIiwic3RhY2siOiIiLCJtb2RlIjoibnVtYmVycyJ9)

<del>Requires a extra space at the end of the input.</del> Also assumes no 2 spaces in a row. (no 0 length words). Anything with ORD of 32 or lower is considered white-space.

### Explanation

[image]

Top row: Push 3 0s on to the stack. The first is the current best ORD, the second is the length of the current word, and the last is the sum of the ord values of the current word. `01.` is a jump to the next row.

The second row sums a word. If a character is less than "!" (char value 33) go down. Otherwise sum the word and increment the length. `$1+

In the third row, we fist push the last value to the register `&` . We use this to later check if this was the end of the string. Then we divide by the length to get the new ORD value. Then we use the `:{:@` trick to copy the stack if it has only 2 elements (which is always the case) from the stack and compare them. If the new one is better we swap the stack with `$`. In either case we delete the top item.

Lastly, we take the value of the register and check if it is negative, `&0(?`. If so, we print the maximum ord and exit. If not, we jump back to `00`. To get the correct direction we use the `00!.|` trick.

Answer (score 5):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>65</s> <s>45</s> 44 40 bytes

```
000i:"!"(?v+$1+$20.
$~$0(?n00.>@$,:{:@(?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38DAINNKSVFJw75MW8VQW8XIQI9LpU7FQMM@z8BAz85BRceq2spBw/7//4zUnJx8haTKVIXy/KKcFAA)

Takes input as a space separated string.

Comment: Welcome back! \o/ First post in 3 years :)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10 9</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÇÅAà
```

-5 thanks to Sʨɠɠan

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cPvhVsfDC/7/j1bKSM3JyVfSUVAqzy/KSQExkipTlWIB)

**Explained:**

```python
ÇÅAà  # Implicit input as a list
      # Implicit map over the input:
Ç     #   Get the ord of each character
 ÅA   #   Get the average of the ords
   à  # Get the maximum value
```

Comment: I think that answering one's own challenge *three times* within 25 minutes of posting it is probably a record, although possibly not one that I'd encourage anyone to attempt to break...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I'll probably delete this one if someone comes up with a better 05AB1E solution.

Comment: Why not just `ÇÅAà`? `Ç` is the same as `εÇн}` and everything vectorizes so you don't need any maps

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan wow, I didn't know that was possible!

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 24 bytes

```factor
[ 0 [ mean max ] foldl ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVA7TsQwEBVtTjEbLQghYRKBQpZt6BANDaKKFuF1nA_rxFnbYRMQJ6GJhKDgBNQcg9MwickWSEwxb8ae997YL-8JZUaq7nvn7ub68uriDESujYaCmoxoQw12OfvtpYq5wgHDFRUaNF_XvGRcQ6W4MW2l8tLA3HGmTw5guBkXQrrgbqQSMeKy5S4c9wbwNybg-x45sTwmYxx0UykSBNyCrRB5wzJaplsJJkvd87yAhJY3Of96xcHp7i3mvYP9_8ysYRiQUzjqIRhxKLhhxOqtN1yZts5lFaEg1XGSZvcrMcfmsWEPy7LYOtj9Z0gf0B8LbzYqPr_VJjkMPyPwIIKC0xI_tYEFJFLEAhb2-qOgFQwvJvag6yz-AA)

Just fold with the max of the mean.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP 8.x, <s>75</s> 73 bytes

Creates an anonymous function that returns the expect values, hopefully.

```php
fn($x)=>max(array_map(fn($z)=>array_sum(unpack('C*',$z))/strlen($z),$x));
```

---

-2 bytes thanks to [Sʨɠɠan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/s%CA%A8%C9%A0%C9%A0an).

### How does it work?

This uses the [`unpack('C*', ...)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) function to convert all characters into an unsigned char (`0`-`255`).
This assumes all characters are part of the ASCII table.

Then it calculates the average using `array_sum([...])/strlen([...])`.
The function [`array_sum()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) takes an array and returns the sum of all elements, and [`strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) returns the length of the string.

The function [`max()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) takes the array with the averages and returns the highest value from it.

Anonymous functions implicitly return values.

### Example usage

You need to assign this to a variable, or call with [`call_user_func()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func) or [`call_user_func_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```php
<?php
$fn = fn($x)=>max(array_map(fn($z)=>array_sum(unpack('C*',$z))/strlen($z),$x));

// Should output: float(110.4)
var_dump($fn(['hello', 'world', 'bye']));
```

You can try this here (with test examples): https://onlinephp.io/c/2a424

Comment: `fn($x)=>max(array_map(fn($z)=>array_sum(unpack('C*',$z))/strlen($z),$x));` saves two bytes. Also you don't need to count the semicolon

Comment: ... How dumb of me to forget to use the string length ... Thank you! I count the semicolon, as it is a required part of the arrow function.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 38 bytes

```
\(x)max(sapply(Map(utf8ToInt,x),mean))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY31WI0KjRzEys0ihMLCnIqNXwTCzSAMhYh-Z55JToVmjq5qYl5mpoQ1bcYBdI0kjXUM1JzcvLVdRTUy_OLclJAjKTKVHVNTWUFLMDQ0EDPhAusLzk_JRWkOj0_Jw1EF5ckJmeDGKkVyRmJeekoZhgamOlZQPQpOiiDVKmoxoEoNS0NXHaBgKmpnrmCPogyg9FgRmpJsh7EuMLy1KKSytLM_IJokHmJxSlp6RlZ2TnWIF5VRXJZUl6uDswKkPMtgdrBtCGMYWAJNRESMAsWQGgA)

```
               Map(utf8ToInt,x)        # for every string in the input, store the vector of its codepoints in a list
        sapply(                ,mean)  # apply mean to each of the list elements and return a vector
\(x)max(                             ) # take max
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
OÆmṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//cFvuw50N////j1bPAArlq@soqJfnF@WkgBhJlanqsQA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 12 bytes

```
M:$+A*_/#_Mg
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJNOiQrQSpfLyNfTWciLCIiLCIiLCItcCBxd2VydHl1aW9wWyBhc2RmZ2hqa2w7IHp4Y3Zibm0sIl0=)

Answer (score 4):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2), 56 bytes

```
;=mF;W=pP;=s!=i~1;W>Lp=i+1i=s+*10A Gp iTs&<m=t/sLp=m tOm
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PW1GO1c9cFA7PXMhPWl+MTtXPkxwPWkrMWk9cysqMTBBIEdwIGlUcyY8bT10L3NMcD1tIHRPbSIsImNvZGVcbmdvbGZcbnN0YWNrXG5leGNoYW5nZSIsIjIuMCJd)

Because Knight doesn't support floating point values, it outputs the maximum average ord multiplied by \$10\$, as allowed by the rules:

> It may be rounded to any number (\$\ge1\$) of decimal places. If your language does not support floating points, you may output the average multiplied by 10.

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 34 bytes

```
!a=max(sum.(Int,a)./length.(a)...)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZBNbsIwEIXFtqdIHIoclA6JBBRUIXXbMwCVjOP8gGPTxCmhV-mGDYeC05AJRMqinc17I837RjO_520pU3Y6nUsTvcwuxGaLjFW0KDOgH8p4zIWRFCo2CdDaA7j3yWuP7vNUGamovSSJkFITzyIHncsQzeYoyNq1_ignCHwYP3XSXIcCM7GWEWphGN-hERVPmIq7JCfwpzDrpu13B2dX_edP1MGQ_rMY05MJvFojq5Zpq40RhkMX-nUQuTmWqd4vEcqKMIqT7U6-YfdT8e-NyrzHnuageQ1pNGiNP39w7w9rX3wD)

Comment: -1 byte with `@.`

Answer (score 4):

## Excel (ms365), 70 bytes

[image]

Formula in `F1`:

```
=MAX(MAP(A1:C1,LAMBDA(a,SUM(CODE(MID(a,SEQUENCE(LEN(a)),1)))/LEN(a))))
```

Comment: you can get this down to 68 bytes if you expect input in array format (eg. `={"hello","world","bye"}`) and use `#` to denote an array input (`map(A1#,...`)

Answer (score 4):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
$m▓╙
```

Input as a list of lists of characters.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TY9BDoIwFET33sKI1pjewI33aGoCIqBSUUBRr2E08XpcpE4/s2DxkmGYzwwubou8KjPvI9d/3/3n570xqlBa7UFJKmW1UZ0orWq6qbgJ1FPy1k5wu2MqHTwkcjrhJhOngWpBDEL@JG5ofNAp@PYM8tHXp9AbMJOLCGoOtvK0gFqBJbNX6I5/UrMxLL2BAzddgJHr0NZwd8bWsOIo@4b1a0m@RjvvIOFOBzS6/w)

**Explanation:**

```python
$     # Get the codepoint of each inner-most character of the (implicit) input-list
 m    # Map over each list of integers:
  ▓   #  Pop and push the average of the list
   ╙  # After the map: pop and push the maximum
      # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [MATLAB](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <strike>39</strike> 31 bytes

```matlab
@(s)max(cellfun(@(x)mean(x),s))
```

Matlab unfortunately doesn't convert strings ("") directly to ASCII values using the double function, and if converted to char type then a string array will be padded with spaces to make a proper matrix. As a result, the input is a cellstr type, which needs to be looped over using the cellfun function with an anonymous function that takes the average of the unicode values of the strings (''). The output is then the maximum of those values.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNYMzexQiM5NScnrTRPw0GjQjM3NTEPSOkUa2r@/w8A)

edit: -8 bytes thanks to Guiseppe

Comment: I think the (implicit) type conversion `+x` should work and be shorter than `double(x)`, at least in Octave: [try it online](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/NzUxT0NbPSM1JydfXfP/fwA)

Answer (score 4):

## T-SQL, 125 bytes

```sql
WITH C as(SELECT len(x)m,0b,*FROM @
UNION ALL SELECT m-1,b+ascii(right(x,m)),x
FROM C WHERE
m>0)SELECT max(b*1./len(x))FROM c
```

**[Try it online](https://dbfiddle.uk/mTX9gZl8)**

Answer (score 4):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 18 bytes

```
[:>./(1#.3&u:%#)&>
```

Accepts list of boxed strings

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxKdrKTk9fw1BZz1it1EpVWVPNDiJxs0eTKzU5I18hTUE9IzUnJ1_dWr08vygnBUgnVaaqwyWT81NSgWLp-TlpQKq4JDE5G0inViRnJOalI6lTdFAGiquoxgFJNS0NhERheWpRSWVpZn5BNFAqsTglLT0jKzvHGsipqkguS8rL1VGHuGnBAggNAA)

```
[:>./(1#.3&u:%#)&>
[:                  NB. cap, [: f g y -> f (g y)
                &>  NB. for each input item, result will be unboxed
     (         )    NB. monadic fork
              #     NB. length
         3&u:       NB. convert input to list of char codes
             %      NB. vectorized division
      1#.           NB. sum the result to compute average
  >./               NB. max item
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Raku](https://www.raku.org/), 27 bytes

```
*».&{.ords.sum/.chars}.max
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtf69BuPbVqvfyilGK94tJcfb3kjMSi4lq93MSK/9bFiZUKaRo2Gak5OfkK5flFOSkKSZWpdpr/AQ)

Edit: as per advice from @Steffan

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: This is actually 26 bytes (25 characters), since we count in bytes

Comment: We don't allow hardcoding the input into the code - the best way to take input in Raku is via a function. This only costs one byte, you can just add a `*` at the beginning to make it a WhateverCode block. :) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtf69BuPbVqvfyilGK94tJcfb3kjMSi4lq93MSK/9bFiZUKaRo2Gak5OfkK5flFOSkKSZWpdpr/AQ "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Steffan : Thanks and amended as per your advice.

Comment: `.chars` can be `.comb` or `.ords` for -1. I was trying to figure out a way of using a HyperWhatever, but I couldn't find something shorter

Answer (score 3):

## [Sequences](https://github.com/nayakrujul/sequences/), \$9 \log_{256}(96) \approx 7.41\$ bytes

```
[$v$aH]gM
```

#### Explanation

```js
[$v$aH]gM  // Implicit list of string input
[     ]    // Loop through the input list:
 $v$       //   Get a list of ords of each character
    aH     //   Get the average and append to `g`
       g   // Push the list `g`
        M  // Get the maximum value
           // Implicit output
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 48 bytes

```rb
->l{l.map{_1.chars.sum(&:ord)/_1.size.to_f}.max}
```

As the division of two integers in ruby gives an integer, and what was expected was a float, it's long :/
And `.fdiv` is one byte longer

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY5LDoJAEET3nkLjZ8AA6s5oNN4DPwFmBpCBwfkoSDyJGxL1UN5GOhoTXVV1v6p0X-9C-2V9o4v1QytqT59je8kq5qReXu0mThB5QjpSp8ZgxgU2R81OxmfiKL6jlyZVXD69W66VNKjroogwxpHVRicuGAbjlwRtNmbrGwk4JgBCziioVF6QgCFFczEL_-KdVRdgr78FGQyNX3w4EaFKHfPcBe5JTMNon7A5TOciOPpZakHl_Wpdv_UF)

Comment: 40 bytes: `->l{l.map{1.0*_1.bytes.sum/_1.size}.max}`

Comment: @Dingus, I think string sum won't work, as it wraps around with modulo, so it may pass given test cases, but not some big string

Comment: @KirillL. Thanks for pointing that out. You are right. I should've read the docs!

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>87</s></sup> <sup><s>86</s></sup> <sup><s>84</s></sup> 81 bytes.

```c
v;*p;f(**t,float*r){for(*r=0;p=*t;*r=fmax(*r,v*1./(p-*t++)))for(v=0;*p;)v+=*p++;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZDfboMgGMXv@xTMrQ2g3frvjpjsAfYG3ZZQBHVFYUjVzvjqcxQTk2a7WMrNdzic7/wS2JJJWqbDUBOsiYAY20hIRS02qBPKQGziFdExtsQpUdDWOVGN149PUC@xDUOE0CVXu5hrQHUYYx2GpB/y0oKC5iVEoJsBd3wvMLw6SUtm3nIZDCyv7Hr/BmLQgZcg41KqIHKqUUYmXh3O3M0V6MlYBP1KBBZjGRptbVydgME8fS1dfHq7Jm0mElMJ9/WpksKLylJ29Iq3LHP/8gd2cxt2O2Hvnu894mH@7ucCw9@U7W2U3UT5bLix51Ou9N5TaJWINPs4SuKvXy2rD2URXchX4N1/wf3wzYSkaTUsmx8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as an array of character arrays.

```
®xc /ZlÃñ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&header=bXE&code=rnhjIC9abMPx&input=WyJoZWxsbyIsIndvcmxkIiwiYnllIl0)

```
®xc /ZlÃñ     :Implicit input of 2D array of characters
®             :Map each sub-array Z
 x            :  Reduce by addition of
  c           :    Codepoints
    /         :  Divide by
     Zl       :    Length of Z
       Ã      :End map
        ñ     :Sort
              :Implicit output of last element
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 29 bytes

```
Max[Mean/@ToCharacterCode@#]&
```

[View it on Wolfram Cloud!](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/acdc57e3-3e30-449f-91e1-4fe95d3faafe)

Answer (score 3):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$6\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 4.939 bytes

```
]KemMC
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJdS2VtTUMiLCJbaGVsbG8sd29ybGQsYnllXSJd)

```
]KemMC
     C - Charcodes
  emM  - Mean of each
 K     - Sort
]      - Last
```

Comment: When maximum is two bytes long

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: `]K` should be one byte

Comment: Ah yes. Pu that on my todo list

Comment: Lol.. Didn't knew there were two of you: [Sʨɠɠan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/s%ca%a8%c9%a0%c9%a0an) and [Sʨɠɠan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107299/s%ca%a8%c9%a0%c9%a0an). The conversation in the comments above is pretty confusing if it would be only a single person. xD

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>81</s> <s>79</s> 56 bytes

```java
a->a.mapToDouble(s->s.chars().average().orElse(0)).max()
```

Input as a `Stream<String>` and output as an `OptionalDouble`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZVHLbsIwELzzFa77kF3A6rm0qJXaY@mB3hCVFscEB8dObSeQVnx7uiSgPrh4vJ7Z2dE6gwqGWbJupIEQyAto@9UjRNuo/BKkIpN9SUiGOlFGbcRrEbWzYJ5cuTCKSPZDhegV5GLawh2CtumYAB@hxa6HR4gQtSQTYsl9A8MxiByKN9dZsTAcByFX4APjAirlIVV4c/7ZBMVuOEf1lvFmtLcqsAWtDo6V0wnJMTzrps7mwLvgUYXI6EoZ4@iAbpw3CeKiVrSNdRRIlyh8T51ZIqCrXCOqLcax6T/t2cM5cheX73heXbO/5MdG@ViX2hUzpCEky3SVrc0Ii8@trBY2H9CThbTx2/4uvhDimH9ah6hy4cooCqSisb8W/ug91EFE17Ux4H16S2jfCnmq6n4HNfwwf9d8Aw)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->                  // Method with String-Stream parameter & OptionalDouble return-type
   a.map             //  Map over the input-Stream
        ToDouble(s-> //  and convert them to a Stream of Doubles
      s.chars()      //   Convert the String to an IntStream of its codepoint integers
       .average()    //   Then take the average of that IntStream (as OptionalDouble)
       .orElse(0))   //   And convert the OptionalDouble to double
                     //   (`.orElse(0)` is shorter than `.getAsDouble()`)
    .max()           //  After the map: leave the maximum (again as OptionalDouble)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>132</s> 108 bytes

```go
func f(S[]string)(m int){for a,s:=range S{a=0
for _,r:=range s{a+=int(r)}
if a=a*10/len(s);a>m{m=a}}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NZBNTsMwEIXX-BTG_MXFQNmhVkEcAanLqFRuYieh_gm2Q1usnIRNhMQhuAR7boPdpKs38zya-Z4_v0rd_zQ039CSQUlrBWrZaONuEZcOfbeO3zz8Cd6qHPJkkS2tM7UqcSJhrRz2XBtIiZ2lhqqwYOFpOgXRXBFzNK2n12mYTgzuQM0hTenkfnonmEosntNH6WVKuw4Y5lqjuvHm7-FmJEqwB9bCWQqz5RHAe1QxITQiEG21EUUs1nuGOgI9ynXBolFqwaNaFwLGgu3yKjINY6dPZ9E8v3iJcjlJrgb_bcuM27e1brL4QG3By-p1I-ax-9jl72slCQrEQ9AD2hjVQg9OngOhEyEdCX9mMQYdGFP1_aD_)

- -24 bytes by @Sʨɠɠan: return as an int, multiplied by 10

Comment: [108](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NZBNTsMwEIXX-BTG_MXFQNmhVkEcAanLqFRuYieh_gm2Q1usnIRNhMQhuAR7boPdpKs38zya-Z4_v0rd_zQ039CSQUlrBWrZaONuEZcOfbeO3zz8Cd6qHPJkkS2tM7UqcSJhrRz2XBtIiZ2lhqqwYOFpOgXRXBFzNK2n12mYTgzuQM0hTenkfnonmEosntNH6WVKuw4Y5lqjuvHm7-FmJEqwB9bCWQqz5RHAe1QxITQiEG21EUUs1nuGOgI9ynXBolFqwaNaFwLGgu3yKjINY6dPZ9E8v3iJcjlJrgb_bcuM27e1brL4QG3By-p1I-ax-9jl72slCQrEQ9AD2hjVQg9OngOhEyEdCX9mMQYdGFP1_aD_) (returns multiplied by 10)

Comment: I think that is only valid for languages that doesn't support floating point operations.

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

*-1 byte inspired by [Aiden Chow's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254368/16766)*

```
⌈´+´∘-⟜@¨÷≠¨
```

Anonymous tacit function; takes a list of strings and returns a float. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oyIwrTCtygrwrTDt+KJoCnCqC3in5xACgpGICJxd2VydHl1aW9wWyLigL8iYXNkZmdoamtsOyLigL8ienhjdmJubSwiCg==)

#### Explanation

```
⌈´+´∘-⟜@¨÷≠¨
          ≠¨  Length of each string
         ÷    Divide the following by the above:
  +´∘           Sum of
     -⟜@       Subtract null character from (each character in)
        ¨       Each string
⌈             Get the maximum of the resulting list of averages
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>48</s> 22 bytes

```arturo
$=>[map&=>average|max]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?U8nh0n)

Answer (score 3):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>166</s> 120 bytes

-46 thanks to the combined efforts of [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat) and [@jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt).

```cpp
#import<bits/stdc++.h>
auto f(auto a,float*r){*r=0;for(char*t:a){int u=0,s=0;for(;*t;u+=*t++)s++;*r=fmax(*r,(0.+u)/s);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rc7NUsIwEADgM32KWJRpmwoInEjL@B7OOBPS9EfSpiYbATt99tpERg9ycYZcdrPJ7resbR8LxoZhWtWtVJDsK9ALDRnDeF7uPGpAojxwgca5kBQiFXaRSpcklypgJVURbGnYVQ0gky5jfXkhERCD0wgwDjXGZGzJa3oKIhUHyzk24UKHpO8H21fTqglC1HnochyEFNdGAPF@yuNe262oNCTO3SHgGp5Qijq/5EJIP0b@USqR2WR/5n5PfkcG7nOMZt9jQ@JN3DwmDaAkuWg2c2XeZGKkJ1fNlTOZzLiVCilyGzVQdrAJP41/m@KKv7qNv3b@3fPUavcPrzbMouCvt76Nt3He@5ErOJtKti8WpDrLi/LtIIi9fZ7Yx76p4787bP65Qz98AQ)

### Original Answer:

Attempting to apply general-purpose programming to code golf doesn't seem to work out well.

```cpp
#import<bits/stdc++.h>
auto g(char*a){int t=0,s=0;for(a--;*++a;s++,t+=*a);return(0.0+t)/s;}auto f(std::list<char*>a){float m=0;for(char*t:a)m=m>g(t)?m:g(t);return m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7NUoMwFIXX9ikiVScQaFkTQN/DGWdCCAGbEEwutpXh2ZEw3emiq3N/zvnu5cOQSM6XZd/pwVjIqw7c0UHNCTm05Y6NYJDEvGU2YuHU9YCgSGNXpLQxFrMkoREhjDpCYiDF6qFWwGh7nB5SAuHR0XljNHiFZpnqHOQbrVxxjTIMkL7BtjFkLNSFLiWG8FVnXm5EpOm8@Ac063ocomn3sCG5GQHl@XphClqhlAliFJyNVbUvqqsI5tDvN7Poa0X/CXJTC2@XRjVeHTB@8oW4rG/18i7I49veR56eP7y8RPie0NdZWLiOnRnefYq5upHt50lR3/1c@HfV6/gvaF5@AQ)

#### Ungolfed:

```cpp
// Gets the average ord value of a string
auto g(char* a) {
    int t=0, s=0;             // Running total and size 

    for (a--;*++a;s++,t+=*a); // Loop until a equals 0 and add a onto the running total
    
    return (0.0+t) / s;       // Cast to float by adding 0.0 and divide the total by the size.
}

// "Main" function
auto f(std::list<char*> a) {
    float m = 0;           // Maximum value
    
    for (char* t : a) {    // Loop through all the strings in the list
        m = m>g(t)?m:g(t); // If m is greater than the output from the function, return m. Otherwise, return the output of the function
    }
    
    return m;              // m is the final result that we want
}
```

Comment: [120 bytes](https://tio.run/##rc7NUsIwEADgM32KWJRpmwoInEjL@B7OOBPS9EfSpiYbATt99tpERg9ycYZcdrPJ7resbR8LxoZhWtWtVJDsK9ALDRnDeF7uPGpAojxwgca5kBQiFXaRSpcklypgJVURbGnYVQ0gky5jfXkhERCD0wgwDjXGZGzJa3oKIhUHyzk24UKHpO8H21fTqglC1HnochyEFNdGAPF@yuNe262oNCTO3SHgGp5Qijq/5EJIP0b@USqR2WR/5n5PfkcG7nOMZt9jQ@JN3DwmDaAkuWg2c2XeZGKkJ1fNlTOZzLiVCilyGzVQdrAJP41/m@KKv7qNv3b@3fPUavcPrzbMouCvt76Nt3He@5ErOJtKti8WpDrLi/LtIIi9fZ7Yx76p4787bP65Qz98AQ)

Comment: or [108 bytes](https://tio.run/##pY/bcoIwEIbveYoUWwcCtp6uBJw@QN/AHiaGcKiBpGEBreOrl4bQ8UovOubm/zfZ3e8PlXKSUtp1o7yQQkFICwLZ2spLwNJvAq0ocfoKg09qEEi5x0QoB6toGmAItCYF2evab/Ds8cmREwye57pu3yUjPdb0nTJwGy/C0vOCk4aVlNcxQ2EuKlCMFGurR6KC5KXjoqOF9Em4IIAUq2oOgWWuWpoR9QEYAatgtnlDETqiFztjnAvb164VisfGbQ9M6xSdgmGZM/zCNZM@Gg973eG1gni1oqIGFIZ/xN7Zr6V9iTw/k6mImcGlgifGVEDozji21zNlej3G/MYYi3OMu@eRQd4/vBsdY@cqdXEjdXmmfrVMwaHOhdwYKqniJM0@dzww5feeNtuy8Pskl4Is/xXk1P3QhJO06ibtLw) for a direct port of my C answer.

Comment: Building on @ceilingcat [93 bytes](https://tio.run/##pY7dcoIwEIXveYoUWwcCTq16ZcT2AfoG9mdiCEiNJA1L0Dq@emkIHa/sRcfc7NnN7vkOU2qUM9a2RQlYkUxICsgQ26Es6GYYYlqDRDo8ZlIHWCdjohIMxNwnaoQhimI7w3ppHrGem7BbMnbHmoUmSrCKInJqB0XJRJ1ytChkBZrT3dLzOsiOFmUQoqOH7Ovpmle1AOK5UcM2VL8DRsAreFi9ogQd0bO/4UJIP7aqkVqkTq0P3NYxOpHeLOjzh@4yRsPeN@x/K0jncyZrQIvFL7FT/kvpXyJPzmQmU@5wuRSZExVQtnWK7@1Nmf8dY3JljOk5xs3TwCFv795cHeLgT@r0SursTP1suIZDXUi1clRapVm@@dgK4tqvPTPrchd3SS4Fmf0ryKn9ZpmgedWOmh8)

Comment: [92 bytes](https://tio.run/##pY7LcoIwFIb3PEWKrUMCTq26MmL7AH0De5kYAlIjScMBtI6vXhpCx5VddDyb85/r93OtRxnnbZsXQDRNpWKAamorlAZdj0DEKlDI4GOqTEBMPKY6JkCD@j7WIwJhiJfEPNpBPR/jbqe2K/YXrsOY6DCkp3aQF1xWiUCLXJVgBNstPa9j7FheBBgdPWSjhxtRVhKo51oN3zDzDgSBKOFh9YpidETP/kZIqfzIqkYZmTi1Pgibx@hE@2dBbx@7ywgN@7@4n5aQzOdcVYAWi19ip/yXwr9EnpzJXCXC4TIlUydKYHzrlNjbmyL728bkShvTs42bp4FD3t69uTwkwZ/U6ZXU2Zn62QgDhypXeuWorEzSbPOxldSVX3ter4td1Dm5ZGT2LyOn9punkmVlO2p@AA)

Comment: Building on @jdt [90 bytes](https://tio.run/##pY/LcoIwFIb3PEWKrUMCTq26MmL7AH0De5kYAlIjScMBtI6vXhpCx5VddMwi5z85l@8P13qUcd62qVQMUE3zAlAa2JsQiFgFChl8TJUJiInHXZXomAAN6vtYjwiEIV4S82iL9XyMu77athFNcR3GRIchPbWDvOCySgRa5KoEI9hu6XkdZ8fyIsDo6CF7egNGlJUE6rmnhm@YeQeCQJTwsHpFMTqiZ38jpFR@ZFWjjEycWh@EjWN0ov2yoP8CdpMRGvZ7cV8tIZnPuaoALRa/xE75L4V/iTw5k7lKhMNlSqZOlMD41imxtzNF9reNyZU2pmcbN08Dh7y9e3NxSII/qdMrqbMz9bMRBg5VrvTKUVmZpNnmYyupS7/2vF4Xu6hzcsnI7F9GTu03TyXLynbU/AA "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ceilingcat, nice! I did not know that you can declare a variable in the middle part of a `for` loop.

Comment: Building on @ceilingcat [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##pY7BcoIwEIbvPEWKrUMCTq16MmL7AH0DazsxBKRGQsMCWsdXL4bQ8VI9OM1l/2Sz@308zwcJ5w0rQaE4bBZLz0YIbNH4EEvFAFU0VtojOhzSNAOShwSoVz2G@YCA7@M50c@mWU2HuP1XmW8kp7jyQ5L7Pj021HF6acZlGQk0S1UBWrDt3HHMMrRlaeZhdHCQOR1Oi6KUYIbap5qvmf4AgkAU8LRYohAd0Ku7FlIqNzCpVlpGNq32wtQhOtJumee1tgTbyQD1u7246xYQTadclYBms19im9y3zDXkC@zRmc1VJCwwUTK2oQDGNzaJnZnJkusio9tE/miMzxp3Lz2LvH94t7VPvKvU8T@pkzP1qxYa9mWq8oWlsiKKk/XnRlJ7/d7xapVtg9bkksjkNpFj88NjyZKiGdQn)

Comment: also [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##pY7BUsIwEEDv/YpYlGnTMlbgRAj6Af4BohPStFRCU9NtCzL8ujVNHWYcuTjksm83u/uWF8Uo5bxlFSiU0Ha58ixCaIP2j4nSfammWNOIWC4oBuLV97QYYQgCf4H1o/mtZ5Hf9demDxfErwOKiyAgp5Y4ziDLuaxigeaZKkELtls4TpYD2rEs93x0dJB5iVQMkBZlJcEMdaWGb5h@A4xAlPCwXCGKjujZ3QgplRsaapSWsaX1QZgYoRPpl3l2JETDfqHfl0uIZzOuKkDz@Y@qI/cldy8px2clV7GwnlTJxEIJjG8tib2ZydML/vGV/snZf/M0sK7bu1cbh9j7q5tcqZuedR@N0HCoMlUsrY6VcZJu3reS2PRzz@t1vgu7E35dMP3fBaf2iyeSpWU7ar4B) but without the ugly casting.

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
000\&l3-,:{:@)?$&0(?n1[!
"(?\+:i:"!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38DAIEYtx1hXx6raykHTXkXNQMM@zzBakUtJwz5G2yrTSknx///EpGSF5KREheTkZAA)

Words are separated by spaces (or characters less than space like newline). This uses the length of the stack rather than a counter to get the length of the word.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
▲moAmc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0Tbn5jrnJ////j1bKSM3JyVfSUSrPL8pJAdJJlalKsQA)

Outputs the highest average ord value as an exact fraction.

```
▲moAmc
 mo    # map 2 functions over each element of input
    mc #   get ord values of each character
   A   #   get the average of those
▲      # output the maximum.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 58 bytes

```javascript
a=>Math.max(...a.map(s=>eval(Buffer(s).join`+`)/s.length))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/dasJAEIXv@xQptN1daycRalBKpPS@TyAWx83@JK67aXaNsS@fuiC0mLk558DMx5kaO/S8rZrwYl0pBlkMWKw@MWg4YE8BAC@mob5YiQ4N/ThKKVrqGdSustvnLUs9GGFV0IwN3FnvjADjFJV0TbQwxpFpQk6uNWU0u7Mgm@RmGEvSNJnNMni9u0XwS6t4qJyRUX1Avo9G9FyjVVfcFZHlsBgh7t/j/sPjV5SnCR0X@NdiPoc8zwFGlO@TaMP5WLlmHTnoS6l0vTdvMf30vNvZw5Rs/n5ZZkuA4Rc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 8 bytes (16 nibbles)

```
`/.$/*+.$o$10,$]
```

Nibbles works only in integers, so this returns the maximum average ord multiplied by 10 (and rounded-*down* to a whole number).

```
`/.$/*+.$o$10,$]
  .$              # map over each input string
       .$         #   map over each character
         o$       #     getting it's ord 
      +           #   sum them all
     *     10     #   multiply by 10
    /             #   and divide by    
             ,$   #   the length of the string
`/                # finally, fold over the list
               ]  #   getting the max of each pair
```

[image]

Comment: OP said in the sandbox that you have to round, not floor or ceil: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/25304#comment78875_25304

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan - Hm, I only read the challenge itself; I've asked OP to specify whether rounding-down is Ok or not...

Comment: @Sʨɠɠan - rounding-down seems to be Ok with the OP, thank goodness: rounding-to-nearest would have increased the already-bloated code by another 50% to 12 bytes: ```/.$/+/*+.$o$100,$5 10]``` (mutiply by 100, integer-divide by length, add 5, integer-divide by 10)...

Answer (score 2):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 38 bytes

```
"dup S>c0\+ fold rev len /"map0\| fold
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin) This might be a good case for adding sum/prod/min/max functions to sclin, the fold construct is alright but it could be better.

For testing purposes:

```
["hello" "world" "bye"] ; 30N>d n>o
"dup S>c0\+ fold rev len /"map0\| fold
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
( dup S>c 0 \+ fold rev len / ) map 0 \| fold
```

Assuming input list *xs*.

- `(...) map` map over *xs*...

  - `dup S>c` get codepoints
  - `0 \+ fold` sum
  - `rev len /` divide by length (i.e. average)
- `0 \| fold` maximum

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/), 63 bytes

```
for w;c=&&for a (${(s::)w})((c+=#a,o=1.*c/$#w,m=o>m?o:m))
<<<$m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBDoIwFATQPaf4BqStEo1boOo9TExKaanS8hXUKoSzI2wmM2/6zkyasiFADo5PGlvwmeRxvDQBNBpol6bMj4xSueWhSJAfdhu5j0KfOI5Hd8LUMRbkeR65aQw0GGUtgsfWllD81CwSSwUVWg3dS8ga1Fca0VTLRVbnkACJ1tc54w0liz29al@/9w0fl1lFV@rK3GubzaP/yk/RuIRMfw)
 <sub><s>[65b](https://tio.run/##FclNDoIwFATgPad4BrQtEo1boOo9TExqaUFpeQpo@QlnR9hMZr4ZmmLWlI0ecrB81liDS0bJk7UJoMFImzhmbmKUyj33RYT8dAjlMfBdZDme7QVjy1gyeWmaBnaePA2FMgbBYW0yePRqEYmZghyNhqYVsgTVyUJU@XqRzdUnQILtfcldSMlqH6fqtv8@8X1bVDSZzotXaZJlDJ38PSobkfkP)</s>  <s>[74b](https://tio.run/##FYlBDoIwFAX3nOIbqm3RaNxSUO9hMKmlBbX1K6BVCWfHsnmZmfdr69Ew3keYg8tHgw140atcTCSBkZ61acr9wBlTy5wcY1lwLjDQdp2oDYl9IVww3Lk9pq4QQ5RlGXHjEBmotbUIHhtbwvmrQ1FYaqjQGmg7qW6gP6qW92q66OwQU6Bkfgq7SBid2tPrpvu@Lvg4hirb0lT19WZFkN9Hvc93t6LjHw)</s></sub>

`for w;` implicitly iterates over the arguments `($@)`.
`for a (${(s::)w})` iterates over each letter in word `w`.
`c` accumulates the ascii sum
`o` is the average ord for `w`
`m` is the maximum `o` found

<sub>Edit: Saved 6 bytes by chaining 3 math expressions in the parentheses`((,,))`!</sub>

Answer (score 2):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), <s>43</s> <s>38</s> <s>36</s> 30 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)

Originally based on [TKirishima's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254232/11261).

```
:*&:/%[:bytes|:sum,:+@|Q]|:max
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboW-6y01Kz0VaOtkipLUotrrIpLc3WstB1qAmNrrHITKyCKbi4uKC0p1nCLjlbPSM3JyVfXUVAvzy_KSQExkipT1WNjNbngSpLzU1JBEun5OWkgurgkMTkbxEitSM5IzEtHU67ooAySVFGNA1FqWhqo0oXlqUUllaWZ-QXRIPnE4pS09Iys7BxrEK-qIrksKS9XB6QF4tQFCyA0AA)

### Explanation

```
:* & :/ % [ :bytes | :sum, :+@ | Q ] | :max

:* &                                         # Map with...
            :bytes | :sum                    #   Sum of bytes
     :/ % [              ,         ]         #   Divided by
                           :+@ | Q           #   Length converted to float
                                     | :max  # Get max
```

Comment: 38 bytes using `bytes.sum` instead of `chars.sum(&:ord)`: `:map+:/%[:bytes|:sum,:size|:to_f]|:max`

Comment: @Steffan Good catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>19</s> 14 bytes

```
{:d_:+\,/}%$W=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBDoIwFAWvUr9gkJK4h5BwAhNWLgpiaQsIhSqggISz10Y3bzKTx2ra6lWvPs98nHinzbYuod78OCAEKiGlAgST6iU3zBcBKSLAFBdGSyULg2GkrDEUM6toV/4vu2hvkmVfzR5c59eek@jH5XVXD2IqHXhRVnUjAyOfmb3zrvUgTdcshsKB6AZHwBhQiAAneLPPrv4C)

A function which takes an input as an array.
Link includes test cases.

## Explanation

```
{:d_:+\,/}%$W= # function which takes an array as input
{        }%    # for each value in the input array...
 :d            # short map `:` the operator `d` to convert into an array of `d`oubles
   _:+         # duplicate and sum
      \        # swap
       ,       # get the length of the array
        /      # divide, giving the average
           $   # perform a $ort on the resulting array
            W= # and get index `W` (shorthand for `-1`), which is the last value of the sort, or the max
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <sup><s>10</s></sup> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é)u6║"⌂w╙
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82297536ba227f77d3&i=%5B%22hello%22+%22world%22+%22bye%22%5D)

This is a [PackedStax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md) program, which unpacks to the following:

```
{:V}kTlE:_
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7B%3AV%7DkTlE%3A_&i=%5B%22hello%22+%22world%22+%22bye%22%5D)

## Explanation (unpacked)

```
{  }k      # map the following over all the values in the input
 :V        # get the mean of the array
     T     # Get the maximum of this map
      l    # The output is a fraction, so it must be listified
       E   # Explode this list onto the stack
        :_ # Float division
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 18 bytes

```matlab
@(x)max(mean(+x'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYtbDoIwFET/XQXGR1t1B8SEfRBNLu1ti5QWKUJx8zX3y@jXnMmZCXKCGXOueBJFD4n3CJ6fExMi6yv4uFFtHLjmNbPoXGBlwZYwOkXQrMhuQnwnMigkYYLTlHEC2RFgkha8@Ztvqx3J/eFOcTzxX/1ccJzWVxuGmjxEpY19dK6k9k5ybnx/oUv@AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 94 bytes

I tried two approaches here, both of which ended up having the same byte count.

### List of Arguments

```lua
m=0 for i=1,#arg do n=0s=arg[i]s:gsub('.',load'n=s.byte(...)+n')m=math.max(m,n/#s)end print(m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcbBCsMgDADQXxF6UJlk3XWQLxk7KLpWMHEYy9avz/ZOrx1RlXA1rz5MxVtY4thM7oZxFfz/UZ9y3@RIzoINrcdsGQXSOYsDAH9h6wkpzh0ofh0Fvi7iC2fzHpWnI6@qe2mt66ePljWd5Qc)

### Space Delimited String

```lua
m=0(...):gsub('%S+',load'n=0s=...s:gsub(".",load"n=s.byte(...)+n")m=math.max(m,n/#s)')print(m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JctRCoMwDIDhq0jHaIOS@TzIKXaCFsscNOkwFefpM9HX/@MvazRjGgMiwvOtawr@/ur9UGqcvNCodIhe4tCd3Qkppr3l8@rFARPHNiPHX@BBHjcFD9/lIy0wmNmcS6ndVpcydWnPfw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 15 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
/↥∵(÷⊃⧻/+-@\0⊔)
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgL-KGpeKItSjDt-KKg-Knuy8rLUBcMOKKlCkKCmYgeyJoZWxsbyIgIndvcmxkIiAiYnllIn0gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIyAxMTAuNApmIHsiY29kZSIgImdvbGYiICJzdGFjayIgImV4Y2hhbmdlIn0gICAgICMgMTA2LjgKZiB7IiFAIyIgIiQlXiIgIiYqKCJ9ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAjIDU1LjY2NwpmIHsicXdlcnR5dWlvcFsiICJhc2RmZ2hqa2w7IiAienhjdmJubSJ9ICMgMTEwLjkwOQ==)

```
/↥∵(÷⊃⧻/+-@\0⊔)
  ∵(          )  # map over input
             ⊔   # unbox a string
         -@\0    # subtract null character
    ÷⊃⧻/+        # mean
/↥               # max
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υ∕ΣＥι℅κＬιＩ⌈υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBDsIgEADvvILjkuALPOrFRGOTvmADK2xKoaFL7e8Rj5OZcRGrK5h6/0ZOpOGRtyazVM4BjNFT2yM0q@98sCeY2wov3ICtflfPGRMsxhirn5SDROABVzWNW@CGu4z45HVM7S96d8WTCiV91C7oFkWni5gDqX450g8) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated strings. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ
```

Repeat until the end of the list is reached...

```
⊞υ∕ΣＥι℅κＬι
```

... take the ordinals of the characters in the string, and divide their sum by the string's length.

```
Ｉ⌈υ
```

Output the maximum average.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>71</s> 70 bytes

```python
lambda l:max(map(lambda s:mean(map(ord,s)),l))
from statistics import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzNDoIwEITvPgXGHwrh5g1j4nugJqU/UGm7ta0CvjyyxsSE08zOfLNujC3YwyRPl0lTU3Oa6NLQgRjqyC8IpRHUfhPwvAhZVugsW0kPJgmRRhWiYiFRxoGP@eS8spFIUqWt0BrSIkl78JqjqUeRXuftn2HABTYNaIk6P2QdGjGwltpmya/PG2y3uxvKPieL/tELH8enAlchQAOXTXvv9BGv98BetTUFbqYP)

[*-1 thanks to The Thonnu*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254224/maximum-average-ord/255713#comment566416_255713)

Comment: You can remove the space for 70 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzNDoIwEITvPgXGHwrh5g1j4nugJqU/UGm7ta0CvjyyxsSE08zOfLNujC3YwyRPl0lTU3Oa6NLQgRjqyC8IpRHUfhPwvAhZVugsW0kPJgmRRhWiYiFRxoGP@eS8spFIUqWt0BrSIkl78JqjqUeRXuftn2HABTYNaIk6P2QdGjGwltpmya/PG2y3uxvKPieL/tELH8enAlchQAOXTXvv9BGv98BetTUFbqYP "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @TheThonnu Feel free to vote on this tomorrow too :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `G`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
€m
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMiU4MiVBQ20mZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lNUInY29kZSclMkMlMjAnZ29sZiclMkMlMjAnc3RhY2snJTJDJTIwJ2V4Y2hhbmdlJyU1RCZmbGFncz1H)

Take the `m`ean of `€`ach string in the (implicit) input list (this automatically converts to codepoints). Then, take the `G`reatest item.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes

```
eᵐµṀ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FitTH26dcGjrw50NS4qTkouhogtu1kcrZaTm5OQr6SgolecX5aSAGEmVqUqxXNFKyfkpqSB-en5OGoguLklMzgYxUiuSMxLz0iGqFB2UQWIqqnEgSk1LAyxaWJ5aVFJZmplfEA0STixOSUvPyMrOsQbxqiqSy5LycnWUYiHuAAA)

```
eᵐµṀ
e       Ord
 ᵐ      Map
  µ     Mean
   Ṁ    Maximum
```