# Last odd digit of power of 2

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence

### Task

Given \$n\$, output position of the last odd digit in the decimal representation of \$2^n\$ (counting from the end).

### Rules

- There are no odd digits for \$n=1,2,3,6,11\$ \$(2, 4, 8, 64, 2048)\$ - you may output anything that is not a positive integer for them (no need to be consistent).
- You choose whether to handle \$n=0\$.
- Standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) [I/O rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

### Test-cases

```
    n answer   (2^n)
    1     NA       2
    2     NA       4
    3     NA       8
    4      2      16
    5      2      32
    6     NA      64
    7      3     128
    8      2     256
    9      2     512
   10      4    1024
   11     NA    2048
   12      2    4096
   13      2    8192
   14      3   16384
   15      3   32768
   16      2   65536
   17      2  131072
   18      3  262144
   19      6  524288
   20      2 1048576
```

*Inspired by [this Mathematics SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4714518/347293) and comments on [OEIS A068994](https://oeis.org/A068994).*

Comment: Is it acceptable if fhe code is affected by floating-point inaccuracies when representing `2^n` for `n` large?

Comment: @LuisMendo I'll say yes, no problem. (I guess it affects bigger test-cases than those provided?)

Comment: Yes, that does not affect current test cases

Comment: 14 answers and 7 votes... 
Imho you don’t have to vote for everything, but if you answer...

Comment: @lesobrod - I have no hard feelings towards the community here. Simple challenges like this one very often attract many answers and don't tend to gather many upvotes.

Comment: @pajonk  Yes, but for beginners it may be frustrated

Comment: @lesobrod That's one of my pet peeves here. How can a challenge be worth answering but not worth upvoting?

Comment: Could we get clarity on what "you may output anything that is not a positive integer for them" means? May we error rather than output? May we never halt?

Comment: Does "counting from the end" imply we must use ordinals (one indexing) or may we use zero indexing (i.e. one less than the given outputs, and not output a non-negative when all digits are even)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I'll allow erroring, but I'd like solutions to terminate ([best reference I could find on Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/55372)). Counting may start from 0 - for me that's covered in standard sequence I/O rules.

Comment: @LuisMendo easily.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES7), 35 bytes

Returns `NaN` if there's no odd digit. Supports \$n=0\$.

```javascript
n=>(g=k=>k?k&1||1+g(k/10):+g)(2**n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZBDoIwEAXQPaf4KzNDFShLcfAsBGiDJTMGjBvx7DW@1XsM72Eft@X5uqhNcw6SVXqKkqRP93Tyx@FdpFT7hq8uMrVlqZyDbaQQNB0UN0H7j3OMTwGMprutc7VaJD0jkDJ3xTf/AA)

#### Commented

```javascript
n => (        // n = input
  g = k =>    // g = recursive function looking for an odd digit in k
  k ?         // if k is not zero:
    k & 1 ||  //   stop and return 1 if the least significant bit is set
    1 +       //   otherwise, increment the final result
    g(k / 10) //   and do a recursive call with k / 10
              //   note that we rely on arithmetic underflow to stop the
              //   recursion if the LSB is never set
  :           // else:
    +g        //   no odd digit found: return NaN, which will propagate
              //   all the way to the initial call
)(2 ** n)     // initial call to g with k = 2 ** n
```

---

## JavaScript (ES7), 30 bytes

A simpler version that throws an error if there's no odd digit.

```javascript
n=>(g=k=>k&1||1+g(k/10))(2**n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBDoIwFET3nGLCQvtpVGCL5S5NLaiQX/IhJgY4ey0bM5tJ3pt524@dnbym5cLh4WNnIptW9WYw7XCqtq3SvRpuVUmk6qJgil0QxTAoGzDuBvVRtCasGbDIFyvEz0noFFODHc4u7qk8/UHuRYLkiaWFCzyH0V/H0KdbjXOKPkRqsj3@AA)

Comment: I guess `'111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111k=>k?k&1||1+g(k/10):g'` is also not an integer and valid as didn't find output

Answer (score 8):

## Excel, 50 bytes

```
=XMATCH(1,MOD(MID(2^A1,1+LEN(2^A1)-ROW(A:A),1),2))
```

Input in cell `A1`. Outputs an `#N/A` error if no odd digit exists.

*Edit: JvdV's wonderfully creative use of passing an array to `TEXTBEFORE` means that we can employ alternatives such as:*

```
=1+LEN(TEXTAFTER(2^A1,{1,3,5,7,9},-1))
```

*for just 38 bytes.*

Comment: Nice! I've just stumbled across this post and puzzled a bit. For 47 bytes (and probably a substantial speed increasement) you could try: `=LEN(2^A1)-LEN(TEXTBEFORE(2^A1,{1,3,5,7,9},-1))` which would still output `#N/A` if not applicable.

Comment: @JvdV Fantastic use of `TEXTBEFORE`! That's significantly different from my solution, so suggest you post it as a separate answer. Looking into it, could you also use `=1+LEN(TEXTAFTER(2^A1,{1,3,5,7,9},-1))` for just 38 bytes?

Comment: Yes that should work because there should always be an even number at the end of the `2^n`. Therefore `TEXTAFTER()` should correctly parse an error if no odd number is present. Please, I don't want to intervene with your answer but I insist on you just adding this into your current post for future reference. Perfectly fine with me!

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby, 31 bytes

```ruby
->n{(2**n).digits.index &:odd?}
```

0-indexed; no result returns `nil`.

I've been programming Ruby for about a year, and really enjoying it. As this example shows, it's possible to be concise and human readable.

`->n{ ... }` is the syntax for creating a lambda. It's not super elegant, but most of the time you're writing methods and not lambdas in Ruby anyways.

`.digits` already returns an array of digits starting with the least significant.

`.index` will search for an item if given an item, but it can also take a tester function, as it does here.

`.odd?` returns whether a number is odd. Prefacing a symbol with `&` creates a function that calls the method associated with that symbol. So `&:odd?` is equivalent to `->(number) { number.odd? }`.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: In Ruby, you don't need the parentheses in lambdas' parameter lists, so you can use `->n{(2**n).digits.index &:odd?}` just fine

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Thanks

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,c=1:2**n/c%2or-~f(n,c%2**n*10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcq7DoIwGIbh/buKLoRDMPKXMwmbrl6AG2IJTbBtaj2weOsVJ5d3ePKa1c1ace@nfhlul@vAVDr21PEkUfsx4NruPlO0WfCThLLYv2a5CEYdmLPrVmasVI5NkVTm4aI4BhPvURjHzsLqg3zKu9TqaK22/zs8aSVCT@DIUaBEhRoNWlAGIhAH5aACVIIqUA1qQC149gU)

Function that terminates with `ZeroDivisionError` for no output. This happens when the power-of-10 `c` that we're using as a divisor is a multiple of `2**n`, which causes `c%2**n` to reset to 0. This first happens for `c=10**n`, which is bigger than `2**n` so we're already out of digits.

A probably-cheating version instead terminates with `RuntimeError` for exceeding the maximum recursion depth, though usually we pretend this doesn't exist since it would also trigger for very large inputs that should produce an output.

**36 bytes**

```python
f=lambda n,c=1:2**n/c%2or-~f(n,c*10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcq7DoIwGIbh/buKfzEcopG/nEkYXR28A8QSmkDbNCXK4q1XNpd3ePLa3c9GixCmfhnW52sgfR577kSa6ut4EsZdvlN8WMpZEt6zWiRxB/JuP0rWKe1pipW2m4@TBCQ/o7SeHpv2apU354z7j9HdaBkFhkCOAiUq1GjQgjMwgwU4BxfgElyBa3ADbiGyHw)

Comment: non cheating [37](https://tio.run/##Rcq7DoIwAAXQ/X5FF8MjELlFngmjq5M/gFgCCbZNU6Ms/np1cznTsbtfjJYhzMM2Pm73UehsGtjLNNXH6SCNyz9zrHNmU1ol4bWsmxLsIbzbfwrrVu3FHK/aPn2cJBDqPSnrxXW36uyccf8VXYxWUSAkSpxQoUaDFh1YgAQlWIInsAJrsAFbsIMsvg)

Answer (score 7):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 32 bytes

```julia
!x=prod(findmax(digits(2^x).%2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X7HCtqAoP0UjLTMvJTexQiMlMz2zpFjDKK5CU0/VSFPzf0FRZl5JTp6ehoaBlZGBpoKerZ2CniKEo/kfAA)

1-indexed, works for `0`, and returns `0` for no odd digit

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 46 bytes

```haskell
(succ<$>).findIndex(odd.ord).reverse.show.(2^)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY69bsMwDIT3ewoOGeyhgun8B2mWZinQTt0LqBYTC7GlQFLS9uld2ejQcjp@4N2x1fEiXTcMtr/6kOiok1ZPrQ74C15sTP/Aq/7@EKDX1tEjGQ/K00miINo8u5ThqGi3o7cUrDvTw4Eyn@6sSxJ0k2hGN9dZJ5EU9fpKRWz9Z9an4Pupgaq8FfHWNPvZoVQn63K4ka/CG6N8MKUKcpcQRY1OVdTvZTb8/jDKKX0YKjBqzLHAEiusscEWnCGDa/AcvAAvwSvwGrwBb1FX@AE)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `gA`, <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
Ef∷ṘT
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJnQSIsIiIsIkVm4oi34bmYVCIsIiIsIjFcbjJcbjNcbjRcbjVcbjZcbjdcbjhcbjlcbjEwXG4xMVxuMTJcbjEzXG4xNFxuMTVcbjE2XG4xN1xuMThcbjE5XG4yMCJd)

`-2` thanks to @lyxal!

Comment: That's roughly what I came up with too. Nice job!

Comment: You can use the g flag to get a 6 byter

Comment: Also, answers can be 0-indexed apparently, so no need for the `›` either. Hence you'd have `Ef∷ṘT` with `g` flag

Comment: I don’t really like flags for golfing
But I missed a 0-indexed permission, so let it all be together ;)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
oRÅΔÉ
```

0-indexed. Outputs `-1` if there are no odd digits. Also works for \$n=0\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/P@hw67kphzv//ze0BAA) or [verify the first 26 test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9kemySn72SwqO2SQpK9n7/84MOt56bcrjzf63OfwA).

**Original 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) approach:**

```
oSÉRƶ0Kß
```

1-indexed. Outputs an empty string if there are no odd digits. Also works for \$n=0\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/P/hwZ9CxbQbeh@f//29oCQA) or [verify the first 26 test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9kemySn72SwqO2SQpK9n7/84MPdwYd22bgfXj@f53/AA).

**Explanation:**

```python
o         # Push 2 to the power of the (implicit) input-integer
 R        # Reverse it
  ÅΔ      # Find the first 0-based index that's truthy for, or -1 if none are:
    É     #  Is the digit odd?
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

```python
o         # Push 2 to the power of the (implicit) input-integer
 S        # Convert it to a list of digits
  É       # Check for each digit whether it's odd (1 if odd; 0 if even)
   R      # Reverse this list
    ƶ     # Multiply each value by its 1-based index
     0K   # Remove all 0s
       ß  # Pop and keep the minimum, or an empty string if the list was empty
          # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>46</s> <s>45</s> 53 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @The Thonnu*
*+8 bytes so it always terminates (added `%(i-2*x)`)*

```python
i=2**input()
x=0
while~i/10**x%2%(i-2*x):x+=1
print x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWSEsrM6@gtERDk6vC1oCrPCMzJ7UuU9/QQEurQtVIVSNT10irQtOqQtvWkKugKDOvRKHi/39DAwA)

Zero indexed, gives a `ZeroDivisionError` for \$n=1,2,3,6,11\$.

Comment: You can change the `//` to `/` for -1.

Comment: Ah, my brain was still halfway stuck in python 3, thanks :)

Comment: I feel like this should not be allowed, there is an explicit instruction not to output a positive integer when no digits are odd, this is like working around that ruling by never halting. (Also, how long does one wait before knowing the result?) If you error at the point it become too long I feel that should be acceptable.

Comment: Unfortunately, [OP has said solutions must terminate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/261908/last-odd-digit-of-power-of-2/261910#comment575049_261908)

Comment: Fixed so it complies

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda n:`[int(c)%2for c in`2**n`[::-1]]`.find('1')/3
```

An unnamed function that accepts a non-negative integer, \$n\$, and returns the 0-indexed position of the last odd digit of \$2^n\$, or \$-1\$ if all the digits are even.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FczNCoQgGEbhfVfxbUKNfsiJFkLdSAVajZNQbyFtunrHzvrhXM@9nZDBdmPYzTGvhqD04HDzRaTSnp4WctAyy6AHpYp6mnRpHVbOaiaqT3gJIiFv8PvythEqodjl44SQE@t6lpPlEOEP)**

Note: this actually gets scuppered at \$n=63\$ when long ints come into play and the representation of `2**n` acquires a trailing `L`. However, this is about where floating point errors would creep in with division-based methods anyway (this errors while they may start giving incorrect results). This can be dealt with by inserting `if'L'>c` between the `]]` for \$60\$.

Answer (score 5):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 40 bytes

```arturo
$=>[index reverse map digits^2&=>[&%2]1]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?LnPBpN)

0-indexed; no result returns `null`.

```
$=>[            ; a function where input is assigned to &
    ^2&         ; two raised to the input power
    digits      ; get its digits as a list
    map         ; map over the digits...
    =>[&%2]     ; ...modulo two
    reverse     ; reverse
    index ... 1 ; get the index of the leftmost 1
]               ; end function
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>49</s> 47 bytes

```
#&@@Reverse@IntegerDigits[2^#]~Position~_?OddQ&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcixCsIwEADQ3a8oBDIplI6FagYRnFrbMUQJ6SU9sBdITsf8esQ3vt3yBrtldLb6ZmiqkErN8IWUQd2JIUC6YkDOunsKU6aYkTFSeV3GdX3IOnqvbx9y/@z7/I5M5jAlJNbidPZKGFkWZ6nMlgLo9ti1pv4A)
`-2` thanks to @att

Comment: [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcixCsIwEADQ3a8oBDIplI6FagYRnFrbMUQJ6SU9sBdITsf8esQ3vt3yBrtldLb6ZmiqkErN8IWUQd2JIUC6YkDOunsKU6aYkTFSeV3GdX3IOnqvbx9y/@z7/I5M5jAlJNbidPZKGFkWZ6nMlgLo9ti1pv4A)

Answer (score 4):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 36 bytes

```
n->valuation(x*Pol(digits(2^n)%2),x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN1XydO3KEnNKE0sy8_M0KrQC8nM0UjLTM0uKNYzi8jRVjTR1KjRhatPyizTyFGwVDHQUjIC4oCgzrwQooKSgawck0jTyNDWhahcsgNAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `M`, 5 [bytes](Https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
OdɗrV
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kq9S7IKlpSVpuhbL_FNOTi8KW1KclFwMFVqwyNAAwgIA) or [verify the first 20 test cases](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMEqI4MjG13UObUPLVpaWpKma7HMP-Xk9KKwJcVJycWLfQ8thoguWAChAQ)

0-indexed. Outputs `[]` if there is no odd digit. Works for \$n=0\$.

##### Explanation

```python
OdɗrV  # Implicit input
O      # Push 2 ** input
 d     # Convert to digits
  ɗ    # Each mod 2
   r   # Reverse the list
    V  # Truthy indices
       # Take the minimum
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 42 bytes

```bash
i=$[2**n] i=${i#${i%[13579]*}}; echo ${#i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@kkKeQmadQbainZ2RQa62Qks@loFBQlJlXkqagrmqUElOirqCS9z/TViXaSEsrL1YByKrOVAZi1WhDY1Nzy1itWqC21OSMfAWVauXM2v8p@Xmp/wE)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 30 bytes

```r
\(n)match(1,2^n%/%10^(0:n)%%2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHynPyU_AIj26WlJWm6FvtiNPI0cxNLkjM0DHWM4vJU9VUNDeI0DKzyNFVVjTQhijYXJxYU5FRqGFoZGehAtENlFiyA0AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 53 bytes

Thanks for the comment to save so many bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BS8NAEIXv@ysepcIu1iXmGGyh3jx4EvEgUsZ0E1fS2TA7VKXkt8dt9TDDvHkf7@WWBprjYUyiyGfhiTkpaUzsleIgoTUmvX@GVvFIkXEywD50OBRhSfrcYCtCP69PKpH7N9fgmaNifSGBLoll3N2ggibUlfv/A2PhdWCbF0teYXnqLLtp4S7uZM5jjjSgax5Y15uySuZ8H/ty2dr5MX3ZnfOa/oq9hGOQHHzkffh@@QgS7O6q3lTu@naezPwL)

1-indexed. "return 0" means missing odd numbers.

```scala
BigInt(2).pow(_).toString.reverse.indexWhere(_%2>0)+1
```

Comment: You may use `0` to indicate missing odd numbers, so no need for the `if` and simple `t+1` will do, I think. (I don't speak Scala, so probably this shortens the code more than just replacing the end bit)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
WVooPfX<
```

Output is empty if no solution.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzwsPz8gLcLm/38jAwA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmv5PA/PCw/PyAtwua/uq6ueoTLf0MrIwMA).

#### How it works

```
W    % Implicit input. 2 raised to that
V    % Convert to char vector
o    % Convert each char to code point
o    % Modulo 2
P    % Reverse
f    % Find: gives 1-based indices of non-zeros
X<   % Minimum. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 7 bytes (14 nibbles)

```
/`?\`@~^2$%$~
```

Returns `0` if there are no odd digits.

```
/`?\`@~^2$%$~   # full program
             $  # with implicit arg added;
 `?             # find the indices of elements that are truthy by
          %$~   # modulo 2 (default)
                # of
   \            # reverse of
    `@~         # digits in base 10 (default) of
       ^2$      # 2^input
/               # finally fold over this list from right, returning
                # left element each time 
                # (so returns first element)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

```python
lambda n:"".join(`int(i)%2`for i in`2**n`[::-1]).find("1")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMHiNNuYpaUlaboWN61yEnOTUhIV8qyUlPSy8jPzNBIy80o0MjVVjRLS8osUMhUy8xKMtLTyEqKtrHQNYzX10jLzUjSUDJU0oSaogZRVAJUpFCXmpadqGOooGBlqWnEpKBQUAY1SqNBRSNOogKpesABCAwA)

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org), 65 bytes

```python
lambda n:"".join(str(int(i)%2)for i in str(2**n)[::-1]).find("1")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3HXMSc5NSEhXyrJSU9LLyM_M0ikuKNDLzSjQyNVWNNNPyixQyFTLzFECiRlpaeZrRVla6hrGaemmZeSkaSoZKmlCD1EFKK0BKixLz0lM1DHUUjAw1rbgUFAqKQMZV6CikaVRoQpUvWAChAQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
;2^₍↔i%₂ʰℕ₁ʰt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9icmFjaHlsb2cy//87Ml7igo3ihpRpJeKCgsqw4oSV4oKByrB0//8xMP9a)

#### Explanation

```
;2^₍             2^Input
    ↔            Reverse the number
     i           Take a [Digit, Index] of that number
      %₂ʰ        [Digit mod 2, Index]
         ℕ₁ʰ     Digit mod 2 must be in [1,+inf)
            t    Output = Index
```

`↔` would mess up indexing in case we reverse a number that ends with 0, but powers of 2 cannot have trailing 0.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 46 (40) bytes

40 bytes if input is allowed to be \$n = 2^t\$ instead of \$t\$ (switched notation). After solving, I saw xnors answer which <strike>I think</strike> is similar but deals with the power of 2.

```python
f=lambda n,j=1:j if n%2else f(n//10,j+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcTRCsIgFADQZ/2K@xLqEpYbgxD8GGtayroTvQ@N6Nut83DKQc8d52upvUe3@ddt9YA6O2MzpAh4msLWAkSJ42guOp@N6nGvQJAQqsdHkEbDvCjLGdXjPys1IckoPlFOw0Dqq4WGgCs4IRRn4X0PhWzxrfH@Aw)

**26** from xnor by accumulating using 1+f instead of j.

```python
f=lambda n:n%2or-~f(n//10)
```

Using this in a \$2^\cdot\$ wrapper gives:

**43** <strike>58</strike>:

```python
lambda t:f(2**t)
f=lambda n:n%2or-~f(n//10)
```

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 46 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,j=0:j if 2**n//10**j%2else f(n,j+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcpBDoMgEEDRNZ5iNo1ATRSJSUPiYWiFFmJHQmdRYzw7Zd3N37yfdnptqG8pl@Ln1b7viwXs4jyYCMHDKCX2vRqkjJfRrR8Hnle@KlH8loEgIGSLT8dVB3oSpmGU91qWckDivj3I6OU0cHhO4mxFw9z34RKZ/wFtxfID)

37 from xnor by accumulating using 1+f instead of j.  (Identical except for `n//j` since python 3)

```python
f=lambda n,j=1:2**n//j%2or-~f(n,j*10)
```

Comment: Nope, taking the \$2^t\$ is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 154 bytes (11×14=154 codels)

```
tldfm?liafqaqQ      ?   i  I rrrjje   e  A ?        e  R biqaasccmu  _             Saeeumcccccc?sVi    qq      Vt    qq sss  Nd    qq  a   Clliqqqq??qfaks
```

Infinite loop for `n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, ...` (No odd digits in `n^2`). Outputs correctly for anything with an odd digit. If you want to see how it works, make sure to add input `n` before executing.

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJx1kcEOgjAQRP9lz3PotqVUfoV4MFgTElQS9GT8d7ttQ6pgdpIuy2N2gBcN93Ogru8VHFiDDZjBXq4U2MnAymlhj-j5gF_5qldrk1mdysfitsLW3hVLv3HdsLqgVrakRFExbJPEaNY8-zH3ZAR1aUeL5FLsannZIqD6etZKiK1pBHc5kyqPWnHT_9xcdaOJpMu_wpaSb-XlNILKOxxBS5ipIwJN4zU3YRmou5ymJYDG2_x8yPj9AYFFaAM)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
V%2↔d`^2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8eGOxUYG/8NUjR61TUlJiDP6/x8A)

```
V           # Index of first element that is truthy when  
 %2         # modulo 2
   ↔        # of the reverse of
    d       # the decimal digits of
     `^2    # 2^input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-g`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

0-indexed, returns `undefined` if there's no odd digits

```
õ!²Ìì Ôðu
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWc&code=9SGyzOwg1PB1&input=MTc)

```
õ!²Ìì Ôðu     :Implicit input of integer U
õ             :Range [1,U]
 !²           :Raise 2 to the power of each
   Ì          :Last element
    ì         :Digit array
      Ô       :Reverse
       ð      :0-based indices of elements that truthy (1)
        u     :  Mod 2
              :Implicit output of first element
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 56 bytes

```cpp
[](int&n){int p=1;for(n=1<<n;n%2-!!n;n/=10)++p;n=n?p:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBhT4MwEP3Or7hhNCAjAlMTaYsfjL9i4wMpZRK3QmgxRMJfF48yMtaU9t1794678rr2j5yPWasrKNi4T51S6gfp9nhBzUJSVI0jWUipJPI@8jcbvJ9YGLieVxPJ5HsdB2QYiXVXSn5qcwG0rJRuRHZOVtyP4LpqEmsqe85K6bi9BbiUzuN4FilqCYiuxkjkwKAPtxAsOzIbwW7Bzyt@t@IRvCIYiPkBr6TSwL@y5hFPwb9Fs0@n4vah@4wO3dsHfi/2Ftbxzr64cXqYXgRKmYsObQG5QDq3rspf4Sw9uwQ8z8guzONNa7JrtBqB3NAC6cW8N3p6TSgc7d6mK0zXV8o0wKtWA6VLVxRs8BM8EKk5NHgZXTCmUsMfpD2XGqxh/OPFKTuq0fexKDvK1vOi7B8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
Ｉ⌕⮌﹪↨Ｘ²Ｎχ²¦¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwy0zL0UjKLUstag4VcM3P6U0J1/DKRHIDsgvTy3SMNJR8MwrKC3xK81NAnI1NXUUDA2AhBGYpampaf3/v6Hhf92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. 0-indexed. Outputs `-1` if no odd digit exists. Explanation:

```
      ²         Literal integer `2`
     Ｘ          Raised to power
       Ｎ        Input integer
    ↨           Converted to base
        χ       Predefined variable `10`
   ﹪            Vectorised modulo
         ²      Literal integer `2`
  ⮌             Reversed
 ⌕              Find index of
           ¹    Literal integer `1`
                Implicitly print
```

Actually outputting the last odd digit also takes 12 bytes:

```
ＦＩＸ²Ｎ¿﹪Ｉι²Ｐι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzmxuEQjIL88tUjDSEfBM6@gtMSvNDcptUhTU1MhM01Bwzc/pTQnH6IuU1NHwQgo7luaU5JZUJSZBxKy/v/f4L9uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs nothing if no odd digit exists. Explanation:

```
ＦＩＸ²Ｎ
```

Loop over the digits.

```
¿﹪Ｉι²
```

If the digit is odd, then...

```
Ｐι
```

... overprint any previous result.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 39 bytes

```
~`.+
.+¶$$.($&*$(2$*)_
-1L$`[13579]
$.'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxDcIwFEXR/s7xAZMoVp4dx/EENGyAEKagoKGIqBkrA2Qxc876@r4/T7WDu9T2q77H9/tm5p0dO3PBuvODQVerN8WUyx3zp9ZEIDKRmMksFDQioYAimlBCM8poQYUw/gE) Link includes test cases. 0-indexed. Outputs nothing if no odd digit exists. Explanation:

```
.+
.+¶$$.($&*$(2$*)_
```

Replace the input with code to calculate that power of `2`. (I could save two bytes by removing the `)_` at the end but this actually prevents a crash in Retina which I feel is not an ideal way to handle zero input.)

```
~`
```

Execute the code to generate the power of `2`.

```
-1L$`[13579]
```

Match the last odd digit.

```
$.'
```

Output the number of digits after it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 50 bytes

```
I=[0...nlog2]
f(n)=I[mod(floor(2^n/10^I),2)=1].min
```

Counting starts from 0 instead of 1, which is allowed as per the OP. Outputs `undefined` for all-even digits.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u01kewkyao)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a8tqzjvnbs)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 61 bytes

Nearly double the length of the [other JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/261910/108556) (and a slightly more naive implementation), but spent a bit of time on it, so might as well post it.

Returns `-0` when there is no odd digit.

```js
n=>-(~(l=(z=[...2**n+'']).findLastIndex(i=>i%2))&&l-z.length)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LcxNCsIwEEDhvacYCraTxgbNyr_pXvAG4kJsWgNhBmwE6cKLuCmih_I2Fuzqe6v3fLNUrn8JfW6xLpZfYioLfGAg7OhgjLF5zjrLjsrUnqv9qY07rtwdPZV-apVK01B0Jjhu4kWNk1UtVwwuggeCxWZgS2DnQ2itJgBn4VaCM0Ea9KAhWSczEPRqHPT93x8)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 26 bytes

```
2{.^:$@I.@:|2x,.@|.&.":@^]
```

0-indexed. Returns an empty array for no odd digit.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxy6haL85KxcFTz8GqxqhCR8-hRk9NT8nKIS4WomCTJldqcka-Qpqanp2CoXamnpEBRGLBAggNAA)

```
2{.^:$@I.@:|2x,.@|.&.":@^]
            2x          ^]  NB. 2^input using extended precision literal
                       @    NB. then
              ,.@|.&.":     NB. stringify→reverse then columnize→convert to int
2          |                NB. mod 2 the resulting digit list
         @:                 NB. then
       I.                   NB. find truthy indices
      @                     NB. then
 {.^:$                      NB. get first item, {., if, ^:, the rank, $, is not 0.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 22 bytes

```
1⊸+|1+·⊐⟜1∘⌊2|2⊸⋆÷10⋆↕
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=TG9kb3AyIOKGkCAx4oq4K3wxK8K34oqQ4p+cMeKImOKMijJ8MuKKuOKLhsO3MTDii4bihpUgIyAyMiBieXRlcwoKTG9kb3AywqggMeKAvzLigL8z4oC/NOKAvzXigL824oC/N+KAvzjigL854oC/MTAK)

First find the 0-based index of the first odd digit of the power-of-2 of input  (or return  if all digits are even):

```
⊐⟜1∘⌊2|2⊸⋆÷10⋆↕
        2⊸⋆       # 2 to the power of input
           ÷      # divided by
            10    # 10
              ⋆   # to the power of 
               ↕  # range from 0..input;
       |          # modulo
      2           # 2;
     ⌊            # floor;
    ∘             # applied to
⊐⟜1               # find first instance of 1
```

Then fix the cases with all-even digits: change to 1-based indices and output this modulo `+1` (so all-even-digit inputs become zero):

```
1⊸+|1+·
      ·           # last result 
    1+            # add 1;
   |              # modulo;
1⊸+               # input plus 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 5.9, <s>70</s> 68 bytes

```swift
var o={(n:Int)in String(2<<n).reversed().index{Int("\($0)")!%2==1}!}
```

0-indexed, throws a force-unwrap error when there aren't any odd characters.

Throws a deprecation warning when compiling on modern Swift versions; ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org) – 182 bytes

```rkt
(define(f n)(let l([L(reverse(map(λ(c)(-(char->integer c)48))(string->list(number->string(expt 2 n)))))][I 0])(cond[(odd?(list-ref L I))I][(>(-(length L)1)I)(l L(+ I 1))][#t 'na])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFNbsIwEEb3OcUIFh2rskT4p1JhHSlLuopSyU0mwcIYapsKJNSL9Q69EnXIokjEWcXfZz@/SYwotuSufSV0DaZdYEmV1IQVaIaKHCjMUjT0RcYS7sQBf3@wYMix2AjDl1I7qslAwcZzxtA6I3XNl0pah/q4@yC/pw2RTgcHQ89tnjxLYJAzLPa6zHBflitsznBDFaSQMJbkGS79NYp07TaQspgl3ghSfIYE4obQd/CkRe5p1/4FOIc3K2pqXi79KIpu@php8PqiZDmLALCU9qDEWfm02pudcNAbvmt4hW/Rg3vFwOb1hkAJ68ArQzsgSAu@krqk00vLqdopvUQrtibr7L@Yoc@jNAS41@rMpb59/KOWDooNFVvua6FW/jzerxtszJqRO4phqBiFijHztMd40h1PQ5gZ83c/xvNuzKI7jgfMi3bkwXnjYYA0CuTjbs94EsinAc4skM8DHD/xpOt/DRrONV4s/gA)

---

### Explanation

We first obtain the list of digits in reversed order of the number \$ 2^n \$ and start the index at 0 since Racket uses 0-based indexing. When we convert the number from a string to a list, the digits are represented in ASCII characters. So to extract the digits numeric value we need to subtract 48 from the character's ASCII value (48 in ASCII is the character `0`).

```rkt
(define (last-odd n)
  (let loop ([lst (reverse (map (lambda (char) (- (char->integer char) 48))
                                (string->list (number->string (expt 2 n)))))]
             [index 0])
    ...))
```

Once we have the list of reversed digits, we can begin looping. We create a conditional statement that checks if the current digit is odd. If it is, we return the index. If it isn't odd, we move on to the next check which checks whether we can still loop through the list. If we can, great, we then loop. If all fails, we return `'na`.

```rkt
(define (last-odd n)
  (let loop ([lst (reverse (map (lambda (char) (- (char->integer char) 48))
                                (string->list (number->string (expt 2 n)))))]
             [index 0])
    (cond [(odd? (list-ref lst index)) index]
          [(> (sub1 (length lst)) index) (loop lst (add1 index))]
          [#t 'na])))
```

### Conclusion

I'd like to end this off with an interesting experiment. I'd like to see how this function looks like on a plot. To do this, we can import Racket's `plot` library:

```rkt
(require plot)
```

Now to customize our plot, we can use `parameterize` to set configurations.

```rkt
(require plot)

(parameterize ([plot-width 600]
               [plot-height 480]
               [plot-title "Plot that shows the positions of the last odd digit in 2^n (0 been the last digit)."]
               [plot-x-label "n"]
               [plot-y-label "Last odd digit."]
               [plot-new-window? #t])
  ...)
```

This will open a new window, set its title, set the label of the `x` and `y` axes and set the width and height of the plot. Cool! Now how do we draw on the plot? Simple!

Racket's plot package has a function called plot that plots what ever renderer is in its argument. Since we are using a line graph, we use a line renderer called `lines`.

```rkt
  (plot (lines ...))
```

This renderer receives a sequence of vector points in the form of `#(x y)`. We can programmatically define this sequence using a `for/fold` loop.

```rkt
  (plot (lines (for/fold ([lst empty]) ([index (in-range 0 200)])
                 (let ([result (f index)])
                   (cons (vector index (if (equal? 'na result) 0 result))
                         lst)))))
```

The first argument of the loop is an empty list called `lst` that will be filled after each iteration. The `index` argument is an iterator that is constructed before the iteration begins. If `index` reaches 199, the loop stops and `lst` is returned.

`cons` prepends a value to an existing list. In our case we create a new vector in the form of `#(x y)` where `x` is the current `index` value and `y` is the result of `(f index)`. We then prepend this new vector to `lst` and replace the old `lst` with the new list by returning the constructed list.

Putting this all together:

```rkt
#lang racket

; -- Paste in the golfed code -- ;

(require plot)

(parameterize ([plot-width 600]
               [plot-height 480]
               [plot-title "Plot that shows the positions of the last odd digit in 2^n (0 been the last digit)."]
               [plot-x-label "n"]
               [plot-y-label "Last odd digit."]
               [plot-new-window? #t])
  (plot (lines (for/fold ([lst empty]) ([index (in-range 0 200)])
                 (let ([result (f index)])
                   (cons (vector index (if (equal? 'na result) 0 result))
                         lst))))))
```

Which renders the following:

[image: Plot of f(x) where 0 <= x < 200]

Pretty interesting! Have an amazing weekend!

Answer (score 2):

## x86, 20 bytes

Assumes input is in ecx and that edx is cleared.

```c
B3 0A B0 01 D3 E0 B1 01 F7 FB 89 C2 FF C1 83 E2 01 74 F5 C3
```

```c
        mov $10, %bl;     # b = divisor
        mov $1, %al;      # a = 1
        shll %cl, %eax;   # a = 1<<n = 2**n
        mov $1, %cl;      # c = 1, first digit is always even

    loop:
        idiv %ebx;        # a / 10
        movl %eax, %edx;  # a->d for comparison / clearing
        incl %ecx;        # c += 1
        andl $1, %edx;    # a % 2, clears edx if 0, otherwise loop is over
        jz loop;          # if a%2 == 0, loop again
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNZb5tAEH7nV4yokMCFGpykcUNjyW38YCmxLcu91FZo2V07Ky0L4ohM0/x2dw98JA0Pc3zf7OzszIADzJHY7N4wgXlDKHysasLyd/cj6xnEWfoCa6t@liHxMrJkYqOwRlRsIygBfI9KSBOcE/rzN1zD4y7cpmc@hNsQKZmG2o6UJBqnGkmjI76@1DJVcvhBSTzQyFrbOmZozg6Opy7PdcyFjjnbPcXQ74MbRcPg3Ou/fxvJYgahZVkV@0OTGmaffqwmElNuvnZNyR7090CvQ2LrIWcEekWC1o2QB2Zfbm9jy2KiBoW4yhDeowXyU3YbazNJUJUlCbjaU5@9zUtwHEq2vlGx/R@HDIde41LDpa9x2HBYcqDefdfwmhWcwmo6D0o5HSjKPOU0QzXD0AhOqwowp6ik5Jgsyx/AiQ6ZjgRGnEPPGZxiOri7OTwhrsC@Lm1wW@8UUojwfGOYXj7j1ZttX@m007jTZGtye6avJa2bUqguP5khZIgJ1wMzgMOU5LIWrhqVbybtw2I5XyXLyfgG/hr723IqN6BzJt8nn324Gy@SxXL6dawJ5Y1n85kPgdqwroCMZrhouzf43a53t8iQwx6oKi7i41pIV@@L6PIU8t@p164t0ram1ZXDm18CQASjVmqHBCOH2Ifi5UXtPnnWCPW4fQH7i0@aE8rm7P4B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 15 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⬚∞⊢⊚⇌◿2-@0°⋕ⁿ:2
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__ZiDihpAg4qya4oie4oqi4oqa4oeM4pe_Mi1AMMKw4ouV4oG_OjIKCuKItWYgKzHih6EyMCAjIDAtaW5kZXhlZAo=)

0-indexed; returns `∞` for no answer.

```
⬚∞⊢⊚⇌◿2-@0°⋕ⁿ:2
            ⁿ:2  # 2 to the input power
          °⋕     # unparse
       -@0       # convert to digits
     ◿2          # modulo 2
    ⇌            # reverse
   ⊚             # indices of 1s
⬚∞⊢              # first one, or infinity if none exist
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 64 bytes

```python
x=0
for y in`2**input()`[::-1]:
 x+=1
 if int(y)%2:print x;break
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxLCsIwGEXh@V1FJtKHCLl/35GuRIRqTbEIbSkVktXHODtw4Nv88V4XCeP6sn2SJMH1GtO6K6/mZZA8n5fte6TZcDPmwruBcueeUPMU/5H67CRm22Mqd33u9vEJEYF1dkz/ZJaLDoSgQIkKNRq06EANEhSwAEuwAmuwAVuwg@gf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 31 bytes

```perl6
{(2**$_ .flip~~/<[13579]>/).to}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WsNIS0slXkEvLSezoK5O3yba0NjU3DLWTl9TryS/9r81V3FipUKahkq8pkJafpFCnJGh9X8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
R%*Ea@?1
```

Outputs 0-indexed: e.g., the output for 2^12 (40**9**6) is 1. Outputs nothing if there is no odd digit.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhYrglS1XBMd7A0hXKjokmhD01goGwA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
R%*Ea@?1
    a    ; Command-line argument
   E     ; 2 to that power
 %*      ; Take each digit mod 2
R        ; Reverse
     @?1 ; Find index of first occurrence of 1
```