# Output each second

Tags: code-golf, date

With roughly one second (plus or minus 10 ms) between outputs, output anything.
The first output must be at most one second after the start of the program, but can be as soon as right when the program starts.
So, the first output can be up to a second after the program starts, the second exactly one second after that, the third a second after that, and so on to infinity.

The outputs do not need to be consistent, nor have any sort of delimiter. However, they must be visible (even if it's only visible when highlighted).

Comment: It says "within one second between outputs," but doesn't that simply allow for no delay at all? What prevents me from doing something like `while 1:print("")` in Python and still be within the rules of the challenge?

Comment: @AidenChow It says _with_ one second between outputs, so no, It must be basically exactly one second. Also, the output must be non-empty.

Comment: Ah oops I read it wrong, but it could definitely be worded a lot better than what is currently written here.

Comment: Also bonuses are [heavily discouraged](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/96039) and are generally a detriment to any challenge that includes them. Your challenge is no exception.

Comment: @AidenChow Bonus removed

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "non-empty thing." With `print("")`, the output is technically a newline, which is not empty. Do you mean to ban whitespace output? If so, that would be a very unnecessary restriction and the rule should be removed from the challenge.

Comment: @AidenChow I had just meant that the output couldn't be empty, but I realize that would be obvious and non-empty thing would just be more confusing.

Comment: You might consider adding a grace duration by which the one-second interval may differ. Otherwise, answers can't be correct for sure.

Comment: @chunes What do you mean a grace duration? Do you mean, like, instead of exactly one second, almost exactly one second (plus or minus, say, 10 ms)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Does invisible output count, e.g. `␛[2J␛[0;0H`?

Comment: @Neil No, I have to be able to see it. Unless those are whitespace, which I could select to see. But if it is zero-width, then no.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## MacOS shell, 3

```
top
```

On the Mac, `top`'s default refresh period is 1 sec.

---

## Linux shell, 7

```
top -d1
```

Unfortunately on Linux, `top`'s default refresh period is more like 2 secs, so we need an extra 4 bytes.

Since this is just one command, both variants are shell-agnostic.

Comment: This is the *top* answer.

Comment: can't confirm this. On my mac top refreshed once every 1.1 sec. you're off by 100ms

Answer (score 13):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + `iputils`, 6 bytes

```
ping 0
```

send `ICMP ECHO_REQUEST` to 0 (127.0.0.1) once per second.

---

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + `procps-ng`, 8 bytes

```
free -s1
```

Display amount of free and used memory in the system with one second between outputs.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```python
import time
while[help()]:time.sleep(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVqzwjMyc1OiM1p0BDM9YKJKRXnJOaWqBhqPn/PwA)

Improved by [Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus)

Comment: `while 1:print(time.sleep(1))` is the same size, so you could use python 2 for one less byte

Comment: `while[help()]:time.sleep(1)`

Comment: @Sisyphus That;s cursed

Answer (score 8):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 5+3+3+2=13 bytes

Ticker expression (5 bytes)

```
a->-a
```

Ticker repeat delay (3 bytes)

```
999
```

Main expressions (3 bytes)

```
a=1
```

2 bytes for "file boundaries" (treat each expression as a separate "file"; there are 3 "files", so there are two "file boundaries", as per this [comment](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19316/scoring-desmos-equations#comment74833_19317))

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b0oevnbpmy)

To run, click the ticker icon (the metronome) near the top left of the screen. This switches the variable `a` between the values `1` and `-1` every 999 milliseconds. While this isn't outputting onto the console or stdin in the traditional sense, you can still clearly see the code switching between the `1` and the `-1`, which hopefully emulates outputting close enough.

Comment: You can do it with just `a=0`, a step of `1`, and option 4 for the slider, and the slider running. Slider running is one bit, the four slider options are two more bits, step is one byte + one boundary byte, and a=0 is 3 more bytes (maybe + one boundary) for a total of 5.375 bytes or 6.375 bytes

Comment: @Dadsdy How are you calculating that running a slider is one bit, and choosing a slider option is two more bits, and so on? I don't think any of these bit/byte measurements that you are coming up with have any meta consensus backing them up, while I am basing my byte calculations off of the meta post for scoring Desmos answers found [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19316/96039). Unless there is some kind of meta consensus regarding the scoring of sliders and such, I won't be changing my answer to include any of that.

Comment: That's fair. I just figured that since each slider is either running or not running, that would be one bit, and because there are four options for the slider that would be two bits, but yeah, I have no meta backing for those numbers. I just think that maybe using a running slider instead of a ticker could be promising.

Comment: @Dadsdy To be fair, while there is currently no consensus on scoring sliders (and many other things in Desmos, like graph settings, setting the colors of an expression, tables, and so on), you could potentially post a follow-up meta post of sorts to address these other cases, if you choose to.

Comment: Meta post posted

Answer (score 8):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 30 bytes

Prints a newline every second.

```c
main(){main(sleep(puts("")));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7MaTBXnpKYWaBSUlhRrKClpampa1/7/DwA)

Comment: Waits a second between writing newlines. Writing a newline takes some amount of time, so it doesn't print something every second.

Comment: @CrisLuengo The challenge says it has to wait 1 second plus or minus 10 ms. I'm pretty sure printing a newline takes less than 10 ms on most computers.

Comment: How exactly does it work? The standard just seems to demand that `puts` returns a non-negative number on success. I assume it is `1` in this case, which is used as the number of seconds to sleep. But is this guaranteed or does this only work in certain implementations. Or phrased differently, are there implementations of `puts` where this won't work?

Comment: @infinitezero I believe the return behavior of `puts` is actually undefined, but for most implementations it appears to return the number of bytes outputted. You could probably call it a "hack"; I think it's a neat way to save a few bytes :)

Comment: @dingledooper so "" even though it's empty outputs a single byte? I presume it's `\0` then? Hacking is definitely fine in CG :D

Comment: @infinitezero It would be `\n`, because `puts` outputs a single newline :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 18 bytes

```
[ .s ] 1e9 every .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQkpmbWlSsUFCUWlJSWVCUmVeiYP0/WkGvWCFWwTDVUiG1LLWoUkHv/38A)

`every` calls a function each time a duration has passed. If `every` is not given a duration such as `1 seconds`, and instead given a number, it defaults to nanoseconds. Thus, one billion (or 1e9) means one second. `.s` simply prints the contents of the data stack without consuming them, which in this case will print the timer object `every` uses to do its thing. The `.` at the end is necessary to satisfy the stack effect checker by removing the item on the data stack (because Factor programs must end with an empty stack), even though it will never be reached.

Comment: In the TIO link, the program immediately ends

Comment: Well I wouldn't expect TIO to handle threads properly. Works fine locally.

Answer (score 7):

## Javascript, <s>22</s> <s>20</s> 19 Bytes

Thanks to @Kaiido for -2 Bytes
Thanks to @Elias Holzmann for -1 Bytes

```
setInterval({},1e3)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ry2sgkz7/

Comment: Please don't link to fiddles that alert infinitely! Gave me quite a scare when I accidentally clicked it on a browser window with lots of unsaved stuff.

Comment: Also, `setInterval(alert,1e3)` is one ms more accurate for same byte count

Comment: @noodleman fixed

Comment: Given that the output can be anything I guess `setInterval("a",1e3)` would work, this does output  "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined" in the console every second for 2 saved bytes.

Comment: @Kaiido I didn’t even think of erroring

Comment: In Firefox dev tools (and probably others), this doesn't exactly output something new each time. There is one line of output which is constantly updated with a new "number of times" counter.

Comment: @SteveBennett you can untick the "Group Similar Messages", but even without doing so, You have the count number that gets updated every second.

Comment: @Kaiido great suggestion, I'm stealing this for my answer ^^

Comment: You can save an additional character by using `{}` as the callback: `setInterval({},1e3)`. This will also error every second, though I'm not sure why – it complains about an unmatched `[`, but there are no square brackets here...

Comment: I think it's because it attempts to do `eval({})`. `{}` is coerced to a string, leaving `[object Object]`, which isn't valid javascript code causing an error.

Comment: @TheZipCreator that’s cool. Probably actually Function({})

Answer (score 6):

## shell + GNU/Linux core utils, 11 bytes

`watch -n1 w`

A bit of a boring answer.

Answer (score 6):

## [*><>](https://github.com/redstarcoder/go-starfish), 4 bytes

Prints "10" on startup, and once every second

```
a:nS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLErLLM74/z/RKi/4/38A)

### Explanation

```
a      # Push 10 onto the stack
 :     # Duplicate it
  n    # Pop a value off the stack, and print it as a decimal number
   S   # Pop a value off the stack, and sleep for 100ms * the popped value
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 5 bytes

```
⁽kNḞU
```

Don't [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJqIiwiIiwi4oG9a07huJ5VIiwiIiwiIl0=) - it doesn't work there.

This one's kind of hilarious. It creates an infinite list of times, and then uniquifies them. The `j` flag is necessary due to how Vyxal handles printing infinite lists.

```
   Ḟ  # Generate an infinite list from...
⁽     # A function that returns
 kN   # The current time of day (hh:mm:ss)
    U # Get unique values
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work if left on for an entire day?

Comment: @UnrelatedString It's linear in space complexity, so... probably? Eventually it will reach a point where it can't perform the check in time.

Comment: I say an entire day because if it's only uniquifying hours-minutes-seconds, the intended outputs should cease to be unique after a full day.

Comment: @UnrelatedString Oops.

Comment: You can shrink it by using the `=` flag, but apparently I shouldn’t poke Vyxal answers with a comment like this.

Answer (score 5):

## [(,)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/(,)), <s>60</s> <s>62</s> 61 Chars or \$61\log_{256}(3)\approx\$ 12.09 Bytes

```
((),((()))((())))((()),((())))(,((()),(),(),,((())),()),,,())
```

```
((),((()))((()))) Sets variable 1 to -2.
((()),((()))) sets variable -2 (time) to itself. (AKA setting the current time to 0)
(, Start of loop
((()),(),(),,((())),()) If variable -2 (time) is at least 1, reduce it by 1 and output 1\n
,,,()) Loop forever
```

First solution sometimes had the second output less than a second after the first.

Comment: What does this mean? Could you post an explanation?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Does this help?

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
`@D1Y.T
```

This displays the natural numbers in order. Try at [MATL online](https://matl.io/?code=%60%40D1Y.T&inputs=&version=22.7.4)!

#### How it works

```
`      % Do...while
  @    %   Push iteration index, starting at 1
  D    %   Display
  1    %   Push 1
  Y.   %   Pause for that many seconds
  T    %   Push true. This is used as loop condition, causing an infinite loop
       % End (implicit)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
1œSṄ¿
```

A full program which prints `1` and a newline and then after (just over) one second has elapsed prints another, then repeats this step forever.

It's "just over" as it takes some time to do the work. The first pause could take more than 1 second on slow hardware as Jelly has to initialise Python, and itself (create an interpreter, import some cruft, etc.) and parse the code. Subsequent pauses are unlikely to be over the 1.01 second threshold however as it just needs to check that the result is truthy and print to STDOUT.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/w4c6Wo5ODD@3//x8A)** (TIO does not output anything as a program runs, but kill it while in flight and take a look; killing within a second should give a single `1` in the "Output" section, leaving it running longer should give more outputted `1`s for each second that passed.)

#### How?

```
1œSṄ¿ - Main Link: no arguments
1     - set the left argument to one
    ¿ - while...
 Ṅ    - ...condition: print {left=1} and a newline, and yield {left=1}
  œS  - ...action: sleep for {implicit right=left=1} seconds and yield {left=1}
```

---

Replace `Ṅ` with `Ȯ` for no newlines.

Comment: Congratulations on 100001!

Comment: Thanks @DominicvanEssen, hitting the palindrome at the same time as passing the 100K milestone is a lovely little bit of icing on that internet-point cake :)

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 17 bytes

```php
for(;;a)sleep(1);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKytEzWLc1JTCzQMNa3//wcA)

I think the naive approach will be the shortest here. On TIO the output will be visible only when stopping the program of course

EDIT: saved 1 byte by echoing the falsey result of `sleep`, it works because `sleep` returns zero instead of `false` which would have lead to an empty string

EDIT 2: stole the suggestion from [this JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/262209/90841) by triggering a warning instead of an echo

Answer (score 4):

## TI-Basic (TI-84+), 22 bytes

```
startTmr
While 1
If checkTmr(Ans:Then
Disp Ans
startTmr
End
End
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org), <s>43</s> <s>37</s> <s>28</s> 26 bytes

### Changelog

1. Thanks to [@Dadsdy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/118038/dadsdy) for the `-2` bytes.
2. The `-4` bytes comes from converting `#lang racket` to `#!racket`.
3. Another `-9` as I found out that language statements may go into the header of TIO, and as such, don't contribute to number of bytes.
4. I just learnt about Racket's `do` loop! `-2` bytes!

### Code

```rkt
(do()(#f)(write(sleep 1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pMzk4t@a@ck5iXrlAE4Wik5GtoaiinaWqUF2WWpGoU56SmFigYampq/v8PAA)

---

### Explanation

We create a [*do*](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._do%29%29) loop that runs infinitely. Since we used `#f` (false) in `do`s second argument, the loop won't terminate as it will only terminate if there is a `#t` value.

If we were to expand this out and make it more readable, it would look like this:

```rkt
(do () (#f)
  ; (sleep 1) doesn't return anything, so #<void> will be printed.
  (write (sleep 1)))
```

The `do` loop acts a bit similar to JavaScript's `while` loop:

```js
while (!false) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: -2 bytes with write(sleep 1)

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, <s>15</s> <s>13</s> 9 bytes

```
ping -t 0
```

After some initial output, outputs the following every second:

```
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
```

Edit: Saved 4 bytes thanks to @c--.

Previous 15-byte solution:

```
timeout/t 1
%0
```

Repeatedly outputs the following:

```
C:\Users\Neil>timeout/t 1 

Waiting for 1 seconds, press a key to continue ...0

C:\Users\Neil>262205.bat
```

When output is to the screen, the cursor is moved so that the `0` overwrites the `1`.

Answer (score 3):

## [GFA-Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GFA_BASIC) 3.51 (Atari ST), 15 bytes

A manually edited listing in .LST format. All lines end with `CR`, including the last one.

```
DO
?0
PA 50
LO
```

which expands to:

```
DO
  PRINT 0
  PAUSE 50
LOOP
```

We could use `DELAY 1` instead of `PAUSE 50`. Unfortunately, the shortest unambiguous abbreviation of `DELAY` is `DELA`.

#### Output

After 5 seconds:

[image: output]

Comment: It's strange that `PAUSE` works with value in 1/50th second :P

Comment: @Kaddath It's most probably based on the vertical blank interrupt, which occurs 50 times per second on a PAL / SECAM machine.

Comment: It would however require some tweaks to work with NTSC (60Hz) and hi-resolution mode (70Hz). According to the documentation, the value is always expressed in 1/50th second, no matter the system or the screen resolution.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>7</s> 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs a `ReferenceError`.
Any lowercase letter word work instead of the second `i`.

```
A³ii
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=JGNvbnNvbGUuY2xlYXIoKSQ&code=QbNpaQ) (Open your browser's console)

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something obvious here, isn't the last `A` redundant?

Comment: Sadly not, @Etheryte; as it turns out, if you don't pass an argument to `O.l()` then it does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

## x86-16 machine code, PC DOS, 14 bytes

```
00000000: b42c cd21 3ac6 74fa 8ac6 cd29 ebf4       .,.!:.t....)..
```

**Listing**

```
B4 2C       MOV  AH, 2CH        ; DOS API get system time function 
        SEC_LOOP: 
CD 21       INT  21H            ; Read time: DH = seconds 
3A C6       CMP  AL, DH         ; second changed? 
74 FA       JE   SEC_LOOP       ; continue polling if not 
8A C6       MOV  AL, DH         ; save new second 
CD 29       INT  29H            ; write AL to console 
EB F4       JMP  SEC_LOOP       ; loop indefinitely
```

A standalone executable DOS COM program. Spams the DOS time function and writes the corresponding ASCII codepoint for the number of seconds.

*Several minutes later...*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>24</s> 21 bytes

```julia
!x=!show(sleep(1))
!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X7HCVrE4I79cozgnNbVAw1BTk0vR4P9/AA)

-3 bytes thanks to ovs: improve recursion, and redefine an operator (An argument has to be passed to it, but this can be ignored by the function)

Comment: I think `!x=!show(sleep(1));!0` would work for 21 as a full program

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 45 bytes

Nothing special

```cs
for(;;){Thread.Sleep(1000);Console.Write(1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/F9anJmXrhBcWVySmqsXklGUmpgCFLD@n5ZfpGFtrVkNEdILzklNLdAwNDAw0LR2zs8rzs9J1QsvyixJ1TDUtK79/x8A)

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/F9anJmXrhBcWVySmqsXklGUmpgCFLD@n5ZfpGFt7ZyfV5yfk6oXXpRZkqphqKkJUaEXnJOaWqBhaGBgoGn9/z8A "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 36 bytes

```
import os
while 0<1:echo 1;sleep 999
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY3VTJzC_KLShTyi7nKMzJzUhUMbAytUpMz8hUMrYtzUlMLFCwtLSFqoVpgWgE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 19 bytes

```perl
say 2 while sleep 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r1Jja2itoFxckl@gEOLpr1uSmZuaX1qikFaUn6tQUJRalppXkpmXrgAUKygt@V@cWKlgpFCekZmTqlCck5paoGD4//@//IKSzPy84v@6vmWmeoYGAA)

Comment: I don't think the space between `2` and `while` is necessary. And if you're fine with just printing newlines, there are multiple 16 byters: `1while sleep say` or `{sleep say;redo}`

Comment: This will not do. `sleep 1` will sleep for _at least 1 second_ (unless you have an old version of perl 5, then it may sleep less), but perl won't guarantee it won't sleep longer. It will be at the mercy of the OS it's running on. But to be fair, most, if not all submissions will suffer from this.

Answer (score 3):

## [ELF (x86/x64, Linux)](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/elf.pdf), 112 bytes

Prints 'A' about once per second, indefinitely.

```
00000000: 7f45 4c46 fec0 505f e81b 0000 0000 0000  .ELF..P_........
00000010: 0200 3e00 0000 0000 0400 0000 4100 0000  ..>.........A...
00000020: 3800 0000 0000 0000 5e40 80c6 3f50 5a0f  8.......^@..?PZ.
00000030: 0504 2256 eb32 3800 0100 0000 0500 0000  .."V.28.........
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 4100 0000  ............A...
00000050: 0100 0000 0000 0000 7000 0000 0000 0000  ........p.......
00000060: 7000 0000 0000 0000 5faf 0f05 eb96 0000  p......._.......
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZG7DsIwDEV3vsLiAyzn4TQw8BhgYujEwAAqVTwx8P9LSUTSUNoMViL7ntwrh5cMA@WzhUYsg@2tAwk9ARMLBK@ekNo/BfB0OSO2D8xn9SWoyCAdB0yYzJMtN6sqA3dFjsfK0JFh/FSeCgdL4Kl3YITjsyMB8Fl/PyDu21thmOSDyYLW7CA8jc7I8ffYrT7WV9Qe/7LYxKC5j1omWXApCyeGmiubBdrIeE99uLSXhXmWToCEOObbuMwo2rKYYfgA) (Prints 60 `A`'s before TIO kills the process)

### Explanation

The file abuses a lot of undefined behavior within the Linux ELF loader; the kernel is able to make a lot of (correct) assumptions when certain fields are not the right value. [Here](https://tio.run/##jVRNc5swEL3zK3bSziSZxI0/sOshpx7aU/9BppMRaGXUAYQlYeP8eXdXQGyTZBoOQuxKb6X33iKcwzItDpNKuPJ4fEq1d7CK/0TRk7EbmNLkEZQuENJGF1JXG8BCgbKmBJdZ4bOcV/BusGJPuW88nZjuAyYq1VUU0fQ5lzaJgB6ZwrT9ru5pjJdhzMK4gseQgKufv39dMexsDunBo4McLYI3kIsdgjMlgmqqCCtvDwkEUF1lIApC6LeEYN24nI7VUngWwl3U1GClvgxmoiigwtZTeNlDhITXJR1gEU5NuaZqHMouJfd03jkFscWs8SIt8BRfICVEKaFdryar@AwrHmGFLVsosXxOhcO7cC1GDe/a6MoPa2prNkwkZXlqRUnUCIkWjFIOfSAtPidNGQulsR1hfL/kxIEbcSCkBKcLFmOhKBV/kspR0B1cYPNSCwYXhL2I3xVpfJa/ZQ0uN9ZDIZw/23LG8PotDU6/YDSwlLzNk4cKIyRzq5kUdjbxa5h9uLHtLQj/qsSp1IyQvhDHIzgHDwGOlQeHmxJ7qTqh55dCf7SYiJm2y9OyG6wk1@L@oVvc0j5L5e7YZYMR@oaiTZ3wdIlwmbGZLhbstA2XM2SrB2poFVbbra8T3jM7PylHBzAGZmIpH159rf@v6mqxKde9J9mOSlfUqeTHQFPE@iYfNyZ5ycnPGOzkmKGBXi1DvbRDKpebZpPTC4mYYCu/N/3BiG@Kj@0iyCMvaM09Jw/8SVjO6/CvQNk377tqc9WgAJOfZkw3yajYNGQ3rkW/vBlc/7iOBrESwG0TwtP@iaKB1S73FSaD9MfjPw) is the full NASM source.

Basically, the executable is just an ELF header, a program header (partially merged into the ELF header), and the actual program (which is spread throughout the two headers so that it doesn't take up any additional space). The full program calls `sys_write(stdout, "A", 1)`, then `sys_nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=112}, <nonsense valid pointer>)`, and then loops back to the start.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to [@Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen).*

```r
repeat show(Sys.sleep(1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxRKE4I79cI7iyWK84JzW1QMNQU/P/fwA)

This works well on my local machine, but TIO accumulates output until it finishes execution, so you don't see the progress.

Comment: ```repeat show(Sys.sleep(1))``` is 25 bytes...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Didn't think of that, thanks!

Comment: This answer also waits 1 s between printing things, which is not the same as printing something every second because the act of printing takes time.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, fortunately the printing is pretty fast and takes less than 10ms (at least on my machine).

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 23 bytes

```arturo
whileø[1:s>>{a}1pause]
```

```
whileø[     ; start infinite loop (while loop with null for condition)
    1:s     ; push duration of 1 second to stack
    >>{a}1  ; create/overwrite file named a
    pause   ; pause execution for one second (which we left on the stack earlier)
]           ; end while
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
#.d
.j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1kvhUsv6/9/AA)

#### Explanation

```
#        # loop forever until error (no error will occur)
   .j    # imaginary number i, printed
 .d      # sleep for abs(i) seconds
```

It may seem weird that I have to sleep for \$|i|\$ seconds, why not just 1? While that would save a byte, unfortunately `.d1` is a predefined macro which returns the amount of time which has passed since the program started, which is not really useful for this challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
ＲＷφψＰＩ¬ΣＫＫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8oNa0otTgjPCMzJ1UjTUehUlPBtzSnJLOgKDOvRMM5sbhEwy@/RCO4NFcjIDU1W0MTBKz///@vW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Uses control codes to toggle the top left corner between `1` and `0`, so on TIO you need to let it run for a few seconds and then interrupt it to see the control codes and `1`s and `0`s. Explanation:

```
ＲＷφψ
```

Repeat indefinitely, showing the current canvas with a 1000ms delay on each repeat.

```
ＰＩ¬ΣＫＫ
```

Toggle the current character between `1` and `0`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 50 bytes

```lua
o=os.time::a::t=o()repeat until t<o()print()goto a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/3za/WK8kMzfVyirRyqrENl9Dsyi1IDWxRKE0ryQzR6HEBihSUJSZV6KhmZ5fkq8A1AMA)

A platform independent solution. You *can* make this shorter by using `os.execute`, but that solution is both platform dependent and not very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

## [GBZ80](https://rgbds.gbdev.io/docs/v0.6.1/gbz80.7) [machine code](https://www.pastraiser.com/cpu/gameboy/gameboy_opcodes.html) (DMG mode): 19 bytes

```
21 0F FF 3E 01 E0 FF 06 78 76 70 05 20 FB 2F E0 47 18 F4
```

Assembly:

```
Entrypoint:
    ld hl, $ff0f
    ld a, $01
    ldh [$ffff], a ; only accept vblank interrupts

.outerLoop:
    ld b, 120

.innerLoop:
    db $76 ; directly encoded halt. saves one byte over "halt" in my assembler.
           ; since by deliberate design IE & IF is sometimes not zero here, we encounter the halt bug. fortunately, "ld [hl], b" is a one byte instruction whose duplication is, excluding time, transparent (with exceptions that would be familiar to those who encounter them)
    ld [hl], b ; discard the pending interrupt every other pass (even parity)
    dec b
    jr nz, .innerLoop

    cpl
    ldh [$ff47], a ; invert the palette
    jr .outerLoop
```

This is just counting vblanks, with some mangling to save a single byte from not loading an immediate to clear the vblank interrupt flag. The effect produced every second is inverting the screen colors. This does not work in CGB mode because the register for the DMG background palette does nothing in CGB mode.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
[₄=.W
```

Keeps printing `1000\n` every second.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@lFTi61e@P//AA)

**Explanation:**

```python
[      # Start an infinite loop:
 ₄     #  Push 1000
  =    #  Print it with trailing newline (without popping)
   .W  #  Pop and sleep that many milliseconds
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 38 Bytes

```python
import time
while[time.sleep(1)]:print
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVqzwjMyc1GsTUK85JTS3QMNSMtSooyswr@f8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [simply](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/simply), 93 bytes

Outputs a 9x9 image with a random color, every 999 milliseconds - which is within the 10ms error range.

```
%C=run!CANVAS->init(9,9)run%C->ontick(fn()=>run%C->fillRect(0 0 9 9run%C->getRandomColor)999)
```

It does exactly what it's supposed to.

---

### Ungolfed

This code does exactly the same.

```
$fn = anonymous function() {
    $color = call %canvas->getRandomColor();
    call %canvas->fillRect(0, 0, 9, 9, $color);
};

%canvas = call !CANVAS->init(9, 9);
call %canvas->ontick($fn, 999);
```

I'm too lazy to write a full English-like version.

---

If you need more information, to confirm it does do what it's supposed to do, just add this after the code:

```
// Golfed version:
call %C->showDebug();

// Ungolfed version:
call %canvas->showDebug();
```

To make sure it is running, just check that the (manually) underlined value changes at a rate of ~1 second:
[image: Debug output]

That value represents the number of frames that were actually drawn.
By default, the code avoids re-drawing the canvas if there were no updates.
And each call to `fillRect` will trigger a single update.

You can replace `ontick` with `onframe` or `onclick` to verify that the value really represents what I've said.

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore BASIC (Commodore C64/C128, C16/+4, VIC-20, PET), <strike>~61</strike> ~45 tokenised BASIC bytes

```
0printti$:b=val(ti$)+1
1ifval(ti$)<bthen1
2goto
```

This works by using the Commodore `TI$` system variable. Firstly, this outputs the value of `TI$` to the screen (which is in HHMMSS format). It then take the value of `TI$` as a number and add one to it. It then waits until the current numeric value of `TI$` is no longer a less significant number than the `B` variable, and then we `GOTO` line 0 to output the new value of `TI$` to the screen. This continues until the `STOP` key is pressed, which will break the program (it may be continued with the `CONT` command).

Screenshot reflects an older iteration of this entry.

[image: Output each second running on a Commodore C64]

Comment: "The first output ... can be as soon as right when the program starts" so I don't think you need the initial ```FOR``` loop on line ```0```...

Comment: ...but, if ```0 TO 937``` *really* takes 'approximately one second', why not just ```PRINT 1``` on line ```1```, and then ```GOTO 0``` on line ```2```...?

Comment: This method definitely takes ~1 second (plus whatever overheads from the KERNAL and BASIC interpreter). According to Commodore BASIC, `0ti$="000000":forb=0to946:next:?ti/60` is ~1 second (again, slight variation on Commodore machine and PAL/NTSC), but thanks for the byte saving tips.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 16 bytes

Paste it into a PS console (Windows or Core) (not using TIO because that will only show the output once the script is stopped):

```powershell
for(){sleep 1;1}
```

Will print `1` every second until Ctrl-C is pressed.
Nothing remarkable, just for the sake of completeness when it comes to languages.

Answer (score 1):

## [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), 13 bytes

I'm not sure how rules-bendy to get, but here's the shortest possible version:

```
?
SLEEP 1
RUN
```

You can try it at [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack).

#### Explanation

```
?        ' Print a blank line
SLEEP 1  ' Wait 1 second
RUN      ' Restart the program
```

Once the screen is filled up with blank lines, you won't be able to see new output happening, and you can't select the outputted text. So here's a **15-byte** version that will be visually different each time something is printed:

```
?0;      ' Print 0 without a newline
SLEEP 1  ' Wait 1 second
RUN      ' Restart the program
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 21 bytes

```
Dynamic@Floor@Clock@2
```

A [dynamic object](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) that alternates between 0 and 1 every second. This only works in the Notebook interface, so no TIO link.

---

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 23 bytes

```
Echo@True~While~Pause@1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/981OSPfIaSoNLUuPCMzJ7UuILG0ONXB8P9/AA)

Prints `True` every second.

Answer (score 1):

## Vyxal , 5 Bytes

```
{1¨w,
```

[Try it online (collects all the output received in ten seconds (or sooner if it halts) and prints it all at once.)](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJ7McKodywiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) `-t0.5`, 2 bytes

```
1n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3zDv////uiUGeqYA)

`><>` has an extra flag to set the time between ticks, presumably to help with debugging. This code simply outputs a `1` every 2*0.5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```swift
import Darwin
while 0<1{print(sleep(1))}
```

Prints "`0\n`" every second. Probably macOS-only due to `import Darwin`.

Answer (score 1):

## ARM Thumb machine code + Linux syscalls, 28 bytes

```
00: 2202       movs r2, #2    // 2 bytes
02: 2704       movs r7, #4    // write()
04: 2001       movs r0, #1    // stdout
06: a104       adr  r1, #0x18 // pointer to 0x18 "!\n"
08: df00       svc  #0        // syscall write(1, "!\n", 2)
0a: 27a2       movs r7, #162  // nanosleep()
0c: a001       adr  r0, #0x14 // pointer to 0x14
0e: 2100       movs r1, #0    // NULL
10: df00       svc  #0        // syscall nanosleep(&{1, 2593}, 0)
12: e7f6       b.n  #0x02     // jump to 0x02, r2 won't have changed
14: 0000 0001  .word 1        // 1 second
18: 0000 0a21  .word 0x0a21   // "!\n" or 2593 nanoseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

## Minecraft Function, 30 bytes

```
say a
schedule function a:b 1s
```

Must be run as a function named `b` in a data pack named `a`.
It prints `[Server] a` to chat once per second.

The first command simply says `a`, and the second command schedules the function to execute again in one second.

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 11 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⍥(&pπ&sl1)∞
```

Doesn't work online, but works locally.

```
⍥(&pπ&sl1)∞
⍥(       )∞  # infinite loop
     &sl1    # sleep for one second
  &pπ        # print pi
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic (TI-84), 15 bytes

```
startTimer
Disp Ans
Repeat checkTmr(Ans
End
prgmA
```

needs to be stored in `prgmA` for the recursion

based on and improved over [Yousername's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/262310)