# Sum of a range of a sum of a range of a sum of a range of a sum of a range of a sum of

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

#### Inspired by the fact that a few related challenges to this could be answered by Vyxal in 0 Bytes using a special flag combination.

Given only one input integer \$n\$, calculate \$f(n,n)\$ where
$$ f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
x & \text{if } y=0 \\
f(\left(\sum_{k=1}^xk\right),\text{ }y-1) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
If you want an explanation in plain English, here it is, quoted from OEIS:

> Let \$T(n)\$ be the \$n\$-th triangular number \$n*(n+1)/2\$; then \$a(n)\$ = \$n\$-th iteration [of] \$T(T(T(...(n))))\$.

Note that a(n) is the function.

---

This is also [A099129](https://oeis.org/A099129)\$(n)\$, but with the case for \$n=0\$. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so as long as you make your answer short, it doesn't matter whether it times out on TIO (my computer can't calculate \$n=6\$ within five minutes!). Yes, standard loopholes apply.

---

### Test cases:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 6
3 -> 231
4 -> 1186570
5 -> 347357071281165
6 -> 2076895351339769460477611370186681
7 -> 143892868802856286225154411591351342616163027795335641150249224655238508171
```

Comment: I have a 2 byte vyxal implementation but it feels unfair to post it...

Comment: Note that adding flags changes the language on this site, "vyxal" != "vyxal -xyz" etc..., so do you _really_ have a 2 byte "vyxal" implementation? :p

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh yeah it’s Vyxal `R`

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
FLO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fzcf//38TAA)

##### Explanation

```python
     # Implicit input
F    # Repeat input number of times:
 L   #  Push the one-range of top of stack
  O  #  Sum the resulting list
     # Implicit output
```

Comment: Gotta go with the flo(w)!

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 35 bytes

```python
def f(n):exec"n=n*-~n/2;"*n;print n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI0/TKrUiNVkpzzZPS7cuT9/IWkkrz7qgKDOvRCHvf1p@kUKeQmaeQlFiXnqqhpmmFZcCVE6HC6z7PwA)

A function that prints.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 39 bytes

```python
lambda n:eval("(n:=n*-~n//2)*0+"*n+"n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQq4irGSWKggjBm7QxyhLsKyJBm65u7@W3XgnTkkvzdm3R3dvuBMzxuEiSYCxU96HvR1aDlgpaQnLzqQiIAFEczoNmNrkEVPIE5vYD)

The annoying thing in Python 3 here is that `exec` within a function is its own scope and doesn't affect variables outside the `exec`, so we can't port the code like `def f(n):exec("n=n*-~n/2;"*n);print(n)` -- the `n` will be unchanged.

The code above works around this by evaluating a string like `(n:=n*-~n//2)*0+(n:=n*-~n//2)*0+n` that modifies `n` using the walrus `:=` and evaluates to `n` within its own scope. If we didn't need `n=0`, we could do:

**37 bytes, fails n=0**

```python
lambda n:eval("(n:=n*-~n//2),"*n)[-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQq0irGVGkWhSCJ6kWRllBfUUiaNPV7b303ntE26dcghvL6a958QJ2ffxJFcE6SP3BmIZVJcGDrqcSYhYQB0T22FaqVcc25QM3BQJz@QE)

Here were some other attempts.

**39 bytes**

```python
lambda n:eval('('*n+'n'+'+.5)**2//2'*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoAgEAXQq7ibGYUEo4igm7QxygrsKxJBp7fe8uX3PhLaIZcaprlGfy2rVxi3x0cmJg1DIEOm6URrZ637S2pIRUGdUMVj37iXMZcTNweGSP0A)

Based on @dingledooper's comment.

**40 bytes**

```python
def f(n):exec("n*=n/2+.5;"*n+"print(n)")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TSFNI0/TKrUiNVlDKU/LNk/fSFvP1FpJK09bqaAoM68EKKuk@T8tv0ghTyEzT6EoMS89VcNM0wqk7T8A)

**41 bytes**

```python
lambda n:0*[n:=n*-~n//2for _ in[1]*n]or n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchLCoAgFAXQeat4Q5XCPhAhuBKTMMoK6ibSpElbtxqeE@5rPdF0ISav@7S7Y5wcQZXCQGmI4oGUtT8jDbTBVFbAfkD6C19RdFhm1nKVUYgbLoacPAPn6QU)

Comment: Also a cute 36 for py2 is `lambda L:eval('('*L+'L*2+1)**2/8'*L)` (it does fail for n=0 though). It takes advantage of the 'L' suffix to save a couple bytes. Sadly I'm not aware of any "feature" like this for py3.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 42 bytes

think i might be able to get it down further... lmk if you guys see anything !!

```python
lambda x:eval("sum(range("*x+"x"+"+1))"*x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TctLDoIwEAbgvacws@rYWTAd2hITbuKmRlATqASR1NPXbgwsv/8xfZfHK0ru20sewni9hWM6d2sYFLw/o5pDvHcKTklDAg2aEQswT/MzLqpXFVKFh78YiTcZJLdJkIzs2rpsuXHW7/4WSWovJfNsGmZnMf8A)

Comment: Using xnor's calculation I can get [40 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3NXISc5NSEhXyrFLLEnM0lDTyrGyVtPK0lfKUtJW0dOvy9PWNNIECmlD1mQVFmXklGmkaBpo6BppcMJ6hpo4hgmekqWOG4Blr6hgZI8maANUaWpiZmiPpN9XUMTYxNwaKmRsaWRgamplCLVywAEIDAA), but py3.8+ only.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
RS$¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8oWOXQwv///5sAAA)

Full program, takes \$n\$ as the first argument and outputs \$f(n, n)\$

### How it works

```
RS$¡ - Main link. Takes n on the left
  $  - Last two links as a monad f(n):
R    -   Range [1, ..., n]
 S   -   Sum; T(n)
   ¡ - Apply f n times, beginning with n
```

Answer (score 5):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 23 bytes

```
i::?\~n;
-10.\r:1+*2,r1
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiaTo6P1xcfm47XG4tMTAuXFxyOjErKjIscjEiLCJpbnB1dCI6IjQiLCJzdGFjayI6IiIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJudW1iZXJzIn0=)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## [Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), <s>64</s> 48 bytes

```
[>+>+<<-]>[->[[>+>+<<-]>>-[<<+>>-]<<]>[<+>-]<<]>
```

[Try it online!](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=SGVhZGVyOiBnaXZlIE4gaGVyZQorKysrCgpBY3R1YWwgY29kZQpbPis-Kzw8LV0gICAgICAgICAgIyBEdXBsaWNhdGUKPlstICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICMgUmVwZWF0IGlucHV0IHRpbWVzOgogID5bICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAjIFdoaWxlIHggPSBuIGNhbiBiZSBkZWNyZW1lbnRlZAogICAgWz4rPis8PC1dICAgICAgICAgICMgQWNjdW11bGF0ZSByZXN1bHQgYW5kIG1ha2UgY29weQogICAgPj4tWzw8Kz4-LV08PCAgICAgICMgTW92ZSBjb3B5IG1pbnVzIDEgYmFjawogIF0-WzwrPi1dPDwgICAgICAgICAjIE1vdmUgYmFjayBhY2N1bXVsYXRlZCBUKG4pIGFzIG5ldyB4Cl0-Cg$$)  (Up to `n = 3` with 8 bit numbers, `n = 4` with 32 bit, `n = 5` with 64 bit, `n = 6` possibly never [with BigInt].)

Rather simple brainfuck answer.  Assumes you initialise the tape with the input on cell 0 and stores the output in cell 2.  If input given in binary, just wrap the code in `,` and `.` for +2 bytes.  If the input should be the number in ASCII this would also involve writing the parser, I feel that is not in the spirit of the challenge.

The input in the first cell (0) is duplicated and then the loop simply iterates on cell 1.  Each value of the triangle is added to cell 3 and copied back with 1 removed to cell 2.  At the end of the loop that new value is stored in cell 2.

```
Header: give N here
++++

Actual code
[>+>+<<-]          # Duplicate
>[-                # Repeat input times:
  >[                 # While x = n can be decremented
    [>+>+<<-]          # Accumulate result and make copy
    >>-[<<+>>-]<<      # Move copy minus 1 back
  ]>[<+>-]<<         # Move back accumulated T(n) as new x
]>
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>63</s> 62 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,y=-1:f(x,x)if y<0else x if y<1else f(x*(x+1)/2,y-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcxBDoIwEIXhPafoDqoldloKxNjDVCyRBJEwmLSnryMLYfn9bzJzXJ/vSafU29G97g/Hgoi2hGtfBBH40LN4k35EzwLbABtoPRXhDPyiRCyBJ4fol5W65NbK7E8gwk5FrHdqotKHvfqdQ1ub5vDDUNRVoyk2oFqA2mTzMkxrkeOn6zxiztMX)

Calculates a(n) using the OEIS definition given in the OP, probably still golfable

Edit: fixed inputs and added "f="

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
LsSbyF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/36c4OKnS7f9/EwA)

#### Alternative 6 byte solution

```
usSGQQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v7Q42D0w8P9/EwA)

#### Another alternative 6 byte solution

```
.v*"sS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X69MS6k4@P9/EwA)

This one's my favorite.

#### Another alternative 6 byte solution

```
em=sSQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzXXtjg48P9/EwA)

Feels like there's gotta be a 5 byte solution but I got nothing

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 26 bytes

```
[ dup [ [1,b] Σ ] times ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnVqUl5qjkJtYkgEm9IoS89JTiyHs0rzM5PyUVIWCotSSksqCosy8EoXi1MLS1LxkoBJrLi4Lhcz8ksT/0QoppQUK0QrRhjpJsQrnFivEKpRk5gKVxP7PTSxQKC5JTM7W@w8A)

Literally just take the sum of the range of the input <input> number of times. Since `sum` dispatches on `range`s to use the arithmetic formula, it's even efficient.

Answer (score 4):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 bytes

```
{RS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWi6uDgpcUJyUXQ_kLFppCGAA)

##### Explanation

```python
{RS  # Implicit input
{    # Repeat input number of times:
 R   #  One-range of top of stack (initially the input number)
  S  #  Sum the resulting list and leave it for the next iteration
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 4):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>9</s> 6 bytes

*Edit: -3 bytes thanks to ovs*

```
+´⟜↕⍟⊣
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgK8K04p+c4oaV4o2f4oqjCgpGwqggMOKAvzHigL8y4oC/M+KAvzTigL81)

```
+´⟜↕⍟⊣
     ⍟  # Repeat
      ⊣ # number of times equal to argument
+´⟜↕    # this function:
    ↕   #   range 0..(arg-1)
  ⟜     #   as left arg to 
+´      #   fold-addition
        #   with starting value of function arg
        #   (so: sum of 0..arg)
```

Comment: This can be `(⊢+´↕)⍟⊣` (left argument of reduction is seed value), which can be further shortened to `+´⟜↕⍟⊣`.

Answer (score 4):

## [R≥4.1](https://www.r-project.org), 33 bytes

```r
\(x){Map(\(i)x<<-sum(0:x),1:x);x}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3FWM0KjSrfRMLNGI0MjUrbGx0i0tzNQysKjR1DIGEdUUtROHa4sSCgpxKoIypTpomRGzBAggNAA)

R afficionados should wince when they see `Map` used for it's out-of-scope side-effect due to `<<-` assignment, and the result discarded...

## [R<4.1](https://www.r-project.org), 42 bytes

```r
f=function(x,y=x)`if`(y,f(sum(1:x),y-1),x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGCpaUlaboWN7XSbNNK85JLMvPzNCp0Km0rNBMy0xI0KnXSNIpLczUMrSo0dSp1DTV1KjQhOtYWJxYU5FRqGFiZ6qRBxWCmAQA)

Without the short `\` form, it's too expensive to define two `function`s.

Comment: For the second solution, assigning the two-argument recursive function to `?` instead of `f` is [one byte shorter](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMG2_IKSzPy8Yo3i5MyC1DxbS0tLTa4026WlJWm6Fjc1E-wTbNNK85JBajQqdCptKzQTMtMSNCp1iktzNQytKjTtK3UNdSo0IRrWFicWFORUahhYmeqkQcUWLIDQAA), as usual :)

Comment: [32 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3FWI0KjSDUlNKk1M1YjQSdZI0i0tzNQysEjV1KqwMdSo0IerWFicWFORUAiVMddKgYgsWQGgA), no `<<-` needed!

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 34 bytes

```ruby
f=->x,y=x{y<1?x:f[(1..x).sum,y-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W165Cp9K2orrSxtC@wiotWsNQT69CU6@4NFenUtcwtvZ/gUJatEEsF4gyjv0PAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
(-:*>:)^:]
```

Requires extended precision integer as input. -1 thanks to @Bubbler.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxSkPXSsvOSjPOKhYisEmTKzU5I19BR08hTc1OIVPPogIisWABhAYA)

```
(-:*>:)^:]­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
       ^:   NB. ‎⁡repeat
         ]  NB. ‎⁢y times
    >:      NB. ‎⁣increment
 -:         NB. ‎⁤halve
   *        NB. ‎⁢⁡multiply
```

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
(-:*>:)^:x:
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxWkPXSsvOSjPOqsIKIrJJkys1OSNfQUdPIU3NTiFTz6ICIrFgAYQGAA)

```
(-:*>:)^:]­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
       ^:    NB. ‎⁡repeat
         x:  NB. ‎⁢y times but promote to extended precision
    >:       NB. ‎⁣increment
 -:          NB. ‎⁤halve
   *         NB. ‎⁢⁡multiply
```

Comment: `(-:*>:)^:]` works with extended precision integers.

Comment: Ah, good catch!

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 29 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,y=x)=>y?f(x*++x/2,y-1):x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcRLDkAwEADQvVNYzmh9lyhnkWplRIyUyPT05S3evrzLbQNdT3ny6lLyBkRHI2imOHuQQimpOx3LFntJQ@Y5AJlmyGns/pUitHzefLjq4A1IeyDE9AE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
!→¹¡Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8WiDocF/xUdtkw7tPLTw3OL//wE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `R`, 14 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 1.75 bytes

```
(∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJSPSIsIiIsIijiiJEiLCIiLCI0Il0=)

Yeah...

```python
(   # Input number of times:
 ∑  #  Sum top of stack
    #  (R flag makes it take the range instead of the digits)
```

Comment: uhm ackshully, this can be shorter if you use vyncode, a fractional byte compression scheme first introduced in vyxal 2.21.0

Comment: At least it’s >0

Comment: [exactly what I was thinking of](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/262647/sum-of-a-range-of-a-sum-of-a-range-of-a-sum-of-a-range-of-a-sum-of-a-range-of-a#comment575810_262647)

Comment: Why is this not titled "vyncode `-R`", or perhaps "Vyxal `-R=`"? (I'm not familiar with the implementation).

Comment: @JonathanAllan I had [mentioned](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/106764?m=63474658#63474658) it to lyxal earlier but it seems everyone just uses the template that I've used in this answer. The [online interpreter](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/) generates that template when you click on the CGCC post button.

Comment: Agreed, while there _is_ a link to more information it's still a little misleading with the same language name as a potential other answer, but I see their point. The only adverse effect would be if there are two different Vyxal * submissions with different implementations of the same SBCS byte count one of which is compressed and the other not (or with an earlier vyncode version), in which case someone will probably comment anyway. I wonder - is there any skill to writing longer programs so that they will compress better (sounds like a headache to me!)?

Comment: @JonathanAllan not longer, but different combinations of built-ins. Two programs can have the same sbcs byte count and do the exact same thing, yet have different bit counts (as is the nature of range coding). I've spent a good 20 minutes fiddling with different ways of arranging things trying to get the optimal bit count, so yes there actually is a bit of skill involved, as you need to have a general idea of what can be substituted for something else.

Comment: @lyxal that all makes sense, and is good to know, thanks! (Although I _should_ have written "_when_ writing programs longer than two bytes ..." rather than "_to_ writing longer programs" >.<) Perhaps some of this is ripe for tips.

Answer (score 3):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org) – 52 bytes

```rkt
(define(f x y)(if(= y 0)x(f(/(*(+ x 1)x)2)(- y 1))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY7BbsIwEETv@YoRqOqagki4VCLiA3rqhRtCwpB1a9VZI9spyYVfT522h567h5F23mg0QV8@OI1zp@UN4eehho0VJoMegyJraIcBperJ0JoW9JT9SvVqo2iVQaXyjWR8WDsbE@ggICurkCsZm7JUR1UA1Nh4dXpwmeZsqxNmB9niro/YZcX9YYaJZZGpsihq7D26yNi/vD5GWLl2Ccaya5AbcJLTEhfftiwJ6Z2hz/6TkW4eLu@Py8kUdPI3801wZudv26Imx7@DA@tmGlr/Y@lYPX8B)

### Explanation

We `define` a function `f` that receives two arguments: `x` and `y` where `y` is used as decrementing iterator that when equal to zero will make `f` return the result of `x`.

```rkt
(define (f x y)
  (if (= y 0)
      x
      (f (/ (* (+ x 1) x) 2)
         (- y 1))))
```

We can represent this function mathematically using the following:

$$
f(x, y) =
\begin{cases}
x & y = 0 \\
f(\frac{x(x+1)}{1}, y - 1) & y > 0
\end{cases}
$$

### Sub-optimal variations

To allow user input I could've done:

```rkt
(let([n(read)])(let f([x n][y n])(if(= y 0)x(f(/(*(+ x 1)x)2)(- y 1)))))
```

Which consists of 72 bytes when minified.
We could also have used a combination of a lambda and `let` statement to save one byte:

```rkt
((λ(n)(let f([x n][y n])(if(= y 0)x(f(/(*(+ x 1)x)2)(- y 1)))))(read))
```

(The `λ` character equals two bytes.)

### Conclusion

Have an amazing day! I am still mind blown at Racket's speed and capability of handling large numbers. At \$n = 17\$, TIO can't seem to render all the digits alongside all iterations of the `for` loop in the footer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
ＮθＦθ≔Σ…·¹θθＩθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05orLb9IAchQcCwuzkzP0wguzdXwzEvOKS3OLEsNSsxLT9Uw1FEo1NQEEdZcAUWZeSUazonFJUA9mtb//xv/1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
Ｆθ
```

Repeat `n` times...

```
≔Σ…·¹θθ
```

... replace the current value the sum of its range.

```
Ｉθ
```

Output the final value.

14 bytes for an efficient version:

```
ＮθＦθ≔÷×⊕θθ²θＩθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05orLb9IAchQcCwuzkzP0/DMK3HJLMtMSdUIycxNLQbyk4tSc1PzSlJTgKp0FEDYCExbcwUUZeaVaDgnFpcApTSt//83@69blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses the triangle formula to sum the range.

Answer (score 2):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 23 bytes

```ruby
~(:-&(:**&(:+|:sum))).D
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboW2-s0rHTVNKy0tICEdo1VcWmupqamngtE9qZSgYJbtGEsF4gyglDGEMoEQpnGQlQuWAChAQ)

### Explanation

With some whitespace:

```ruby
~(:- & (:** & (:+ | :sum))).D
```

The core function here is `:** & (:+ | :sum)`, where `:+` constructs a range and `:sum` sums it, and `:**` applies that function to its own result `n` times. That does what we want—but only if we call it like `F.(n).(n)`. In order to be able to call it like `F.(n)`, we use `:-` to turn it into `F.(n, n)`, `D` to force `F` to be treated as a dyad, and then `~` to repeat the given argument the necessary number of times (which is two, thanks to `D`).

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
t:":s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8RKyar4/38TAA)

#### How it works

```
t      % Input (implicit). Duplicate
:      % Range
"      % For each
  :    %   Range
  s    %   Sum
       % End (implicit). Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, 10 bytes

```
{+/⍤⍳⍣⍵⊢⍵}
```

### Explanation

```
   ⍤        ⍝ ‎⁡Function composition:
 +/         ⍝ ‎⁢  sum reduce
    ⍳       ⍝ ‎⁣  the numbers from 1 to the argument of the composed function
     ⍣⍵     ⍝ ‎⁤repeated input times
       ⊢⍵   ⍝ ‎⁢⁡starting from the input

 Created with the help of Luminespire at https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), <s>24</s> 20 bytes

```
/O
\I@/.!wrd&+?t.!$K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fnyvG00FfT7G8KEVN275ET1HF@/9/k/8A)

Times out for larger values as it creates a range from 0 to the sum of the last range.

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 21 bytes

```
/O
\I@/.!w.h*2:?t.!$K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fnyvG00FfT7FcL0PLyMq@RE9Rxfv/f7P/AA)

Does not time out as it uses the `n*(n+1)/2` formula instead

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes

```
ᵑ{R∑
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6Fisebp1YHfSoY-KS4qTkYqjggpUGXIZcRlzGXCYQAQA)

```
ᵑ{R∑
ᵑ{      Repeat
  R     Range
   ∑    Sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 20 bytes

```
Nest[#(#+1)/2&,#,#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y@1uCRaWUNZ21BT30hNR1lHOVbtf0BRZl5JtFKeQppGnqZSLJdbflF0nq2BTp6NrRGQ1NbWgajI01FSUNJRSIvOi42N/Q8A)

This code simply nests the short-hand expression for the triangular numbers the given number of times. The computation time starts to become noticeable around `n=20` and my laptop takes around 50 seconds to compute `n=27`, which is a number that takes 63.5 MB to store.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
;?{⟦+}ⁱ⁾
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/39q@@tH8Zdq1jxo3Pmrc9/@/yf8oAA)

#### Explanation

```
;?{  }ⁱ⁾         Iterate <Input> times on the Input:
   ⟦               Range
    +              Sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>33</s> 26 bytes

```julia
~x=(1:x.|>_->x*=(x+1)/2;x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v67CVsPQqkKvxi5e165Cy1ajQttQU9/IukLzf7RCQVFmXklOnoaSikZOQWKKRp6OiaamlYKKRl2eppKmQlp@kUKeQmaegqGVaex/AA)

-7 bytes thanks to MarcMush: replace `for` loop with pipe operator `|>`

### Alternate approach, <s>39</s> 35 bytes

```julia
~x=x|>∘(fill(n->n*(n+1)÷2,x)...)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjeV6ypsK2rsHnXM0EjLzMnRyNO1y9PSyNM21Dy83UinQlNPT08TqlQ_WqGgKDOvJCdPQ0lFI6cgMUUjT8dEU9NKQUWjLk9TSVMhLb9IIU8hM0_B0MpUIRaiDWYTAA)

-4 bytes thanks to MarcMush: remove call to `reduce`

Comment: Your reduce version doesn't need reduce in more recent versions of Julia [`~x=x|>∘(fill(n->(n+1)n/2,x)...)`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjcV6ypsK2rsHnXM0EjLzMnRyNO108jTNtTM0zfSqdDU09PThCrUi1YoKMrMK8nJ01BS0cgpSEzRyNMx0dS0UlDRqMvTVNJUSMsvUshTyMxTMLQyjYXoglkDAA)

Comment: And -7 bytes on the first one [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v67CVsPQqkKvxi5e165Cy1ajQttQU9/IukLzf7RCQVFmXklOnoaSikZOQWKKRp6OiaamlYKKRl2eppKmQlp@kUKeQmaegqGVaex/AA "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 29 bytes

```
(!!)=<<iterate(\x->sum[0..x])
```

Expands to

```
\n -> iterate (\x -> sum [0..x]) n !! n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03BVkFDUVHT1sYmsyS1KLEkVSOmQteuuDQ32kBPryJWkys3MTMPqKigKDOvREFFITexQCFNASRpEvv/PwA)

Answer (score 2):

## x86-64 machine code, 17 bytes

Standard System V ABI, signature `long fsor(int n)` (`n` is taken in `edi`, and the output is placed in `rax`).

```
57 58 50 5e ff c6 48 f7 e6 48 d1 e8 ff cf 7f f2 c3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVTJbtswEL3zKwYuAtiwJSWO4QJ2klOvRQ899FAXBiWOJCYUqXLxgqLf7g7pJU57CVAfBHLmcd6bzSV37QGr1sDg8L2U3sF89oOxJXwNHZgaLNcNQp7nZGq9792iKCojsDGqzp3n1QvuqjaC8sp0xc@AzkujXTGdT@ezj4ULXWbqjGcp0PH4H7aoTHPXgTPJmMdzZs43A1mNqp7PGHNYRSGQe9x5BvRrlCm5gprAMYwyukmXodQe9IhMlI8W3Apwe7cBXkqySd0Hv4CEoS/YAkW0m@CTI4Wx6ILyyc13LAZdJEoSC97EN2SOhj64FiwFSBfTJ/wJ2nEdSJ8yZC6x4sEhxIa41liPNgZ6QeyhMkHHe2SjSOt15Fur/pXyEfRQj@9GxRQooRQx@S4AyoZUOXml6SwwaiLHGTq@ewtewhYpXR@sBh5d89naT6gdJ0qgkgftZKNRONhKpcBs0NbKbEnLfsv3IOuLDmHQgTYeaumPPBzup0BzCH7f4wQ65FpSgYnU8Q2Su9x7hBYtQnDRgxdhUjuPXKSpdTJPVqmrhDgzHjUeMzplvKSJT4xdUDEP33Jib/HUYZCOyrxbEPyaAcl0bmp8aP8modq/oXGtjecJ3J1xAiuLHdJg0URdGgUl7RSEnspE8xjr9wS36QXhIzKdnxu49P21tdSXwwCernaDseNusw9UCRUEwoPzQpq8fWKsKKCpqrhKNq/gaofiPlnIvnFiz77cU5AdDZz@Z2WWjMVDx6UebowUI/iVdNTGQoLIx1vqy8OcPuPxKPnSkFly1sPVIMW6oXePcKPEaqVXgwnIyYljFAlOecV5u12y3@yYHwlm7F1/BO/LMC@igZnyWYSuh@wTZJ9JI6rXR4c/)

### Explanation

```
0000000000000000 <fsor>:
   0:   57                      push   rdi           ; cnt (edi)
   1:   58                      pop    rax           ; n = cnt
                                                     ;
0000000000000002 <__fsor_lp>:                        ; start_loop:
   2:   50                      push   rax           ;
   3:   5e                      pop    rsi           ; n1 = n
   4:   ff c6                   inc    esi           ; n1++
   6:   48 f7 e6                mul    rsi           ; n *= n1
   9:   48 d1 e8                shr    rax,1         ; n >>= 1
   c:   ff cf                   dec    edi           ; cnt--
   e:   7f f2                   jg     2 <__fsor_lp> ; if (cnt > 0) goto start_loop
  10:   c3                      ret                  ; return
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 25 bytes

```perl6
{($_,{.++*$_/2}...*)[$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZm@79aQyVep1pPW1tLJV7fqFZPT09LM1olPrb2vzVXcWKlQhpQXlMhLb9IIc7QwPo/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [ForWhile](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ForWhile), 15 bytes

`{:(.0'(+:):)}1$`

same length, but faster (uses formula for sum of first n numbers):

`{:(.::*+2/:)}1$`

[online Interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=forwhile&src=ezpbOjoqKzIvOil9MSQKCnswOzErKC47MTAlIjAiLis7Mit-LDErJzEwLyc7KScuKCwjKTEwIy59MCQgXCBwcmludCBwb3NpdGl2ZSBpbnQKNCAxQD8gMEA_)

## Explanation

`{ }1$` defines a function, store it at id 1

the argument is read from the stack

`:` duplicate the argument

`(.` loop but ignore the loop counter

`0'(+:)` compute the triangle number corresponding to the top value on the stack

`:)` end of for loop, now the next triangle number is on the stack

returns the result on the stack

Example for how to call the function

```
{:(.0'(+:):)}1$ \ the actual function

4 1@? \ call the function with argument 4

\ print the top stack value as an integer, displaying stack values directly is not supported by this version of the interpreter
0;1+(.;10%"0".+;2+~,1+'10/';)'.(,#)10#. 
\ alternatively you can read the stack contents in the browser console from the 'valueStack' variable
```

The interpreter is newer than the challenge, but it implements he same language as the original [C interpreter](https://github.com/bsoelch/ForWhile).

Comment: Amazing that "The interpreter is newer than the challenge" when the challenge is still only 2h old, but somehow I'm afraid the link doesn't work for me...

Comment: I have worked on porting the language to JavaScript for a while now, but only made the (unfinished) version public after the challange was posted. The link might not work since I created the GitHub page just a few minutes ago

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 18 bytes

```
.+
*
"$+"+`_
$>`
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS4tLSUVbSTshnkvFLoEr/v9/YwA) No test suite due to the way the program uses history. Explanation:

```
.+
*
```

Convert `n` to unary.

```
"$+"+`
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
_
$>`
```

Replace the current value with its range, effectively taking the sum.

```
_
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>6</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
_Å╒Σ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/@cOujqZPOLf7/34DLkMuIy5jLhMsUAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
_      # Duplicate the (implicit) input-integer†
 Å     # Pop one, and loop that many of times,
       # using the following two characters as inner code-block:
  ╒    #  Pop an integer, and push a list in the range [1,integer]
   Σ   #  Pop a list, and push its sum
       # (after the loop, the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

† The initial duplicate `_` is necessary despite having implicit inputs for two reasons:

1. MathGolf uses `0` if a stack is empty and it needs an integer. Although I think it's a bug in MathGolf (I'm not 100% sure), unfortunately that `0` will take priority over the implicit input-integer in the first iteration of a for-loop. So for any \$n>0\$, just `Å╒Σ` will result in `0` because `Å` will push a 0 in its first iteration and use it for the `╒`, instead of using the (implicit) input-integer.
2. For \$n=0\$, the `Å╒Σ` will only pop the (implicit) input-integer and leave the stack empty, and thus it'll output an empty string as result. The initial `_` will ensure a second `0` is still on the stack to be output instead.

Comment: Wow mathgolf doing everything except what the challenge requires without the `_`

Answer (score 1):

## Python + `vyxal`, 68 Bytes

```python
lambda x:execute_vyxal("","eR"+"s"*x,str(x))
from vyxal.main import*
```

With the power of Python, I can make dynamic flags!*

The `vyxal` package can be installed using `pip install vyxal`.

---

###### *Oh wait dynamic flags sound very useful

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 73 bytes

```
s/!*/&''&/g
:a
s/<(!*)''!(!*>)/<'\1'\2/
s/(<!*)'(!*)!/\1\2!'\2/
ta
s/'//g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY/dbsIwDIXv8xS1JjXABKc/wKCKerenWHeRtF1BgwYtISqa9urrksyS/Vk@tmWbvlsP432eDWiFlPMUA6skMxALWi05J496CcGbnDcFvLAQQQgqocmbgmLdhhkODPNTch/l1yOxOun69nyVl@Rk7c1UQKu7ftCXj42xsv3sp/Ykx6HftPoKiV1eFkfkWXYo96zqGAjfficFg/NnGTiHySd4I/cOMpiaZ6QZYhdUbFEK21BQhDLQEfaRCi@RJQ6RWxzBHiDlJuTFjvwLHfth4fMaIqsxi5oJCv4fqP7VN3vWo5nXr38)

Input is unary, with exclamation marks, surrounded by angle brackets. Output is unary with exclamation marks, surrounded by angle brackets. In the TIO link I made it convert to decimal for the output, so that it's easier to see. If you would like to see the unary output, just delete everything in the footer section.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 27 bytes

```perl
$\=$_;$\*=$\++/2while$_--}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxlYl3lolRstWJUZbW9@oPCMzJ1UlXle3tvr/f9N/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Comment: Overflows to infinity on nine, but that’s ok.

Comment: adding `-Mbigint` option: https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxlYl3lolRstWJUZbW9@oPCMzJ1UlXle3tvr/f8t/@QUlmfl5xf91C/7r@iZlpmfmlQAA

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 36 bytes

```c
x;a(n){for(x=n;n--;x/=2)x+=x*x;n=x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc1BDoIwEIXhNT3FBGPSVtDIttaLGBe1CEwCU1PRTEI4ey1Ll@/7F8/Xvfdph@THT/uEy3tuR3wch6v4MwyZEhsnSS1diJItGaprwyfbKD5Y1mzIslnT5JAk0gwu9r4CP7gIWufxVWIRxVYILLg5oNz0dr4rI4pXzKWT5b4tK9huMq4pNT8)

Was missing a semicolon, so now it's 36 bytes.

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##Vc2xDsIgFIXhuTzFTY0JkFJjV8QXMQ4ItiWpF4NoSJr66gij4/n@4RgxGZN3Ds3ytnc4vaJd3K2fz@TPnC@Uk9QU2Tr6QJNCiUJIlrgS33QYeokqyS0/tEPqMIIOk@nAzDoA52V8GFlJUwuCAh29o1UvxyuTpHmGUkba7m3bQX0puOU8/AA)

Comment: @c-- Thanks for the tip. And that's a beautiful statement there: `x*=-~x/2.;`. Took me nearly a half hour to fully grok it.

Comment: maybe something like `x*=-.5*~x;` makes more sense, but I'm used to looking at `-~x` as `(x+1)` thanks to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6374/112488) tip

Comment: I'm familiar enough with bit twiddling to catch that part, it was the floating-point and type coercion that caught me. Then I tried it without the decimal point and figured it all out. Thanks for the teaching tips.

Comment: Right, implicit conversions are very useful. Anytime :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 45 bytes

Input is in a variable `n`. Output is placed in variable `f`.

Start the ticker to run the program. To reset, run the action in the "reset" folder.

**Ticker:**

```
\left\{k<n:f->f(f+1)/2\right\},k->k+1
```

**Expression List:**

```
f=n
k=0
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jed1q2lmm9)

---

**Explaination:**

Applies \$f\to T(f)\$ `n` times, using a ticker because Desmos does not support recursion.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õ@=ô x
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=9UA99CB4&input=Mw)

### 5 bytes

If we could output `undefined` for `0`
(or I could [use the `-hF0` flags to output `0`](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWhGMA&code=xj31IHg&input=MA) but I *hate* [Japt's `-E` & `-F` flags!](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/#docs-flags))

```
Æ=õ x
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=xj31IHg&input=MA)

Comment: It has to output 0 for 0, so the 6 byte solution is the valid one.

Comment: What’s wrong with -E and -F ?

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 56 bytes

```go
func(n int)int{k,i:=n,0
for;i<n;i++{k=k*-^k/2}
return k}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY1NCoMwFIT3OcWrICRNbG1X4k_XXfYApRDUyCMYJcRuxJN0I4Ueyts0ti6GbzF8M693083Lrpellk0NrURDsO076w6Bal1AyFNaUMVncCpKlkQNpqQG0DjmM2qBaWFETFRnM8xNhpyPutD76KGP54nY2g3WgJ42_7r6vxfKYFwtQEgLiDPP_LSCc1_crF9XNAgriC4QVncTCEABiiJjZCLb3jz_-QU)

Maxes out at `n=5`.

## [Go](https://go.dev), 138 bytes, `math/big`

```go
import."math/big"
func f(n int)*Int{N:=NewInt
k,i,z:=N(int64(n)),0,N(0)
for;i<n;i,z=i+1,N(0){k.Div(z.Mul(k,z.Add(k,N(1))),N(2))}
return k}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5BSsRAEEX3fYoiMNBlemIiIjKZCIILXdh4ADdxko5Fm87QdBQScgGv4CYIHsKjeBsr47j6Vf9Tv97HZ9PN3_tyZ8umhrYkJ6jddz4kkWlD9NUHs778ef_32jI8nz5REwnTux0Y6YBcwJM7F0a9KXT9xpOwitTAm-Ts4lw6RJUqLVMUpvM5bV3OeUFxdjBHm9zQqxyS-_5FWjUk11XFqmWGfKjlGeIkfB1678BOR6Lbw_-FVyKMSy8QbApIc9Zttkgcc_DgmcHIaFXB-gpW1aOLFJBickIUkzj2zfOf_gI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 9 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⍥(/++1⇡).
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__ZiDihpAg4o2lKC8rKzHih6EpLgoKZiAwCmYgMQpmIDIKZiAzCmYgNApmIDUK)