# German pharmacy payment

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

Your task is to calculate the amount you have to pay for prescribed medication at a pharmacy in Germany. The amount is simply based on the full price of the item, which will be your input. It is a decimal number with exactly two fractional digits (ex. 5.43). You can assume it's strictly positive. Your task is to calculate the amount a customer has to pay, according to this function:

$$
A(x)=\begin{cases}
x&\text{if } x\le 5\\
5&\text{if } 5\le x \le 50\\
0.1x&\text{if }50\le x \le 100\\
10&\text{if }100 \le x
\end{cases}
$$
or equivalently
$$
A(x)=\min(x,\min(\max(0.1x,5),10))
$$

The result must be **rounded** to two decimal places (half up). If these are 0, they may be skipped from the output. There must not be more than 2 decimal places. You can take numbers or strings as input and output, but be aware of inexact floating point representations.

Use a comma or a point as the decimal separator.

### Test cases

(Whitespace just for readability)

`5.00`, `5.0` and `5` are all ok.

```
  4.99  ->  4.99
  5.00  ->  5.00
  5.05  ->  5.00
  10.00 ->  5.00
  49.00 ->  5.00
  50.00 ->  5.00
  50.04 ->  5.00
  50.05 ->  5.01
  50.14 ->  5.01
  50.15 ->  5.02
  99.84 ->  9.98
  99.85 ->  9.99
  99.94 ->  9.99
  99.95 -> 10.00
 100.00 -> 10.00 
1000.00 -> 10.00
```

Comment: You should have a test case between 5 and 50; otherwise the second row of your formula isn’t tested

Comment: @NickKennedy Thanks, I added a few test cases

Comment: Your spec says you can assume it’s strictly positive, but the examples include zero. Can we assume it’s positive, or do we have to handle zero?

Comment: A price of zero doesn't make sense in this context, so I removed the test case.

Comment: Is it ok to return 5 instead of 5.00 ?

Comment: No, it will always be printed with two decimal places on your reciept, and that's what I'm trying to go for.

Comment: @corvus_192 It seems that most answers are not outputting in the correct format.

Comment: @corvus_192 a float of exactly `5.00` might be represented as `5.0` or `5` etc. Is a function that returns floats not valid?

Comment: @alephalpha It seems I was unclear with the specification. To not invalidate existing answers, I'll allow 5, 5.0, 5.00 but no more than 2 fractional digits.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
÷⁵«⁵»5«+ȷ-4ær2
```

A monadic Link that accepts the full price as a float and outputs the charge as a float.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9keNWw@tBhG7TQ@t1j6xXdfk8LIio/86h9s13f//jzbQMzDQUTDRs7TUUTAFs4GkqY6CIVTCEiJmAKdMIJQpmDKE8AyBPEtLPQsTCAXhWUJ4lmDDIPqBNIgRCwA)**

#### How?

```
÷⁵«⁵»5«+ȷ-4ær2 - Link: Full Price           P
÷⁵             - divide Full Price by 10    P/10
  «⁵           - minimum with 10            min(10,P/10)
    »5         - maximum with 5             max(5,min(10,P/10))
      «        - minimum with Full Price    min(P,max(5,min(10,P/10)))
       +ȷ-4    - add 0.0001 (catering for banker's rounding effects below)
           ær2 - round to two decimal places
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the output requirement of always having 2 decimal places

Comment: This is a monadic Link (function) and the result is a float. It is always rounded to two decimal places, but the representation of a float like `5.00` is `5.0`. I have added a comment under the question as output formatting isn't part of the requirements unless clearly specified as such, and I don't feel that this challenge is about output formatting.

Comment: @SamDean the restrictions have been relaxed.

Answer (score 6):

## APL+WIN, 21 bytes

Prompts for input

```
2⍕(n⌊((.1×n←⎕)⌈5))⌊10
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tv9Gj3qkaeY96ujQ09AwPT88DygBVaD7q6TDVBJJdhgb/geq4/isopHEZ6BkYcIEYJnqWlmCGKUzE1ACZZQJnmcJYhnAxQ4iYpaWehQmcBRezhItZAsXSuAwNwCaDGWAWAA)

Comment: You can get rid of the parentheses and write as a dfn `{2⍕⍵⌊10⌊5⌈.1×⍵}`

Comment: Thanks for the comment but unfortunately my version of APL+WIN is 20 years old and does not have any of that functionality. Fortunately I can still use the basic functionality of Dyalog Classic to post my answers on TIO.

Comment: @Tbw see my comment above. Please feel free to port any of my answers into a modern APL to demonstrate how far the language has developed.

Comment: ah I see. You can actually make my solution shorter by making it tacit as `2⍕⊢⌊10⌊5⌈.1×⊢`, but I'm not sure that would help in running in your case. I think I will post a solution.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 39 bytes

```r
\(x)round(.001+min(x,max(.1*x,5),10),2)
```

Basically using the formula given by the OP.

-5 bytes thanks to @doubleunary

-3 bytes and fix a rounding error thanks to @NickKennedy

-6 bytes since the OP removed the requirement for exactly 2 decimal places.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtLCoAwDESvk2gJSTV@EA8jSsGFFUSht6/W6mbefJgjujG6y8/nunsIeOyXX4CYpdzWpzDbFICkCEbRCKOxGB30jIMDKy@kSVqTlUQl1ndUkt80Wld5bTUr9V37tF/ID2FmjDc)

Comment: hmm... `round(min(x,max(.1*x,5),10),2)`

Comment: @doubleunary obviously... thx!

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 bytes

```apl
2⍕⊢⌊10⌊5⌈.1×⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#%23SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P03hUdsEBaNHvVMfdS161NNlaAAkTB/1dOgZHp4OFPr/vyS1uKQYrMpEz9JSwVTPwABEmCoYGoCYJpZgAQMYaQImTUGkIZhtaKpgaalnYQImwWxLMNsSZAJYG5AC0VwaIGccWgG2UFMn2lDPNDYNylV41DtXoaAotaSkUiEtvyg3saQkMy8dAA)

Tacit prefix function. Takes input as number.
Thanks to Graham for original APL solution.

#### How it works:

```apl
2⍕⊢⌊10⌊5⌈.1×⊢ ⍝ Anonymous, tacit function.
         .1×⊢ ⍝ 0.1x
       5⌈      ⍝ max with 5
    10⌊        ⍝ min with 10
   ⊢⌊          ⍝ min with x (as a fork)
2⍕            ⍝ format with 2 decimal places
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 40 bytes

```javascript
x=>Math.min(x,x<50?5:(x*10+.5|0)/100,10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddA9boMwFAfwnVM8sWAX4poKS3EoZMrYqSPKgPhIqKiNwK2Q2t6gUpeO7T16nlygR6AGESVEZXm2fu9vW34P8XPcJHVRqYWQadblQdcG4V2s9uSxEKh12ltG12yF2iuX2oS9UnztUuq4FHd@ZABEAECJFr2a/caErTO6RzgfvN@cOTvm2TTPxov@c2/G2eju1F1vxo/5mzPnnCyHPCd8eeFsdD517s24zpvudA56XsO/Tg5DQ/tFw9gaJJf1Jk72CEWFqByQT2qLIQjhRZ8pMwV11kAAOdJd7GtLpGhkmZFS7nojSt6ruhA7hEkVpxuRIobBBhMWoS52f34ug4a7g/5NWIP1@/Nx@PrU1YIVWIfvdwvrF9@w3/0B)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 45 bytes

```python
lambda x:round(sorted([x,5,10,x/9.999])[1],2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc/BDoMgDAbgO0/RIyTMgZNkmLijL@E8sGgiiVOiuLmndyjTZJwoX/42rfnYpu8uS57BfWnV81EpmNOhn7oKj/1g6woXMxWUMzqfZSSlLEnBSxqT5d3otgaeIlCQQf1SLdadmSwm0WgHbdbXtNr9C1YSBGbQncWKQo4VIQsAixgDON18hQASN9/DWjkQR0L4hNh6AkhCEDtwDzwJ4UjEDqSMrj7hDrz@QOwgPcgkhC3B/eqc7YttAMjBn3wB)

-2 from PattuX

Comment: The reason to add a small positive number here is to cater for the fact that Python's `round` does banker's rounding by default, which rounds half-way points to the nearest even multiple. (It also negates any floating point effects that this rounding can introduce as per the first note in the [round documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#round))

Comment: @JonathanAllan As it happens, there are no floating point effects between `0.00` and `100.00`, at least not using the naïve formula `floor(x*10+0.5)/100` rather than `round(x/10,2)`.

Comment: The rounding only affects the cases from 50 too 100€, i.e., the x/10 part. You can also fix it by not dividing by 10 but a slightly smaller number, saving 2 bytes: ```lambda x:round(sorted([x,5,10,x/9.999])[1],2)```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>95</s> 92 bytes

```
\.

.+
$*
^(.{1000}(?=.{8995})|.(.{499,998})(?=\2{9}....)|.{0,500}).*
00$.1
0*(.+)(..)
$1.$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY6xCgIxDIb3PEeFtneE9Gig/yCOvsQhOji4OIhb7bP30oIZvnzkTyCf5/f1fvSTv977zkS8kIt081yTiDR/OXMtgLbwYxtmYAVKCxbsW0VjK4uqrGrrgSOJOE4k0fMSvIXkErutd2ERygyQDlP5M0/qYJqelAAueXI6pkPJnhpn4zfrBw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\.
```

Multiply by `100`.

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
^(.{1000}(?=.{8995})|.(.{499,998})(?=\2{9}....)|.{0,500}).*
00$.1
```

Calculate the amount to pay, with two `0`s prefixed in case the amount is less than `100`.

```
0*(.+)(..)
$1.$2
```

Divide by `100`.

The disjunctions are as follows:

- `.{1000}(?=.{8995})` Any amount over `9994` becomes `1000`.
- `.(.{499,998})(?=\2{9}....)` Any amount over `4999` becomes a tenth of its value. `.(.{499,998})` is the amount to pay, between `500` and `999`, but the input has to match that value plus `9` times `1` less than that value plus `4`, which equals `10` times that minus `5`, thus rounding half up.
- `.{0,500}` Any amount below `500` is unchanged, but amounts between `500` and `4999` become `500`.

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets / Microsoft Excel, 31 bytes

`=fixed(min(10,A1,max(5,A1/10)))`

Put the input in cell `A1` and the formula in `B1`. The `fixed()` function also takes care of rounding.

Equivalent JavaScript (rounding issue, non-competing, **45 bytes**):

`x=>Math.min(10,x,Math.max(5,x/10)).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>42</s> 36 bytes

```ruby
->a{[a,[a/10,5].max,10].min.round 2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdDRCoIwFIDhe59iD6CnTTbwQHlVt72ASBglCKViCYb67OvkScnR1Tl8/IxtTXt@2Xxngzjrk8xPso2SvknhnnW@kjSLEpqqLS8iHO12ezju4VaU1wcFdT90Qy3ypINndcrT0RNCgpRCBDFvBBoQGT4bgVkKwwUNswI1HfIDGh0w8g9oF8wMikFpF5YiJECEiAsEjL5gZkAG1C5MheLXKjlfjN/gEazEo/@zbw)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 38 bytes

Formatted as per initial requirement:

```ruby
->a{"%.2f"%[a,[a/9.999,5].max,10].min}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdDNCoMwDAfwu09RBt60a6UFA87Tdt0LiIwOVhA2J/sAh/rsXWamzLJTwq9/QpPb8/hyduPi3HSrkCd2FRYmKswaOABEuuQX00ZSYK3qwWXZbr/l56o@3fGh6fq2b5gtWv64Hmw5BIwJLgRjcU4dgsJBBJ8OQc8JTQksegFyHPIDCjzQ4g8oH/QEkkAqH@ZEggDAU0rg8ukX9ARAAMqHMSFpWymmj9EOAcJCAryfewM)

Comment: This sometimes prints 5 or 5.0 instead of 5.00

Comment: @Evargalo That's ok, it was unclear, so I removed the restriction.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes

```javascript
x=>~~(Math.min(x*10,x<50?50:x,100)*10+.5)/100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddA9boMwFAfwnVM8sWAX4poKS3EoZMrYqSPKgPhIqKiNwK2QquYElbp0bO/R8@QCPQI1iKghKov99Ht/P8t@iJ/jJqmLSi2ETLMuD7o2CA8HdBerPXksBGqvXOq0t4yuGV21jksp1mIThq913fmRARABACWUOno3@8KErTO6RzgfvC/OnJ3ybJpn46D/3JtxNro7ddeb8VP@5sw5J8shzwlfXjgbnU@dezOu86Y7/Qf9V8O7/hyGhvaLhrE1SC7rTZzsEYoKUTkgn9QWQxDCiz5TZgrqrIEAcqS72NeWSNHIMiOl3PVGlLxXdSF2CJMqTjciRQyDDSYsQr3Y/fm5DBpmB/2dsAbr5/v9@PmhVwtWYB2/3iysb3zFfvcL)

---

### 40 bytes

This one works in theory, but fails on some test cases because of rounding errors.

```javascript
x=>Math.min(x,x<50?5:x/10,10).toFixed(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddE9boMwFAfwnVM8sWArxDURruJQyJRunTqiDIiPhIraCGiFVPUGlbp0bO/R8@QCPQK1KVFDFBbb@r2/n2X7IXqO6rjKy2YuZJJ2md@1fnAXNXvymAvU2u0No2u2aq8cajsUk0be5m2aoAXuvNAACAGAEkptNZt6YcLWHtwlnPeuFyfOjnk2zrOh0SV3J5wN7ozdcSf8mF@cOOdk2ec54cszZ4PzsXN3wlXedMbv4NC/e/079AXlZwVja5BMVpso3iMU5qK0QT41Wwx@AC9qT5E2UKU1@JAhVcWesliKWhYpKeROm/qg@6bKxQ5hUkbJRiSIYZiBCfNADTO9/0LmWmdQ39vXZ8IarJ/v98PnhxotWIF1@HqzsDrxFXvdLw)

Comment: `x=>Math.min(x,x<50?5:(x*10+.5|0)/100,10)` works for all cases and conveniently is also the same length!

Comment: @Neil Seems like l4m2 already came to the same version.

Comment: Huh, I hadn't even noticed...

Comment: Think you need to include the `toFixed(2)` in the first answer to comply with the output requirement of always having 2 decimal places

Comment: @SamDean The OP has since clarified that `5`, `5.0` and `5.00` are all acceptable.

Comment: Apologies for the downvote now then. I can remove it if you edit the question "You last voted on this answer yesterday. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 41 bytes

```python
lambda x:min(max(5,(x*20+1)//2/100),x,10)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3NXMSc5NSEhUqrHIz8zRyEys0THU0KrSMDLQNNfX1jfQNDQw0dSp0DA00oRoepuUXKWQqZOYpFCXmpadqmAIVWHEpJBYXpxaVKKRpZIK12NoW5ZfmpWhoZGrrGQBNAorpGGlyYerVAWLsBphiUW0AdAgu9QgLIfZhsxCsW8fQCJcZhgZcClwQjy5YAKEB)

Straight-forward implementation of OP's formula. For the rounding it uses floor division resulting in integer-valued floats which - unlike tenths - are guaranteed to be represented exactly.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
ＮθＩ⌊⟦θχ⌈⟦⁵∕⌊⁺·⁵×θχ¹⁰⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDObG4RMM3My8ztzRXI7pQR8HQQEfBN7ECwjfVUXDJLMtMSdVwy8nPL9IIyCkt1jDQAwqHZOamFmuA1WtqaoIoA81YINS0/v/fzETP2PS/blkOAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of the formula given in the question, but with rounding as required. I checked all inputs from `50.00` to `99.99` and none of them had any rounding errors; even though for example `64.35*100` does not result in `6435`, `64.35*10` does result in `643.5`, which is then rounded to `644`, with a final result of `6.44`.

```
Ｎθ                      First input as a number
                θ       First input
               ×        Multiplied by
                 χ      Literal integer `10`
            ⁺           Plus
             ·⁵         Literal number `0.5`
           ⌊            Floor
          ∕             Divided by
                  ¹⁰⁰   Literal integer `100`
         ⁵              Literal integer `5`
        ⟦               Make into list
       ⌈                Take the maximum
      χ                 Predefined variable `10`
     θ                  Input number
    ⟦                   Make into list
   ⌊                    Take the minimum
  Ｉ                     Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

Formatted to two decimal places also turns out to be 21 bytes:

```
Ｎθ﹪%.2f⌊⟦θχ⌈⟦⁵∕θ⁹·⁹⁹⁹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDNz@lNCdfQ0lVzyhNSUfBNzMvM7c0VyO6UEfB0ADIT6yA8E11FFwyyzJTUjWAMpZ6lpaWmrFAqGn9/7@ZpZ6BwX/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses @PattuX's observation that dividing by `9.999` before rounding suffices to compensate for floating-point errors.

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) 0.3.1, 16 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247669/i-want-8-bits-for-every-character/265917#265917)

```
↧↧↥5⍜×⁅100⊃÷∘10.
```

[See it in action](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_3_1__R1BQIOKGkCDihqfihqfihqU14o2cw5figYUxMDDiioPDt-KImDEwLgoKR1BQIDQuOTkgICMgNC45OQpHUFAgNSAgICAgIyA1CkdQUCA1LjA1ICAjIDUKR1BQIDEwICAgICMgNQpHUFAgNDkgICAgIyA1CkdQUCA1MCAgICAjIDUKR1BQIDUwLjA0ICMgNQpHUFAgNTAuMDUgIyA1LjAxCkdQUCA1MC4xNCAjIDUuMDEKR1BQIDUwLjE1ICMgNS4wMQpHUFAgOTkuODQgIyA5Ljk4CkdQUCA5OS44NSAjIDkuOTkKR1BQIDk5Ljk0ICMgOS45OQpHUFAgOTkuOTUgIyAxMApHUFAgMTAwICAgIyAxMApHUFAgMTAwMCAgIyAxMAo=)

Answer (score 0):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 26 bytes

```
dup.1*5|10,` &/100* |~100/
```

[Try it on scline!](https://scline.fly.dev/#H4sIAM2vWmUCAx2MMQqAQBADe1.RUkGWO9gFg2Bla2GtFoKtYOP_ddNMhkCyuZEIKyURqCXVqUKedDGSVV4DpA0uyilnPmj2R.ZhTYvrfbCPWNGjw30.mDEtH5MqRc56AAAA#H4sIAM2vWmUCA0spLdAz1DKtMTTQSVBQ0zc0MNBSqKkDUvoAuFXTaxoAAAA#)

sclin's default real/rational number representation comes in handy here.

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
dup .1* 5| 10,` &/ 100* |~ 100/
```

Assuming input *n*:

- `dup .1*` *n* * .1
- `5|` min with 5
- `` 10,` &/ `` min with 10 and *n*
- `100* |~ 100/` round 2 decimal places

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 36 bytes

```
#~Min~Max[.1#,5]~Min~10~Round~.01&@x
```

Alas, we cannot save an extra byte by using infix notation with `Max` because multiplication has a lower precedence than passing an argument, so `.1#~Max~5` is equivalent to `.1(#~Max~t)`, rather than `(.1#)~Max~t`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78X2FraalnYcJVYPtfuc43M6/ON7EiWs9QWcc0Fsw1NKgLyi/NS6nTMzBUc6j4H1CUmVfiUPAfAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 44 bytes

```
x->printf("%.2f",min(x,min(max(x/10,5),10)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY5BCsIwEEWvMgSECaQxkQQ6iL2IiHQTKdgSSoV4FjcFEXfex9vYZkrBzbx5f_ghj3es--Z8ieMzwOF1G0JRflUqqtg33RBQbPQuCNU2HaY82zph2lqjvFTWSCmXzqeO8XrHBEUF_11Ics-RRTGfxeQB1xSlgqPTRAq8NiZPr8CaLI44Myscw2dYNjsZkS4dg43YKD_G_Ynzclp-PY7MHw)

A port of [@Evargalo's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266912/9288).

Prints the result to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 16 (or 25) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
T/5‚à‚Tªß4°z+2.ò
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/RN/0UcOswwuARMihVYfnmxzaUKVtpHd40///pgZ6hqYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/xB900cNsw4vABIhh1Ydnm9yaEOVtpHe4U3/df5Hm@hZWuqY6hkYgAhTHUMDENPEEixgACNNwKQpiDQEsw1NdSwt9SxMwCSYbQlmW4JMAGsDUiA6FgA).

This outputs `5.0` or `10.0` instead of `5.00` or `10.00`, like most other answers. To fix this, the following 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) can be added:

```
т+0«6∍¦0Û
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/RN/0UcOswwuARMihVYfnmxzaUKVtpHd408UmbYNDq80edfQeWmZwePb//5aWepamAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/xB900cNsw4vABIhh1Ydnm9yaEOVtpHe4U0Xm7QNDq02e9TRe2iZweHZ/3X@R5voWVrqmOoZGIAIUx1DAxDTxBIsYAAjTcCkKYg0BLMNTXUsLfUsTMAkmG0JZluCTABrA1IgOhYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
T/        # Divide the (implicit) input by 10
5‚        # Pair it with 5
  à       # Pop and push the maximum of the pair
‚         # Pair it with the (implicit) input
 Tª       # Append 10 to this pair
   ß      # Pop and push the minimum of this triplet
4°        # Push 10**4: 10000
  z       # Pop and push 1/10000: 0.0001
   +      # Add it to the value
    2.ò   # Then (banker's) round it to 2 decimals

т+        # Add 100
  0«      # Append a trailing 0
    6∍    # Shorten it to length 6
      ¦   # Remove the leading 1
       0Û # Trim any leading 0s
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 48 bytes

```
{y=$0/10;a=y>5?y>10?10:y:5>$0?$0:5;print a+1e-4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBCoJAFEX3fsVgtoqm92Ie9BRHKCxcpJL2AS4KIoiIIAbx26fmQZtzDxfuHT53vy0PVT02@2Ofx3O9vsaTmqmu7M@tak/lruqqpvajyxNYIWRD7iwVziIUCKlLySZQJJBS9nzdHm81LPCyNJP3RjNHpAECKEIIalgK@NMIKRDFkSJmvTFCcRbn8CCzX4T8Ag)

---

Ungolfed :

```
BEGIN{
    OFMT = "%.2f"
}

func min(n,m){
    return m>n?n:m
}
func max(p,q){
    return p>q?p:q
}

{
    x=min($0,min(max(0.1*$0,5),10))+0.0001
    print $1, "->", x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>106</del> 100 bytes

Saved 6 bytes thanks to @corvus_192

---

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZCxasMwFEXp0MVf8cgkUVuVHMtODA60ZM3S0ClkUGzZuDiSa8utQ8mXdMnSLvmi9Gsq8FCo85YHh_vuvbzP7zYVlZieNxNP6XfRqMn2gvXuRaYGVqJU8OE48CYqyGNAS93tKpksho0h-epM7s0uWZ8sHstiKdNyLyq0lq-od7nLqNvfM4pJqxsjMyLqujoghu-Y9EJLpVnbcIl89--YPOlOZaUqVjqTKMCYGD3EDVk_N7cAmcxhb8sh0RRtDA9NIw6btWns2RbH8KxKA4ltDnZqS02lUI7mFON_yGdjxsIRCojPRpATyseGnLCrNOTB9IpJNBZHnMxnkdWPm1E61D06x-Ebp9OwfwE)

```scala
x=>BigDecimal(Seq(x,5,10,x/10).sorted.apply(1)+1e-6).setScale(2,BigDecimal.RoundingMode(4)).toDouble
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZHNSsNAFEZxm6e4dDXBZJxJO0lbcFEp4qIFsXRVikyTSYikM5JMNCJ5Ejfd1I2P4Vv4NI5N_MF0dYcz33c5cF9ei5BnvP-26rlSPfJc9ta7faljd_hx8q42dyLUMOephGcLIBIxxKgaw1SVm0zY3w84P3wDPPAMCpVrEc3SQhv8NVDlAHOAEgeqM0ps3CQOhYs0mYow3fIM_fYQteEUqHB9kxV6YQwF8pw_YXyjShmlMpmrSOCryezydnltY60aH7O6tlrfrZFHPE-KMUzynD-tFjo3xbWRX8pU_6jfG6oziWI0Irb9D3m0y6jfQQPs0Q5kmLDuQobpUeqzQf_IkqAbDhgeDQOT75oR0ujWVt3csj3prp2f)

```scala
object Main {
  def f(x: Double): Double = {
    val sortedList = List(x, 5, 10, x/10).sorted
    BigDecimal(sortedList(1) + 1e-6).setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(f(90))
    println(f(210))
    println(f(16))
    println(f(4.21))
    println(f(5.05))
    println(f(25.15))
    println(f(25.654321))
    println(f(75))
    println(f(75.987654))
    println(f(1000))
  }
}
```

Comment: 100 bytes: `x=>BigDecimal(Seq(x,5,10,x/10).sorted.apply(1)+1e-6).setScale(2,BigDecimal.RoundingMode(4)).toDouble`

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 50 bytes

```rust
|x|(500f64.max(1e1*x).min(1e3).round()/1e2).min(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZJRb5swFIXf8ytcHipTpR6ksBVvidSXSdNa9WHSNGmaKpJcWmvGQcZu0Ci/PbvgOKVoD@MBX30@59xrg7a1OVR2TQpFylwoGpLLFcF3OyP4SDDkmSzJ4aV5oWkUFe8TVuYNjSG@aEJWoiGGq5DpnVVbGr6LYeFoEx4@nhJqsxUKU3DlXOw4HwANXxWlNWRtiwI0yr4ZLdQj5wr2XrN/EhIG5f1vGjO2HKJsLf4A53c3P0KXLhTTkG8fpFBAz19D/XF8u34fHW6TYbvSN/KKKtem5uQ7bD49rFDaO1hdSWFocLkKQrbZSQkbM/adClEMGT/z@foXes8vhrTRDL6LUJU1nOCtoiw/DsJQXQOuVu11Xo07eB80FfaGrbeu/9@qobbSoOeZDt0nkgqv3kh1RoOWf2CLrv8bWp6yCMu2C@Zu5PkxZt4f1Q9Dlkuf3gb3X4OOgKwB6883X27Pgm7UqTtVx0@wkZBrP2436w6EJCzLSN9@qHADh4gc6CsH0jcgjnrJCCTZBKTRP0AyBakHsQNxMgUnxQJBlrFrp8hYdn0EqQeZA1kyBYNiGHmGix/MnWGG4A35Cw)

Answer (score 0):

## [*><>](https://github.com/redstarcoder/go-starfish), <s>90</s> 89 bytes

-1 byte by removing a semicolon that shouldn't have been there

I'm still trying to condense it using the dive `u` and rise `O` instructions, but in case I forget, here's a working version without them.

Requires running with the `-i` flag to receive input.

```
:5)?!\:5a*)?!\:9b*(?!\aa*:}*:a%:4)?v-   >$a*,n;
   ;n/    ;n5/    ;na/             \a$-+/
```

### Explanation

#### x ≤ 5

```
:5)?!\
   ;n/
```

```
:         Duplicate the input
 5        Push 5 onto the stack
  )       Evaluate 5 > input
   ?!\   If true, redirect down
     /   Redirect left
   ;n     Print the input, and halt execution
```

#### 5 ≤ x ≤ 50

```
:5a*)?!\
    ;n5/
```

```
:         Duplicate the input again
 5        Push 5 onto the stack
  a       Push 10 onto the stack
   *      Multiply the top to values, thus putting 50 onto the stack
    )     Evaluate 50 > input
     ?!\   If true, redirect down
       /   Redirect left
    ;n5    Push 5 onto the stack, print it, and halt execution
```

#### 100 ≤ x

```
:aa*(?!\
    ;na/
```

```
:          Duplicate the input
 aa*       Multiply 10by 10, putting 100 onto the stack
    (      Evaluate 100 < input
     ?!\   If true, redirect down
       /   Redirect left
    ;na    Push 10 onto the stack, print it, and halt execution
```

#### 50 ≤ x ≤ 100

In order to get half-up rounding, we multiply the input by 100 to make it an integer. From there we then round up/down to the nearest 10, and then divide by 1000 to get our final amount.

```
aa*:}*:a%:4)?v-   >$a*,n;
             \a$-+/
```

```
aa*                         Push 100 onto the stack
   :                        Duplicate the 100 on the stack
    }                       Shift the stack to the right, moving the duplicated 100 to the 0th index
     *                      Multiply the input by 100, replacing future instances of "input" with "input * 100"
      :                     Duplicate the input
       a                    Push 10 onto the stack
        %                   Push input modulo 10 onto the stack
         :                  Duplicate that value
          4                 Push 4 onto the stack
           )                Evaluate (input modulo 10) > 4
            ?v              If (input modulo 10) > 4 == true, redirect down
// If (input modulo 10) > 4 == true
             \              Redirect right
              a             Push 10 onto the stack
               $            Swap the top two values on the stack
                -           Subtract (input module 10) from 10
                 +          Add that to the input
                  /         Redirect up
// If (input modulo 10) > 4 == false
              -             Else, subtract (input module 10) from input
// After conditional
                  >         Force instruction pointer to the right
                   $        Swap the two values on the stack, making it [input, 100]
                    a*      Multiply the top value by 10, pushing 1000 onto the stack
                      ,     Divide the input by 1000
                       n;   Print the value and halt execution
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLErLLM74/9/KVNNeMcbKNFELTFsmaWkA6cRELataLatEVSsTTfsyXQUFBTuVRC2dPGsuINM6T18BTJlC6UQwDQcxiSq62vrW////yy8oyczPK/6vm/nf1EjP2BQA)

Answer (score -1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>30</s> actually 35 bytes

A one-liner Desmos equation for once (thanks to Aiden Chow for the fix and optimization):

```
f(x)=round([x,5,10,x/10].sort[2],2)
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ugiaae4h9h)

Comment: You say Desmos takes care of rounding but if I input `50.55` it shows `5.055` not `5.06`.

Comment: @Jonathan Allan Fixed it!

Comment: I see the fix, however it is not rounding half-up (same now gives `5.05` not `5.06`).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, wrapping your original answer with `round(..., 2)` seems to fix the issue (Desmos seems to always round half up from what I've noticed).

Comment: So it would be 39 bytes: `f(x)=round(min(x,min(max(.1x,5),10)),2)`

Comment: But porting l4m2's Python answer yields 35 bytes (we can remove the correction that was present in the Python answer because as I mentioned earlier, Desmos seems to always round half up): `f(x)=round([x,5,10,x/10].sort[2],2)` [Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ugiaae4h9h)

Comment: I just realized that `x/10` can be `.1x`, saving another byte (I just copy-pasted the list from the aforementioned Python answer without much attention, so I didn't catch this before).