# How Many Paint Tins Do I Need?

Tags: code-golf, number

## Task

Take in **3** inputs. The **length** of the wall, the **height** of the wall and the **coverage** of the paint. Output how many tins of paint are required.

## Output

Since there's no way to purchase `1/3` tin of paint, you'll need to round the amount of paint tins up to the nearest integer.

## Assumptions/Stipulations

- Only 1 coat of paint is required
- Round up in terms of paint tins required

## Test Cases

> Length: 20 meters | Height: 7 meters | Coverage: 12 meters = 12 tins of paint

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `1/1/10` | `1` |
| `5/5/10` | `3` |
| `2/3/8` | `1` |
| `5/8/8` | `5` |
| `45/5/18` | `13` |
| `20/7/12` | `12` |
| `1/1/1` | `1` |
| `200/10/14` | `143` |

### Current Winners! (28th November 2023)

Jelly - 3 bytes - Jonathan Allan
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267131/91342

Uiua - 3 bytes - chunes
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267109/91342

Vyxal 3 - 3 bytes - Nick Kennedy
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267138/91342

APL - 3 bytes - Tbw
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267134/91342

Vyxal - 3 bytes - Iyxal
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267112/91342

Comment: -1 because this isn’t interesting in the slightest. I really recommend you wait for feedback in the Sandbox before posting a challenge.

Comment: @noodleman Perhaps, but I'm happy with the turnout in terms of answers :-)I thought about making each input be a different unit, so meters, meters squared, feet, inches, miles etc and making them convert but I think it would all boil down to the shortest conversion for all answers so I chose to omit. Let me know you're thoughts!

Comment: That idea seems to fall into a common challenge-writing trap of [combining many not-directly-related sub tasks and just stacking them on top of each other](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384/108687). I can’t think of a more interesting variant of this challenge, but that’s not to say one doesn’t exist. Don’t feel too discouraged if you write a few poorly-received challenges before you write one that clicks; just please wait for feedback in the Sandbox  for future ideas. If you don’t get any feedback, you can bring your post up in the site’s chatroom The Nineteenth Byte (see footer)

Comment: @noodleman Appreciate the information, thank you very much :-) I'll make sure to use the sandbox in future to vet questions

Comment: What do you mean by "coverage"?

Comment: Showing only the "3 bytes winners" doesn't make much sense. We emphasize competition within each language, and this is what [this leaderboard snippet](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5139/58563) does.

Answer (score 6):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org),  <s>4</s>   3 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⌈×÷
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_3_1__ZiDihpAg4oyIw5fDtwoKZiAxMCAxIDEKZiAxMCA1IDUKZiA4IDIgMwpmIDggNSA4CmYgMTggNDUgNQpmIDEyIDIwIDcKZiAxIDEgMQpmIDE0IDIwMCAxMAo=)

-1 thanks to alephalpha

Takes input in the order `coverage length height`

```
⌈×÷
  ÷  # divide first two args
 ×   # multiply by third
⌈    # ceiling
```

Comment: You can do `⌈×÷`, and take input in the order `coverage length height`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
P÷Ċ
```

A monadic Link that accepts the dimensions on the left and the paint tin coverage on the right and yields the number of tins required.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/g8PYjXf8PL3@4c5Xm///R0QoKhjpgbGgQq8OlAOSb6oAxnG8E5BsDsQWSvAWCbwJTD@UbGQD55kC@EVQ91HwFQzDfyMAAZDYQmwD5sQA)**

#### How?

```
P÷Ċ - Link: Dimensions, Coverage
P   - product {Dimensions}
 ÷  - divide by {Coverage}
  Ċ - ceiling
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 3 bytes

```
÷×⌈
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLDt8OX4oyIIiwiIiwiMTBcbjIwMFxuMTQiLCIzLjEuMCJd)

Similar to most other answers. Divide by coverage, multiply by other dimension, take ceiling.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 bytes

```apl
⌈÷/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhEc9HYe36///X5JaXFIM5GsYKhgaKBhqapiCaFNNDSMFCwVjENdCwUJTwwQobAEWBioyUjDXBKkHKTcyAAqYAPVocoGN0ok21DONTTu0AswDAA)

Written as a tacit function that takes a vector with entries length, coverage, and height, in that order.

`÷/`, read as Divide Reduce, calculates `length ÷ coverage ÷ height`. Since APL evaluates right to left, this gives `length ÷ (coverage ÷ height) = (length × height) ÷ coverage`. `⌈` takes the ceiling of the result.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 22 bytes

```javascript
(a,b,c)=>(a*b+c-1)/c|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BDoIwEETP9is8bm1h2wKRxOCXEKWUQjBICRhP/nstEBOzh30zs5PsQ7/1YuZ@ekWja6xvCw@a19zQ4gr6VDMTSYrmI/ylIhLDiONBkgyzjRKiMMF8t/IVMpJu4eqFVOAZpQqs9vZ6qYQIZZRpEGlSxbOdBm0s4A3KhtES/xc@Ow53/vvJuHFxg40H10ELTHNWc2Yopf4L)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 20 bytes suggested by Arnauld

```javascript
(x,y,z)=>~-(x*y+z)/z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc/LCsIwEAXQfb8iy0Sn5o3d1H8ptRWlTMSKtFn469FIQFIfMMvDvXNPza0Z28vxfC3R7bvQ14FOMINn9e5e0mk1rz3jPrQORzd0m8EdaE8lQjyBhBDGCOdEFrmwCDYXeiEUgkaoIvidUeXCLoRJNdGkjI8agbB9EvUmqvi65s8nSojXGJAGkzA6PAA)

Comment: [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##fc/LCsIwEAXQfb8iy0Sn5o3d1H8ptRWlTMSKtFn469FIQFIfMMvDvXNPza0Z28vxfC3R7bvQ14FOMINn9Y5Oq3l9Lz3jPrQORzd0m8EdaE8lQjyBhBDGCOdEFrmwCDYXeiEUgkaoIvidUeXCLoRJNdGkjI8agbB9EvUmqvi65s8nSojXGJAGkzA6PAA) with BigInts.

Comment: `x*y-~z` wouldn't be the same as `x*y+~-z` ?

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul We need `+z-1` (`+~-z`), not `+z+1` (`-~z`).

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul As a reminder, `-n` is `~n + 1` by definition of [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). So `-~n` is `n + 1`, `~n` is `-(n + 1) = -n - 1` and `~-n` is `n - 1`.

Comment: @Arnauld, thank you, understood, i thought at first glance that the two symbol could be inverted and some tests were passing but testing with values it was obvious.

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 6 bytes

Prompts for three numbers. Coverage followed by wall dimensions:

```
⌈⎕×⎕÷⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3t/6OeDqDI4ekgYjuQ@A8U5fqfxmVoAEZcYJYpEKZxWXAZcxmBaQsw3xBEmYBZRlzmXEYGIBYYAmkTkD4jAwMuAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```python
lambda l,h,c:-(-l*h//c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSFHJ0Mn2UpXQzdHK0NfP1nzf0FRZl6JRpqGoQ4QGmhqcsEETHVMUQWMdIx1LFAUWKDwTcA6kEWMDHTMdQyNkETAtqCoMABaomNooqn5HwA)

---

Edit

- -2 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)

Comment: I don't think you need the inner set of `()`s.

Comment: `-(...)` can be `0-...`

Answer (score 3):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 15 bytes

```
$=>[ceil//&*&&]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?TRHAvo)

```
$=>[ceil//&*&&]
$=>[          ]  ; a function
          &*&    ; multiply first arg by second
        //   &   ; divide by third
    ceil         ; ceiling
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 20 bytes

```scala
(l,h,c)=>(l*h+c-1)/c
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZA9CsJAEIX7nOKVu7rBJEYMAQVLCyuxEot1NRpZV0lWQUJOYpNGT-BlchQ7N0YbDcwPvI95M8z1ngouebco3cNytxYaEx4rZJYFnLlEFBKQsdIM30IHw6pigNtJR3bwIJJtmTAyka1tW9gu7YgalU9gtY6wN5aEJ5s0xChJ-GU-1UmsNgsaYqZibawysw44GlVLRSLiMlThUPoDegy9RuAxdBmCpoGgSfc_Tv_Ecxj6hnh_5HNVw4RT3WTSf7PcyusHFEXdXw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
Ｉ±÷×ＮＮ±Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwy81PbEkVcMzr8QlsywzJVUjJDM3tRjILygt8SvNTUot0tDUUUDhAvlwXcjCIGD9/7@RAZc5l6HRf92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @SevC_10's Python answer.

```
    Ｎ       First input as a number
   ×        Multiplied by
     Ｎ      Second input as a number
  ÷         Integer divided by
       Ｎ    Third input as a number 
      ±     Negated
 ±          Negated
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 39 bytes

```
.+
$*
1(?=1*¶(1+)¶)
$1
(1+)(?=1*¶1+¶\1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZyg819Pm0tFi8tQw97WUOvQNg1Dbc1D2zS5VAy5QEyoqKH2oW0xhpr//xvqAKEBl6mOKYgy0jHWsQByLICkCVjMgsvIQMdcx9CIC6wSyDMAKtQxNAEA) Takes input on separate lines but link is to test suite that splits on commas for convenience. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
1(?=1*¶(1+)¶)
$1
```

Multiply only the first number by the second.

```
(1+)(?=1*¶1+¶\1)
```

Partition the first number into as few values as possible that do not exceed the third number and output the size of the partition.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
×/V c
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=1y9WIGM&input=WzQ1IDVdCjE4)

Answer (score 3):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 6 bytes

```
/ * |^
```

[Try it on scline!](https://scline.fly.dev/#H4sIANZhZWUCA4s2VABCg1g9rmhTBVMoy1jBSMECxLAACoEZpgomQEkw01zByEDB0AjEBOsFMwyAgkBREyBHJ0FBQ0EnXk9BUyE3sQAAADFLcmAAAAA#H4sIANZhZWUCA9NX0FKoiQMA93pifgYAAAA#) Takes input as `H L C`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 3 bytes

```
*/⌈
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJyIiwiIiwiKi/ijIgiLCIiLCI1XG41XG4xMCJd)

Hehehehe flag go brrrr

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 40 bytes

```powershell
param($l,$h,$c)[math]::Ceiling($l*$h/$c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0MlR0clQ0clWTM6N7EkI9bKyjk1MyczLx0ooaWSoQ@U@F/LxaWmkqZgCIIGYKYpEEKZRgrGChZQQQsoywQsD2EbGSiYKxgaIUyAihoADVAwNOH6DwA)

Thanks [Julian](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97729/julian)!

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 47 bytes

```powershell
$c={param($l,$h,$c)[math]::Ceiling(($l*$h)/$c)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXZtrogsSgxV0MlR0clQ0clWTM6N7EkI9bKyjk1MyczL10DKKOlkqGpD5SqBarX88wry89O1TDUUQAhA00uhJipjoIpupiRjoKxjoIFmjILNCETqFYUQSMDHQVzoKARsiDUXlR1BiBbgdhE8z8A)

Thought I'd throw my own suggestion in :-)

Comment: You can remove the function declaration from the body and remove the parentheses from the multiplication: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0MlR0clQ0clWTM6N7EkI9bKyjk1MyczLx0ooaWSoQ@U@F/LxaWmkqZgCIIGYKYpEEKZRgrGChZQQQsoywQsD2EbGSiYKxgaIUyAihoADVAwNOH6DwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>27</s></sup> 24 bytes

```c
f(l,h,c){l=(l*h+c-1)/c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHtaoNAEPyfp1iEgMaT@JHQFmv/lD5FlSKbMye9aPCESsVXr707TzFtxF3XnZldnUPvjDiOhc0JI@j0PLH5jrnoBc4e42EsqxYueVnZDvQbkJdqtFS0H/w9gwT6gMCRQKjzQVU@gUA9/CG@FbC1ICLwqIsHTQ/@sdGw1Thfk@UdqAgnxWGloN2VYktPy4ZIc@T4IFopIiPBuhItIMubncwUP2kzKa20ewvT7ulVxtEisH6PLKMu6gZstbWsTrSTMj825TOI8pvWhT1/j7M3jd3SicF1NdvRwyZT5//gcpoxV3Oy@AZmM8zuwjjDeBcWElbnDIwAOrcYldhi4l/xtZGUwra2JwJTgPei8laklXTJjCQgyGKnSBKamSXDZhh/sOD5WYze1@jxyy8)

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to [Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48931/sisyphus)!!!*

Comment: integer divison with `(l*h+c-1)/c` works i think

Comment: @Sisyphus Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 18 bytes

```
=roundup(A1*B1/C1)
```

Put the input in cells `A1:C1`.

In Microsoft Excel, `roundup()` requires a second parameter (**19 bytes**):

```
=roundup(A1*B1/C1,)
```

Comment: `roundup(X)` can also be spelled `ceiling(X)` or `-floor(-X)` (which are all exactly the same length)

Answer (score 2):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 11 bytes

```lua
ceil(l*h/c)
```

Not the most imaginative answer.
Arguments as `coverage, height, length`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z85NTNHI0crQz9Z8////4Ym/w0N/hsZGAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
/*î
```

Inputs in the order \$coverage,length,height\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fX@vwuv//DY24jAy4zAE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WmVCklJxfllqUmJ5qpXB4v7VCSmZual5xZn5eMYhfcXi/wqO2SQpK9kCV//W1Dq/7r/M/OtrQQMdQxzBWB8Qw1TEFMix0jHSMwbSpjgVIwkLHBCJjaKRjZKBjDmLBNJkARYAmGMTGAgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
/    # Divide the second (implicit) input length by the first (implicit) input coverage
 *   # Multiply it to the third (implicit) input height
  î  # Ceil it
     # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
*╠ü
```

Inputs (as floats) in the same order as the challenge description: \$length,height,coverage\$.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1/r0dQFh/f8/2@oZ6AAxgZ6BlymQIYpjGMEZBgDsQVUwgLKNoGrAvGMgEoVzEE8oHouuGlgGQOoUQqGJnoGAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
*    # Multiply the first two (implicit) inputs: height*length
 ╠   # Divide it by the third (implicit) input: (height*length)/coverage
  ü  # Ceil it
     # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 34 bytes

```
K.Q)=+Z*@K0@K1;J0;W>Z0=-Z@K2=+J1;J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/31svUNNWO0rLwdvAwdvQ2svAOtwuysBWN8rB28hW2wso8v@/kYEBlyEQmQAA)

I just wanted to try out in `Pyth`. Unfortunately, `Pyth` doesn't support float division so, had to use `while` to do the trick.

##### Explanation

**K.Q)** - get input in a newline, as in the question's order and store it as `list` in `K`

**<Z** - used to store the product of `length` and `height` i.e `area`

**W>Z0=-Z@K2=+J1** - used to iterate until the area isn't `0` and decrement the `area` by `coverage` (`@K2`); and increment `J` by `1`