# Coin sequence probability

Tags: code-golf, math

Given two strings containing only `0` and `1`, decide the probability that first appears earlier as a consecutive substring in an infinite random 0/1 stream.

You can assume that neither string is suffix of the other string, so `01, 1`, `00, 0` are invalid. <sup>(*)</sup>

IO format flexible. Your answer should be precise given ideal floating point numbers, so [sampling](https://tio.run/##VcgxDgIhEADA/j7CrkQCFhaH6AusrckBHuZkDUsMhX/HWDrlPPzb81Lzq@0LhThGct2du4ol8C23FYQ2RuDFzH@nf6fnBF3C1bdVVV8CPQF3h49GnBJVYJedtvlk4tFKmZGlSyAE2mmhwrRFtdEdGMf4Ag) is likely not a good idea.

Shortest code wins.

## Note

- I'd like to see how much longer code without assumption `(*)`, allowing collision in a sequence but won't happen (due to fact that one string would appear earlier) or even just no extra rule(In which case `f(a,b)+f(b,a)!=1`). Therefore, you may also provide version(s) that do so, even if longer, if convenient.

## Test cases

```
0, 1 => 50%
00, 1 => 25%
10, 00 => 75%
0, 01 => 100%
011, 001 => 1/3
00, 110 => 1/2 (Example with different length input but result half)
000, 101 => 5/12 (Examples provided by Bubbler)
000, 011 => 2/5
111, 1001 => 4/7
111, 0011 => 5/12 (Suggested by Neil, longer string would likely come earlier)
(Following not required)
11, 1 => 0%
1, 11 => 100%
10, 10 => 100% (0% if you choose strict early)
01, 1 => 50%   (0%)
1, 01 => 100%  (50%)
```

## References

- [Penney's game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game), where two strings have same length
- [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26193/76323), where `00, 0` was required to handle

Comment: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/293812/use-mathematica-to-implement-a-penneys-game-solver/293813#293813) may help.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/268769/can-their-first-appearance-happen-together) (though probably not very useful)

Comment: Can we express the answer as odds?

Comment: @NickKennedy I guess so but what do other probably questions do

Answer (score 8):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```
≔⮌Ｅ²ＳθＩＥθΣ⊞ＯυΣＥθ×⊖⊗⁼κμ↨²Ｅι¬⌕λ✂ιξ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3NDoIwEITvPEWP26Qm1CsnFU08qER8gQobaGwL9If49rWgB/cy2W92Z5pe2GYQKsadc7IzcMcZrUO4iBG2jJzNGHztrTQdUEoZmWiRVWn1cBDOr2cTI3XQUAXX30a0wg8Wwpf97IfU6KDExqJG47GFcghPlfQ4BaEcvBjRa/xepO7UuzxKRq6Dh5M0LaiUp2SDC3zTvyli5Jxnec553MzqAw) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the ratio as a fraction but not necessarily in lowest terms. Technically works for all edge cases although two identical inputs outputs `0/0`. Explanation: For the Cartesian product of the two inputs with itself, calculates which suffixes of one are prefixes of the other, then interprets that in base `2`; this is negated when the strings are compared against each other. The final denominator is simply the sum of all four values; the numerator is the sum of two of them. Example for `111` and `0011`:

```
Suffixes of 111: 111 11 1
Are they prefixes of 111? 1 1 1 = 7
Are they prefixes of 0011? 0 0 0 = -0
Suffixes of 0011: 0011 011 11 1
Are they prefixes of 111? 0 0 1 1 = -3
Are they prefixes of 0011? 1 0 0 0 = 8
Numerator = 8 - 3 = 5
Denominator = 8 - 3 + 7 - 0 = 12
```

Note that the values `7` and `8` are also half the indices at which you would expect to find `111` and `0011` respectively, which leads to the paradox that although you would expect to see `0011` first, the expected position of `111` is before that of `0011`.

26 bytes by taking input in the form of a reversed list:

```
ＩＥθΣ⊞ＯυΣＥθ×⊖⊗⁼κμ↨²Ｅι¬⌕λ✂ιξ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLCsIwFER/JWR1AxFat@60ulMLuitdXNMLDebR5iH@fWzRhbM5cIYZNWJQHk0pbdAuwQFjgjNOMEt2yxbaHMfrRAGTD5C/7lfftaUIDalAllyiARqfH2bhcc5oIjwls0IIyfYYCbaSrUMt2cUnOGk3gFn@jFa0yrf4y66UruNVVddcMl4v6PuyeZkP) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  θ                         Input list
 Ｅ                          Map over elements
         θ                  Input list
        Ｅ                   Map over elements
              κ             Outer index
             ⁼              Equals
               μ            Inner index
            ⊗               Doubled
           ⊖                Decremented
          ×                 Times
                   ι        Outer string
                  Ｅ         Map over characters
                      λ     Inner string
                    ¬⌕      Begins with
                        ι   Outer string
                       ✂    Sliced from
                         ξ  Innermost index
                ↨           Convert from base
                 ²          Literal integer `2`
       Σ                    Take the sum
    ⊞Ｏυ                     Push to predefined empty list
   Σ                        Take the sum of that list
Ｉ                           Cast to string
                            Implicitly print
```

Comment: Seems your solution treats longer string win when collide, and it looks like that you thought so in sandbox

Comment: @l4m2 That's how my source treats it: `01` precedes `1`, unless the very first bit is `1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua 0.8.0](https://www.uiua.org/), 35 bytes <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/SBCSUiua)</sup>

```
+,∩(-:∩(°⋯⇌⊢⍉⊐≡⌕),:≡(□↘)⇡⧻♭..∩¤)⊙.,
```

[Try on Uiua Pad!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__RiDihpAgKyziiKkoLTriiKkowrDii6_ih4ziiqLijYniipDiiaHijJUpLDriiaEo4pah4oaYKeKHoeKnu-KZrS4u4oipwqQp4oqZLiwKCkYgWzFdIFswXQojIyMKRiBbMF0gMF8xCiMjIwpGIDFfMV8wIDBfMAojIyMKRiAxXzBfMSAwXzBfMAojIyMKRiAwXzBfMV8xIDFfMV8xCiMjIwo=)

Port of Neil's answer.

### Explanation

```
⊙., # duplicate inputs in reverse order
∩(  # on both pairs,
  ∩¤    # add an axis to both inputs
  ⇡⧻♭.. # dup the first twice and range the length
  ≡(□↘) # for each in the range, 
        # drop that much from the front and box the result
  ,:    # dup top of stack to third
  ∩(    # on both pairs,
    ⊐≡⌕ # find suffixes in input
    ⊢⍉  # first column
    °⋯⇌ # reverse then un-bits, binary to number
  )
  -:    # subtract second from top
)
+,  # duplicate the second onto top then add
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
¹ÐƤ€eþ€¹Ƥ€Ḅạ/€UÄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDPSsNAEMbveYq5FBqIJFsNPbUHwasXUfDYNJN06zYp@WPNrUqhVx9AEf8cPao0Ch4a8D2SF4mz2ZZAdplv5ttfPmaKQmR1vc2L@7@36u4di1@6t3kjys2q/H42qTovVrVRrMtcTqfV8gEOhlAtH7Vy81TdfpU/H9vPMn@lzqDcvKjKuCAvfXqxpvuyri0DGAyGYFsdzdqLnt3RGAnLkqpPSopmxCxpZEwOVcM8VA@ZpWQPuic3o9lcICx4MgGXex5GGCQgMPCpwYN5moBDJ8I4FQlMRsLTCSIpCmqbrMXEMI/Ca@6iC04Gx6njCIx2fkrSBDZtjclQbJfqyOyrhrVzKOJZ6vsYJ4p0ilwYIMLAxwjiJOKBD4swFS4IfoUig3E4Q8BRJLj8X4OXKFqALNt1sCb4XkKXDvcgC1MYT8IwxgY@ThpURsFZu3MAadclsN0v9Wik/wM)

A Jelly port of [Neil’s Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269024/42248), so be sure to upvote that one too!

If odds are allowable as output, one byte can be saved (by omitting the `Ä`). If it’s allowable to reverse the order of the inputs, then a further byte can be saved (omit the last `U`).